# Generate alphabet with 4 copies of each letter

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity, alphabet

Note that this is not the same as [Print the alphabet four times](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/print-the-alphabet-four-times).

This task is to write a program to generate four copies of each letter of the English alphabet, one letter per line, on standard output:

```
A
A
A
A
B
B
B
B
```

etc.

The output should include newlines after each letter.

Lowercase letters and/or extra whitespace are acceptable.

The solution must be a complete program.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so answers will be scored in bytes with a lower score being the goal.

Comment: I'm slightly confused. Is the challenge here just to output the alphabet with each letter repeated four times, or does the output actually need to be stored in a file as well?

Comment: And do I have to output **only** the alphabet?

Comment: @MarkReed Do I need to print it with newlines in between? Why not just print it, but newlines optional?

Comment: Also, I recommend rephrasing your challenge so that it is more like a challenge and less like telling the story of how you invented your answer.

Comment: The last bit muddies the whitespace rules just a tad. Could you please clarify? Particularly, am I reading it right to interpret that *extra* whitespace is okay but omission of newlines is not?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### APL (5)

```
⍪4/⎕A
```

Matrix format (`⍪`) of 4-replication (`4/`) of alphabet (`⎕A`).

Comment: Seems unlikely to be beaten. :)

Comment: [I count 9 bytes.](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%E2%8D%AA4%2F%E2%8E%95A)

Comment: APL uses a code-page that maps each of the characters it uses to one byte.  This code page can be found [here,](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB27U_6.2.0/com.ibm.zvm.v620.dmsp2/hcsp2c00316.htm) on IBM's website.

Comment: @StevenH. Link is dead

Comment: @StanStrum I believe the link is dead because of deprecation, but for the sake of code golfing [this meta answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/55696) should work.

Answer (score 12):

## Python 2 - 37

```
for i in range(104):print chr(i/4+65)
```

As `i` goes from 0 to 104, it is divided by four and added to the ASCII value for `A`, and the resulting character is printed.

Comment: I take it Python uses integer division by default? Would kinda be nice if PowerShell did right now. As it is, the code necessary to force it into integer division is too long for this trick to help me save anything on my script.

Comment: @lszi - Python takes its cue from the type of the operands.  `3/4` is 0, while `3.0/4.0` is 0.75; `range()` generates integers.

Comment: This does not work on newer versions of python. First, the print function must be called with brackets, and / no longer does integer division by default (even if both numbers are integers), which is //'s job

Try: `for i in range(104):print(chr(i//4+65))`

Comment: @Consciousness I know that. I deliberately chose to use an old version so that it can be golfed better. If you were to run this at Ideone.com, you'd choose "Python" instead of "Python 3"

Comment: @Consciousness - by "newer versions of python", you're referring to "Python 3", which is far from universally adopted at this point. I generally assume that anything claiming to be "Python" without a specified version is Python 2.x until proven otherwise; Python 3 code tends to be explicitly so labeled.

Comment: The above is no longer the case in 2022, so I took the liberty of editing this answer to mark it explicitly as Python 2.

Answer (score 9):

## R, <strike>30</strike> <strike>28</strike> <strike>27</strike> 25

```
write(rep(LETTERS,e=4),1)
```

---

Former version with 30 bytes:

```
cat(rep(LETTERS,e=4),sep="\n")
```

Comment: I think a literal newline is a byte shorter :)

Comment: @Giuseppe Can you specify this idea?

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKMotUDDxzUkxDUoWCfV1kRTpzi1wFaJS0nz/38A "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @Giuseppe Really good idea! Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You can use `1` instead of `""` to specify stdout in `write` as well, which saves another byte.

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks for the hint.

Comment: The final `1` is not necessary, making it [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVoyi1QMPHNSTENShYJ9XWRFPHUPP/fwA "R – Try It Online").

Comment: @RobinRyder Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 7):

### C, 59

I submit this, an uncompetitively long answer, simply because I don't see a C submission yet. And that makes me sad.  :-/

LATER: Props to @moala for doing a "/4" int version of this, saving 13 chars!

```
float i;main(){while(i<26)printf("%c\n",65+(int)i),i+=.25;}
```

Comment: I've edited my answer, now saving even 2 more chars!

Comment: and another one!

Answer (score 6):

## J: <s>18</s> 13

```
4#u:65+i.26 1
```

<sup>I'm still pretty shaky with J, so this could probably be improved</sup>

Comment: You can use replicate (`#`) instead of division like so: `4#u:65+i.26 1`. Also, `~` swaps a function's arguments, so if you ever find yourself doing `(expression) F value`, you can replace that with `value F~ expression` to save a character.

Comment: @marinus Thanks for the tip. I'm still learning J and it's hard to find any good info with those kinds of tricks.

Comment: `4#65{26,.\a.` for 12 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

## PowerShell: <strike>32</strike> 23

**Golfed code:**

```
[char[]](65..90*4)|Sort
```

**Walkthrough:**

`[char[]](`...`)` takes an array of objects and converts them to ASCII characters.
`65..90` are the ASCII codes for A-Z.
`*4` repeats the series 4 times.
`|Sort` sorts the output.

**Note:**

If you want this written to a file, just throw `>`, followed by a file name, at the end.

Answer (score 5):

## Befunge 98 - 18

```
1+::'g`#@_4/'A+,a,
```

Works by storing a number and ending when it reaches 104. Prints out the corresponding character of the alphabet for the number divided by 4, followed by a newline. But if I need not add a newline after each letter, then it is 16 chars:

```
1+::'g`#@_4/'A+,
```

Can be reduced if I can print more characters (ie all of them four times)(<s>7</s> 6 chars, even works in Befunge 93):

```
1+:4/,
```

With newline:

```
1+:4/,a,
```

Answer (score 5):

### Ruby, 23

```
puts ([*?A..?Z]*4).sort
```

All credit to @manatwork -- upvote his comment, not this. :)

Comment: Huge. @manatwork, I'll make the edit but obviously I don't deserve any credit!

Comment: Better make it `puts [*?A..?Z].map{|i|[i]*4}` or `puts ([*?A..?Z]*4).sort`, so the letters get ordered as in the example.

Comment: @manatwork: `puts (?A..?Z).map{|i|[i]*4}` is a character shorter.  You can call `map` directly on a Range, so you don't need the splat in this case.

Answer (score 5):

## C, <s>46</s> <s>44</s> 43

<s>46</s>:

```
i;main(){while(i<104)printf("%c\n",65+i++/4);}
```

<s>44</s>:

```
i=260;main(j){for(;(j=i++>>2)<91;puts(&j));}
```

44 too:

```
i=260;main(j){while(j=i++>>2,j<91)puts(&j);}
```

Thanks to @marinus, 43:

```
i=260;main(j){while(j=i++/4,j<91)puts(&j);}
```

Should I add a bounty for getting to 42? :)

Comment: 50 rep. is needed to comment on anything, and you have 101 at the time of posting this comment.

Comment: You can replace `>>2` by `/4`.

Comment: [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/LOjcxM08jU7M6Lb9IwzrLxtDAxLqgtKRYQy1TUzPTNktbW99E28zUuvb/fwA) Can I get the bounty :-)

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 46

```
x a=a++a
main=putStr$['A'..'Z']>>=x.x.(:"\n")
```

Comment: `putStr$['A'..'Z']>>=("golf">>).(:"\n")` saves 8 bits

Answer (score 5):

**Java: 56**

```
for(int i=0;i<104;)System.out.println((char)(i++/4+65));
```

edit: changed from 'print' to 'println'

Comment: The output should include newlines after each letter.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, it should print a new line each time now

Comment: `The solution must be complete enough to execute. I should be able to invoke an implementation of the language, paste the code from the answer, and get results, without typing any additional code.`  i think your solution violates this condition

Comment: @user902383 If you paste it into JShell (the Java REPL in Java 9) it works, and you don't even need the final semicolon.

Comment: @DavidConrad Its awesome then, I think I might start using REPL/JShell.

Comment: @user902383 You can [download an early access release here](https://jdk9.java.net/download/). It was glitchy under Cygwin so I run it directly from a `cmd` prompt; should be find on other OS's and hopefully they'll fix the Cygwin problems for the final release.

Answer (score 5):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 48 bytes

```
+++[[-<+>>++<]+>]<<<<<<+[->,++++[->.<<<.>>]>+<<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fW1s7OlrXRtvOTlvbJlbbLtYGDLSjde10tEGSunZ6QL6enV2snbaNTez//wA)

Prints in lowercase, separated by carriage returns. Uses wrapping 8 bit cells as well as cells left of the origin, though you can prepend a `>` to counter the latter.

Comment: I was about to post a new one, but you managed to completely out-do my best, i got 71 bytes with ++++++[->++>++++>++++++++++<<<]++++>+>++>+++++<[->.<<.>>.<<.>>.<<.>>.+<<.>]

Answer (score 4):

## GolfScript: <s>17</s> 15 characters

```
26,{65+...}%+n*
```

Answer (score 4):

## Bash: 24 characters

```bash
printf %s\\n {A..Z}{,,,}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 20 bytes

```perl
print"$_
"x4for A..Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvREklnkupwiQtv0jBUU8v6v9/AA)

---

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-M5.10.0`, 20 bytes

```perl
eval"say;"x4for A..Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@1LDFHqTix0lqpwiQtv0jBUU8v6v//f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwN9AwA)

Comment: It has never occurred to me to put a literal newline inside a double-quoted string in Perl. +1.

Comment: I should note, that I didn't either, but @manatwork mentioned it on another answer of mine and it's stuck!

Answer (score 4):

### Forth, 37

```
'h 0 [do] [i] 4 / 'A + emit cr [loop]
```

Comment: [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//G5uZKBiZGShEp@THKkRnxiqYKOgrpOZmligkFylE5@TnF8T@/w8A) by avoiding `+`.

Answer (score 4):

**BrainF*** ,<strike>79</strike> 60

```
+++++++++++++[->++>+>+++++<<<]>>---<[->>>++++[-<.<.>>]<+<<]
```

Comment: `+++++++++++++[>+>+++++>++<<<-]>--->>[<.<.>.<.>.<.>.<.>+>-]`

Answer (score 4):

## Actually, 6 bytes

```
4ú*SÖi
```

[Try it here!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=NMO6KlPDlmk&input=)

Explanation

```
4ú*SÖi

4 *         Do 4 times
 ú          Create string of alphabet in lowercase
   S        Sort it
    Ö       Switch Case
     i      Push each character of string
```

4 Bytes with lowercase and no newline:

```
4ú*S
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 4):

## 16-bit x86 machine code MS-DOS COM, 25 bytes

In hex:

```
B409BA160189D7B96800F6C1037502FE05CD21E2F5C3400A24
```

This is a complete MS-DOS .COM program. Copy the byte sequence to the file with .com extension and run it from DOSBox

Disassembly:

```
00: B4 09        mov    ah,0x09         ;INT 21h "Write string to STDOUT" function
02: BA 16 01     mov    dx,0x116        ;Address of the string s ('$'-terminated)
05: 89 D7        mov    di,dx           ;Because there's no way to dereference address in DX
07: B9 68 00     mov    cx,104          ;CX=26*4
_0000000A:
0A: F6 C1 03     test   cl,0x03         ;When lower two bits are zero...
0D: 75 02        jne    _00000011       ;...do not skip the next instruction
0F: FE 05        inc    b,[di]          ;*s++
_00000011:
11: CD 21        int    21              ;Print the string
13: E2 F5        loop   _0000000A       ;Until --CX==0
15: C3           retn
16: 40           db     0x40            ;s[0], starts with 'A'-1
17: 0A           db     0x0A            ;'\n'
18: 24           db     '$'             ;Terminator required by the print function
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](//github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ØAx4Y
```

[Try it online!](//jelly.tryitonline.net#code=w5hBeDRZ)

Explanation:

```
ØAx4Y Main link
ØA    “ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ”
   4  4
  x   Repeat each element of x y times
    Y Join x with newlines
```

Answer (score 4):

## x86-16 ASM, IBM PC DOS, <del>22</del> 19 bytes

**Binary:**

```
00000000: 400a 24b8 1109 8bd6 b168 d0c8 102c cd21  @.$......h...,.!
00000010: e2f8 c3                                  ...
```

Build with `xxd -r` and test in DOSBox or your favorite DOS VM.

**Unassembled:**

```
40 0A 24    DB   '@', 0AH, '$'      ; the letter + NL + '$' string terminator
B8 0911     MOV  AX, 0911H          ; AH = DOS print string; AL = 0001 0001 bit pattern
8B D6       MOV  DX, SI             ; DX to output string
B1 68       MOV  CL, 26*4           ; Loop 4 times for each letter in alphabet
        ALOOP:
D0 C8       ROR  AL, 1              ; roll repeating bit pattern to the right
10 2C       ADC  BYTE PTR[SI], CH   ; add rightmost bit to ASCII character
CD 21       INT  21H                ; print letter to console
E2 F8       LOOP ALOOP              ; continue looping
C3          RET                     ; return to DOS
```

**Notes:**

For most flavors of DOS, we know the values of many CPU registers at the [start of execution](http://www.fysnet.net/yourhelp.htm) and we know `SI` is `0100H`, and `CH` is `0`.  So by placing the output string in the beginning of the program, `[SI]` will already be pointing to it.  These bytes (`'@',0AH,'$'`) decode to two benign instructions (`INC AX`, `OR AH, [SI]`), which have no effect on the program.

`AL` contains the bit pattern of `0001 0001` which is bit rolled right each time and the rightmost bit added to the ASCII value of the output char in memory.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 5 bytes

```
kAdds
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=kAdds&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Look ma, no Unicode!

```
kA    # Uppercase output
  dd  # Quadruple
    s # Sorted
      # (j flag) join by newlines
```

Comment: the explanation here is wrong: clearly, the `Adds` here is what is adding everything 4 times ;)

Comment: @lyxal Honestly, this is the first time I've unintentionally done a letters-only answer...

Answer (score 3):

## Raku, <strike>34</strike> 21 bytes

```
('A'..'Z'Xxx 4)».say
```

Comment: I think this is the first time that Perl 6 was the first solution I thought of, but the hyperoperator just seemed a natural fit.

Comment: Updated, @JoKing. Thanks! I was able to mostly predict what your re-golfed solution was before looking, now that I have 9 more years of Raku under my belt. Though I got stuck at 22 bytes; didn't think the space before `Xxx` would be removable. I also left the hyperop as `»` instead of `>>`; it's two bytes either way, and I prefer the look of the guillemet .

Answer (score 3):

## Julia 0.2, <strike>39</strike>, 36

```
println([char(i/4+64.5)for i=0:103])
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica <s>50 41</s> 30

With help from alephalpha and Mark S.

```
Print/@{#,#,#,#}&/@Alphabet[];
```

Comment: `Print /@ {#, #, #, #} & /@ "A"~CharacterRange~"Z";`

Comment: The semicolon in @alephalpha's comment is necessary. Also, using a newer version of Mathematica you can use `Print/@{#,#,#,#}&/@Alphabet[];` instead of `Print/@{#,#,#,#}&/@"A"~CharacterRange~"Z";`

Comment: Echo/@{#,#,#,#}&/@Alphabet[]; shaves another character. Theoretically, #+0{,,,} might let you get to 28 (since it's one shorter than {#,#,#,#}), but I couldn't get the precedence to work.

Answer (score 3):

## Q (13)

.........

```
-1@''4#'.Q.A;
```

Answer (score 3):

**AWK, 48**

Lets try it with AWK...

```
END{s=65;for(i=104;i--;s+=0==i%4)printf"%c\n",s}
```

As suggested by [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) we can get rid of 2 chars

**AWK, 46 (Edit)**

```
END{for(i=104;i--;s+=0==i%4)printf"%c\n",s+65}
```

**AWK,40** (editing [MarkReed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4133/mark-reed)'s code)

```
END{for(;i<104;){printf"%c\n",i++/4+65}}
```

Comment: By removing the initialization of variable s you can spare 2 characters: `END{for(i=104;i--;s+=0==i%4)printf"%c\n",s+65}`.

Comment: Putting the code in an `END` block means it requires an input stream (even if it's `/dev/null`) to work.  Does that modify the char count?  Anyway, `BEGIN{for(;++i<104;){printf"%c\n",i/4+65}}` is 5 chars shorter.

Comment: @MarkReed Your code isn't working. Check [this](http://ideone.com/rYTDph)

Comment: D'oh.  So close! :) But I still don't like the `END` pattern's requirement for an input stream...

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell, 21

```
65..90|%{,[char]$_*4}
```

A slightly different approach to Iszi's. And shorter :-)

Comment: Damn, I got close to this at 22 using what looks like a blend of y'all's:  


65..90|%{[char[]]$_*4}

Answer (score 3):

**C# LINQ <s>115 Bytes</s>110 Bytes**

```
Enumerable.Range(65, 26).SelectMany(i => Enumerable.Repeat(i,4))
.ToList().ForEach(i=> Console.WriteLine((char)i));
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first post!

Answer (score 3):

## 05AB1E, 6 bytes

```
A4×{S»
```

Explanation:

```
A       # Push 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
 4×     # Repeat four times
   {    # Sort
    S   # Split into list
     »  # Join by newlines
        # Implicit print
```

Without newlines, 4 bytes

```
A4×{
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=QTTDl3tTwrs)

Comment: you beat me by >5 years ://

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
Aε4F=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f8dxWEzfb//8B)

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 46 bytes

```cs
for(var a=259;a++<363;WriteLine((char)(a/4)));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/Lb9IoyyxSCHR1sjU0jpRW9vG2MzYOrwosyTVJzMvVUMjOSOxSFMjUd9EU1PT@v9/AA)

Answer (score 3):

### [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
Ｚ４１＊⟳
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNBJXVGRjE0JXVGRjExJXVGRjBBJXUyN0Yz)

Explanation:

```
Code        | Explanation                                  | Stack
------------+----------------------------------------------+------------------------------
Ｚ          | The uppercase alphabet                       | "ABC..."
  ４１＊     | Stretched by 4 horizontally and 1 vertically | "AAAABBBBCCCC..."
        ⟳  | Rotated clockwise                            | "A¶A¶A¶A¶B¶B¶B¶B¶C¶C¶C¶C¶..."
            | Print ToS (implicit)                         |
```

With `¶` replaced with `\n` upon printing.

Answer (score 3):

## VBA, 30 bytes

An anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs to the console.

```vb
For i=260To 363:?Chr(i\4):Next
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>66</s> 59 bytes

Save 7 bytes removing for loop.

```
fun main(a:Array<String>){repeat(104){println('A'+(it/4))}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVVdb9tGEHzXr1igD5JSgWoKB0idNIUdC6mAwg1qF3k@HVfkQcc75j4sK4Z/uzt7FC0bqD4A8ni3szszu9z5ZI17Wr6hz4FV4pq2PlBqTSTta6bG2@35pE2pj@fLpSzJShWT0ju@161yDVfad8vvmWMy3sXl23fv3/86@cKOAwKSsn2rNpxob1JLZwjbG47kt8RKt2Q5JQ6TybXH3tSqNIDj57xcM0XVIUqkr8G4YeU55NZnJGs6jtVkcivnkoo7OZw87YMReOqDb4LqZKkZkyoH/zcTuRWMlWusie0z1oK843FPjz9oY1kkcOFqFWryOfU5nU8mF8fv5fE74aRLgnzcQ7H12dZknLYZLDveS7hIaivhX6SDY//2gNMqjuhxYNJ54vsU1BhSBUapvOUQuP5Ard/zHYcFWVy8Po50lxB5OL1vwVLsleYSQWnNfVIby2S2pFVvkrLmh3HNMqZg@h5XtC/JW3YNmHJ0EDKjt1n0R8Krq/Xt6opu/6aLq6tzkrLHp9TlmGjD4L7rkQ8TO5@bVsThe9Y5cUXrkR7sK5ngoXF3fodbR0YOduySKgGPclkYMasGivQqFifxYOBt8N1gGhf3wgeqhw8SBY7ZprgobIJDSodSnHIHUnVtJLqyJchRO7Xxd0yj0QV5rALSoV/Ep7lHqkd0l0CxbFP0@cQP3eTA9iB7wPfIhxpsJAmEjJK92NPdoUyBAnI@NobcnVpT9kcI@Aett4BY0HpqLTVW1UA4GAaJIG9Ip@uyM@lATTY1F7tVdJlP/dYhJ7Vj@Jfw@SYeC9yIsRECBfSszdZoZe1hIZrDtVwP2gwungm12meX5gWyU8bN5g9VVT3CW1ivn2VZIGsHyxmMBe@mqTBppG6hZW8ibPBNBYf6IujRKkceGJvKYKCfRsyPMdXGV@2n4l7wUUaF9SJkPLkAilk7gqDutTvOArsodJb1@tlFKPx7NkEa8viw@FD4qwZ6LmgjgHyPlotRNCqzq1A@4NYcEaEefSYMv26usRz0oDq8aIBy@kXgGmF0socPZTQbJ0bRYNC8dj61SmL9s/r6Fzzmi0Ia/RLzpgPNf2IwMjgY3a6KPL@/ZAu7lE5ZBIYqYRdlUaYoDE4ojqumKpBNq42M1a5Pg4UGMQsDHaPRCAMpiTfRHOLYMiFq1laF0rXoOoB1KLtY35W3gxMOIJTeDQNOkEJ27TFxFN@pkf4b00GTIE5U@x1FjdEEjk9zA9EuV1/W1zQDZ6vrq8UppooxI/NnzcRBrsiT8FZrB08va75bumztnDbWa3Ax1LjnKWSXVxPq16LQcWQYh5qr46h/9xttDhirkzfLp212Qyeo84sQ1OHjDeaoaz7NHwL3eOXO3v5yNn/o5eVm3Wx6Mf15ZtLybD5/fHx6@g8)

Answer (score 3):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) `-nr`, 27 bytes

```
range(104)/4+65|[.]|implode
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/78oMS89VcPQwERT30TbzLQmWi@2JjO3ICc/JfX//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3XzigA)

`implode` seems to convert floating point to their floored value, which is quite useful here.

Comment: Unless I'm misremembering the rules, I believe command-line options count toward the total, so `-nr` adds three bytes and takes you to an even 30. :)

Comment: @MarkReed You're not misremembering, but the rules have changed since 2013 ;). [Here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/64121) is the *"new"* concensus. In short, `jq -nr` is considered a different language than `jq` and the flag is not counted as any amount of bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [jq `-nr`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 32 bytes

```
range(26)+65|[.]|implode|.,.,.,.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/78oMS89VcPITFPbzLQmWi@2JjO3ICc/JbVGTwcM////l19QkpmfV/xfN68IAA)

`.,.,.,.` may just be the funniest thing I've written on this site. This language's generator system never ceases to amaze me.

Answer (score 2):

## Dc: 35 characters

```
[rdP10Pr1-d1<p]sp65[5lpx+d91>l]dslx
```

Answer (score 2):

## F#: <s>61</s> <s>62</s> 49

```
for i in 'A'..'Z'do for j in 0..4 do printfn"%c"i
```

Comment: hm, do you not need `;;` at the end?

Comment: @MarkReed If executed from fsi.exe, yes, you would usually need that. However, this is a complete program by itself, so you can simply compile and run it as is.

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 42

```
('A'to'Z')map(x=>List.fill(4)(println(x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, 53

```
for($i=65;$i<91;$i++)echo str_repeat(chr($i)."\n",4);
```

Comment: I count 53 chars; where's the 44 from?

Comment: I know a 44 character long solution, but definitely not with that `str_repeat()`: http://pastebin.com/decsAZXi

Comment: @manatwork - that looks like 40, even. Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't count the $i

Comment: It doesn't includes ZZZZ

Comment: @MarkReed, indeed. Seems my character counter bookmarklet fails on pastebin. I not consider it significantly different to post it as separate answer. Just intended to help ub3rst4r to get into codegolfing.

Comment: What VarunAgw said; needs to be `$i<91` instead of `$i<90`.  Doesn't affect the char count, though.

Comment: Its been fixed.

Comment: @ub3rst4r, if you feel the improvement I suggested earlier is too far from your taste, you can still manipulate the loop: 1) remove the explicit incrementation: `for($i=65;$i<91;)echo str_repeat(chr($i++)."\n",4);` and/or 2) remove the explicit initialization: `for(;$i<26;)echo str_repeat(chr($i+++65)."\n",4);`.

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab, 38

```
x=repmat(char(65:90)',1,4)';disp(x(:))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript 55

`for(i=65;i<91;i+=1/4)document.write("&#"+(i|0)+";<br>")`

1 character shorter, but outputs to the screen instead of console.

Comment: `(i|0)` => `~~i`

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, 6 bytes (noncompetitive)

```
G4m*_X
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=G4m%2a_X)

Or 4 bytes without newline separation

```
G4m*
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, <strike>15</strike> 13 characters

```
'[,65>4f*e_N*
```

Probably very golf-able; I'm new to CJam and even code golfing.

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 3, 53

[`(0...103).map{print(String(UnicodeScalar($0/4+65)!))}`](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/58167a41586da353fafab4f3)

***IF*** one day Apple decided to include `Foundation` by default, we could have

`(0...103).map{print(String(format:"%c",$0/4+65))} //49 bytes`

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, 58 bytes

```
(dotimes(i 26)(format t"~4@{~c
~:*~}"(code-char(+ 65 i))))
```

#### Explanation

```
(dotimes(i 26) ; loop for i from 0 to 25
(format t"~4@{~c
~:*~} ;output four times character given by (code-char(+ 65 i)) followed by newline
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74/18jJb8kMze1WCNTwchMUyMtvyg3sUShRKnOxKG6LpmrzkqrrlZJIzk/JVU3OSOxSENbwcxUIVMTCP7/BwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/) `-R`, <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
;B²²¬n
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=O0Kysqxu&input=LVI=)

```
;B²²¬n
;B         :Uppercase alphabet
  ²        :Duplicate
   ²       :Duplicate
    ¬      :Split
     n     :Sort
           :Implicitly join with newlines
```

Answer (score 2):

## Vim, 27 bytes

```
:h<_
jjYZZPVUqqx4O<C-r>"<esc>jq25@q
```

Thanks [@Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87010/31716) for the trick of grabbing the alphabet from helpfiles.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 122 bytes

```
(((((()()()()){}){}){}){}())((((()()()){}){}()){}){({}<(()()()()){({}<(({})<((()()()()()){})>)>[()])}{}({}())>[()])}{}{}
```

this is 120 bytes of source code, and `+2` bytes for the `-Ar` flags.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XwMMNCFQs7oWjoA8hBRcCERrVNfaIGmBcIESNgiDICrtNO2iNTRjNWuBWsG64dzq2v///@s6FgEA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)

```
VGj*4rN1
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VGj%2a4rN1&debug=0)

**Explanation**

```
VG          # For N in G (the alphabet)...
     rN1    # ...convert N to uppercase...
   *4       # ...generate the string NNNN...
  j         # ...join on newlines
            # Implicit print for each iteration
```

Comment: [8 bytes](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VGj%2a4rN1&debug=0): `VGj*4rN1`

Comment: `VrG1NNNN` is also 8 bytes and is way simpler...

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 36 bytes

```php
while($i<104)echo"
",chr($i++/4+65);
```

bonus version, **38 bytes**

```php
while($i<104)echo"@K"^chr($i++/4+1).A;
```

Run with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/86e57428db77b59bc44cf8d9d1b0b67630639ebb).

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 22 bytes

```perl6
.say xx 4 for "A".."Z"
```

Even though this is an old challenge, I found a different approach to the Perl 6 answer, so I decided to post it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/1@vOLFSoaJCwUQhLb9IQclRSU9PKUrp/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## [///](http://esolangs.org/wiki////), 73 bytes

```
/./\/A
A
A
A
\/A\///~/.B.C.D.E.F.G.H.I.J.K.L.M.N.O.P.Q.R.S.T.U.V.W.X.Y.Z.
```

### [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##JcYnDoBAEEBRz2H@nIFel96zBkGCwK3n6gMJeea5@3DX6VQFseJ7v29WRB4hICQiJiElI6egpMJQ09DS0TMwMjGzsLKxo/oC)

This just replace `.` by `/AAAA/A/` to get `AAAA/A/B/AAAA/A/C/AAAA...` (newlines excluded for legibility). The `/~/` is the first part of a dummy replacement which does nothing; it's there to grab initial `/` from the first replacement. We don't need to worry about the final `/A/` (`/Z/` by the time the interpreter gets there), because /// simply exits if it encounters EOF while reading a replacement

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - 7 Bytes

```
VrG1V4N
```

Explanation

```
VrG1V4N
V       For each character N in
  G     The alphabet
 r 1    Converted to uppercase:
    V4  For each variable from 0 to 3:
      N Implicitly print N
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), <s>126</s> 117 bytes

```
[S S S T    S S S S S S N
_Push_64][S N
S _Duplicate][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S N
N
_Discard_top][S S S T   N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][S N
S _Duplicate][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S T   S T T   S T T   N
_Push_91][T S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S S S N
_Jump_to_Label_EXIT_if_0][S S S T   S S N
_Push_4][N
S S T   N
_Create_Label_INNER_LOOP][S S S T   N
_Push_1][T  S S T   _Subtract][S N
S _Duplicate][N
T   T   S N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP_if_negative][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][S N
S _Duplicate][T N
S S _Print_as_character][S S S T    S T S N
_Push_10][T N
S S _Print_as_character][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][N
S N
T   N
_Jump_to_Label_INNER_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##PUxbCgAhCPweT@HVIoL2b6Gg45szQiojzsMzvz3W3/qIcHe4ytTaXDAUKzJN4JAsxSpJL54fTKMwQYKyees3qFjEBQ) (containing raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**General explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer i = 64
Start Loop:
  i = i+1
  If i == 91: Exit program with error
  Integer j = 4
  Start Inner Loop:
    j = j-1
    If j is negative: Go to the next iteration of the outer Loop
    Print i as character
    Print new-line
    Go to the next iteration of the Inner Loop
```

**Example run:**

```
Command        Explanation                            Stack            STDOUT    STDERR

SSSTSSSSSSN    Push 64                                [64]
SNS            Duplicate top (64)                     [64,64]
NSSSN          Create Label_LOOP                      [64,64]
 SNN            Discard top                           [64]
 SSSTN          Push 1                                [64,1]
 TSSS           Add (64+1)                            [65]
 SNS            Duplicate top (65)                    [65,65]
 SNS            Duplicate top (65)                    [65,65,65]
 SSSTSTTSTTN    Push 91                               [65,65,65,91]    
 TSST           Subtract (65-91)                      [65,65,-26]
 NTSSSN         If 0: Jump to Label_EXIT              [65,65]
 SSSTSSN        Push 4                                [65,65,4]
 NSSTN          Create Label_INNER_LOOP               [65,65,4]
  SSSTN          Push 1                               [65,65,4,1]
  TSST           Subtract (4-1)                       [65,65,3]
  SNS            Duplicate top (3)                    [65,65,3,3]
  NTTSN          If negative: Jump to Label_LOOP      [65,65,3]
  SNT            Swap top two                         [65,3,65]
  SNS            Duplicate top (65)                   [65,3,65,65]
  TNSS           Print as character                   [65,3,65]        A
  SSSTSTSN       Push 10                              [65,3,65,10]
  TNSS           Print as character                   [65,3,65]        \n
  SNT            Swap top two                         [65,65,3]
  NSNTN          Jump to Label_INNER_LOOP             [65,65,3]

  SSSTN          Push 1                               [65,65,3,1]
  TSST           Subtract (2-1)                       [65,65,2]
  SNS            Duplicate top (2)                    [65,65,2,2]
  NTTSN          If negative: Jump to Label_LOOP      [65,65,2]
  SNT            Swap top two                         [65,2,65]
  SNS            Duplicate top (65)                   [65,2,65,65]
  TNSS           Print as character                   [65,2,65]        A
  SSSTSTSN       Push 10                              [65,2,65,10]
  TNSS           Print as character                   [65,2,65]        \n
  SNT            Swap top two                         [65,65,2]
  NSNTN          Jump to Label_INNER_LOOP             [65,65,2]

  SSSTN          Push 1                               [65,65,2,1]
  TSST           Subtract (2-1)                       [65,65,1]
  SNS            Duplicate top (1)                    [65,65,1,1]
  NTTSN          If negative: Jump to Label_LOOP      [65,65,1]
  SNT            Swap top two                         [65,1,65]
  SNS            Duplicate top (65)                   [65,1,65,65]
  TNSS           Print as character                   [65,1,65]        A
  SSSTSTSN       Push 10                              [65,1,65,10]
  TNSS           Print as character                   [65,1,65]        \n
  SNT            Swap top two                         [65,65,1]
  NSNTN          Jump to Label_INNER_LOOP             [65,65,1]

  SSSTN          Push 1                               [65,65,1,1]
  TSST           Subtract (1-1)                       [65,65,0]
  SNS            Duplicate top (1)                    [65,65,0,0]
  NTTSN          If negative: Jump to Label_LOOP      [65,65,0]
  SNT            Swap top two                         [65,0,65]
  SNS            Duplicate top (65)                   [65,0,65,65]
  TNSS           Print as character                   [65,0,65]        A
  SSSTSTSN       Push 10                              [65,0,65,10]
  TNSS           Print as character                   [65,0,65]        \n
  SNT            Swap top two                         [65,65,0]
  NSNTN          Jump to Label_INNER_LOOP             [65,65,0]

  SSSTN          Push 1                               [65,65,0,1]
  TSST           Subtract (0-1)                       [65,65,-1]
  SNS            Duplicate top (-1)                   [65,65,-1,-1]
  NTTSN          If negative: Jump to Label_LOOP      [65,65,-1]

 (Note: Contains additional trailing `[65,` here, but we'll ignore that for now.)
 SNS            Discard top                           [65]
 SSSTN          Push 1                                [65,1]
 TSSS           Add (65+1)                            [66]
 SNS            Duplicate top (66)                    [66,66]
 SNS            Duplicate top (66)                    [66,66,66]
 SSSTSTTSTTN    Push 91                               [66,66,66,91]    
 TSST           Subtract (66-91)                      [66,66,-25]
 NTSSSN         If 0: Jump to Label_EXIT              [66,66]
 SSSTSSN        Push 4                                [66,66,4]
 NSSTN          Create Label_INNER_LOOP               [66,66,4]
  SSSTN          Push 1                               [66,66,4,1]
  TSST           Subtract (4-1)                       [66,66,3]
  SNS            Duplicate top (3)                    [66,66,3,3]
  NTTSN          If negative: Jump to Label_LOOP      [66,66,3]
  SNT            Swap top two                         [66,3,66]
  SNS            Duplicate top (66)                   [66,3,66,66]
  TNSS           Print as character                   [66,3,66]        B
  SSSTSTSN       Push 10                              [66,3,66,10]
  TNSS           Print as character                   [66,3,66]        \n
  SNT            Swap top two                         [66,66,3]
  NSNTN          Jump to Label_INNER_LOOP             [66,66,3]

  ... etc. etc. for all letters in the alphabet

 SNN            Discard top                           [90]
 SSSTN          Push 1                                [90,1]
 TSSS           Add (90+1)                            [91]
 SNS            Duplicate top (91)                    [91,91]
 SNS            Duplicate top (91)                    [91,91]
 SSSTSTTSTTN    Push 91                               [91,91,91]    
 TSST           Subtract (91-91)                      [91,91,0]
 NTSSSN         If 0: Jump to Label_EXIT              [91,91]                    error
                (Label_EXIT doesn't exit, so exits program with an error to STDERR)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
ʊ4*ąşÁ
```

Explanation:

```
ʊ     Pushes "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
4*    Quadruples the string
ą     Convert to array of characters
ş     Sort the array in ascending order
Á     Push contents of the array onto the stack
      implicit output
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//VJeJ1pHWo/MPN/7/DwA)

---

If outputting it as an array is acceptable:

## Pyt, 5 bytes

```
ʊ4*ąş
```

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, 29 bytes

```
FOR I=260TO 363?CHR$(I/4)NEXT
```

Comment: This is a polyglot, and will function in Yabasic - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/380/SMHT1sjMIMRfwdjM2N7ZI0hFw1PfRNPPNSLk/38A "Yabasic – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

**Solution:**

```
`0:`c$+,65+&26#4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P8HAKiFZRVvHzFRbzchM2eT/fwA)

**Explanation:**

```
`0:`c$+,65+&26#4 / the solution
            26#4 / generate a vector of 26 4s
           &     / where, turns this into 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 etc
        65+      / add 65 to this vector
       ,         / enlist (,:) each-both (')
      +          / flip
   `c$           / convert to characters
`0:              / print to stdout
```

**Notes:**

- -1 byte with thanks to @ngn!

Comment: `,:'` -> `+,`­­

Answer (score 2):

## [**@NUM**](https://esolangs.org/wiki/@NUM), 43 bytes

```
#1@13#0@65|#1$#0$#1$#0$#1$#0$#1$#0$+<90{*0}
```

(I messed up on some of the code, now it works, but is almost double the size...)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Languages are required to have an implementation (interpreter/compiler), so you'll need to either link to one or write one.

Comment: I would call your language implementation an interpreter. Also, I am unsure if [a leading newline](https://tinyurl.com/ybvqvyaj) is valid. Furthermore, I would recommend not to send the execution time to stdout.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki), <s>6</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page)

```
ＦαＥ⁴ι
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Neil*.

[Try it online (verbose)](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98tv0gjUVPBNTE5Q8NERyFT8////7plOQA) or [try it online (pure)](https://tio.run/##ARkA5v9jaGFyY29hbP//77ymzrHvvKXigbTOuf//).

**Explanation:**

Loop over the characters of the uppercase alphabet:

```
For(a)
Ｆα
```

Create an array of size 4, each mapped to the current letter. (Items of an Array are each printed on a separated line by default.)

```
Each(4, i)
Ｅ⁴ι
```

Comment: Hm, that's 6 _characters_, but I don't see how you can encode them into 6 _bytes_.  I would change the title to just claim "6" instead of "6 bytes". Sadly, 6 characters is still one more than APL.

Comment: @MarkReed In UTF-8 this would indeed be a bit more than 6 bytes (15 to be exact). However, Charcoal uses, just like most codegolf languages (i.e. Jelly, 05AB1E, etc.), a [custom code page](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page) for all 256 characters it knows, where each character is encoded as a single byte.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Didn't realize it was limited to a single code page. Carry on. :)

Comment: 5 bytes: `ＦαＥ⁴ι`

Comment: @Neil I see you're going through all my Charcoal answer. :) And nice golf! I didn't even knew the `Each`/`Map` builtin could be used like that.

Comment: Heh, I hadn't realised there were so many!

Answer (score 2):

## [Cardinal](https://www.esolangs.org/wiki/Cardinal), 68 bytes

```
%+v
(A+
~ =
([t
' >t*~v
8 v~'n<
D<v< #
-~
~+,
 ,,
 ,,~
 ,,-
 ,~
>^R^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sSsnMS8z5/19Vu4xLw1Gbq07BlksjuoRLXcGuRKuujMtCoaxOPc@Gy8WmzEZBmUu3jqtOW4dLQQeM60CELpCo47KLC4r7/x8A)

### Explanation

```
%+v
(A+
~ =
([t
' >t*~v
8 v~'n<
**** #
```

Sets up loops for printing and corrects timing between loops. Right column sets up space to be printed in a loop of 25 times while left column sets up letters of alphabet starting with A to be printed.

```
D<v<
-~
~+,
 ,,
 ,,~
 ,,-
 ,~
>^R^
```

Left 2 columns print out each letter in alphabet while right 2 columns print out newlines.

#### How the loops work:

The inactive value of the pointer is set to the number of times to iterate through the loop. The timing of the loops is set up so that it will print alphabet character then newline four times before decrementing the inactive value of the pointer. The alphabet character to print was selected at the start by assigning the ascii value of A to the active value of the pointer "(A" in the code. After each loop of printing, this active value is incremented by one to print the next character in the alphabet.

Answer (score 2):

### [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 20 bytes (SBCS on Keg wiki)

```
AZɧ^(\
(3|$:\
)$(8|,
```

Push range from A to Z and then 4-speak it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brian & Chuck](https://github.com/m-ender/brian-chuck), 32 bytes

```
A{<?
!{>-_{.>.<.>.<.>.<.+>.>-?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyrKTMzTTc4oTc7@/9@RW6raxp5LsdpON75az07PBo617fTsdO3//wcA)

code:

```
Brian:
A                       ["A", 11, 26] Variables: Letter, newline+1, letter count
{<?                        restart current code portion of Chuck

Chuck:
code 1:
{>-                        go to "newline+1" and decrement it, so it becomes a newline

code 2:
{                          go to letter
.>.<.>.<.>.<               print letter and newline three times
.+                         print and increment letter
>.                         print 4th newline
>-                         decrement counter
?                          if counter > 0, switch to Brian (who just restarts Chuck's code 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 72 bytes

```
9a1a2x1v9m2x2v3d2m4a1x1f1a2x3v1o1v1o3v1o1v1o3v1o1v1o3v1o1v1o3v3x2v1l0x1f
```

**Explanation** (with `0x` commands removed)

```
9a1a2x1v                                         # Set variable 1 equal to 10 (newline)
9m2x2v                                           # Set variable 2 equal to 90 ("Z")
3d2m4a                                           # Set the register to a value of 64 ("@")
1x1f                                             # Function 1
    1a                                           # Add 1 to the register
      2x3v                                       # Store the new value in variable 3
          1o1v1o3v1o1v1o3v1o1v1o3v1o1v1o         # Output it, then a newline, four times
                                        3v       # Load variable 3 into the register
                                          3x2v1l # Jump back to the start of the function
                                                 # if the register is less than variable 2
1f                                               # Call function 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ØAṄ4¡€*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDMeHO1tMDi181LRG6/9/AA)

### Explanation

```
ØAṄ4¡€*
   ØA: alphabet 
   Ṅ: print w/ new line
   4¡: repeat 4 times
   €: each
   *: to error out(see below)
```

The reason I use the `*` is to error out the code so it wont print the whole alphabet at the end (I'm very new to jelly). If anyone can tell me what character to use in combination with `Ṅ` to achieve this, I would appreciate it!

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and impressive first answer! Jelly implicitly outputs the final value at the end of the program, and so Jelly programs normally avoid using `Ṅ` in favour of printing at the end. For example, rather than printing each one 4 times, you can repeat each letter 4 times (to create `'AAAABBBBCCCC....'`), then join by newlines. This approach takes [5 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97575/66833)

Comment: thank you for the quick response! I see what you mean about editing te string rather than the output... I learned something new!

Comment: If you're interested in learning more Jelly, feel free to drop by the [Jelly Hypertraining chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57815/jelly-hypertraining) :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
4kA*s⁋
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=4kA*s%E2%81%8B&inputs=&header=&footer=)

```
4      - Literal
 kA    - Uppercase alphabet
   *   - Multiplication
    s  - Sort
     ⁋ - Join by newlines
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 4 bytes

```
kA4•
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=kA4%E2%80%A2&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Multiplies each letter of the alphabet by 4, and joins on newlines.

Answer (score 1):

#### Bash <strike>28</strike> 26

```
echo {a..z}{,,,}|tr \  \\n
```

Comment: A shame bash doesn't do curly-brace expansion on here-strings.

Answer (score 1):

## Q, 16

........

```
-1@'(,/)4#'.Q.A;
```

Answer (score 1):

#### 4DOS, 59 (including newlines)

Why? Because not enough people use it any more and it's still the same size as C and shorter than F#!

```
do i=65 to 90
@for %j in (1 2 3 4) do echo %@CHAR[%i]
enddo
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (<strike>59</strike> 56)

```
for(i=65;i<91;i+=1/4)console.log(String.fromCharCode(i))
```

Comment: Hey @user113215, you can save 1 extra char by doing `i|0` instead of `i,10`!

Comment: @DomHastings No, `i,10` prints a newline as well as the letter. `i|0` is the same as just `i`. Considering that `console.log` adds an implicit newline, however, I suppose this could be shortened to just `i`.

Comment: Ahhh, i see! Apologies, for some reason I thought it was doing some kind of parseInt!

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure <s>41</s> 45 bytes

```
(doseq[i(range 65 91 0.25)](println(char i)))
```

Comment: except that outputs the letters in reader character syntax (`\A`, `\B`, etc).  And I don't count leading backslashes as "whitespace". :)  Replacing `prn` with `println` yields the correct output at a cost of 4 additional characters.

Comment: you'r right, i was too lazy to test it out :D fixed

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 86 bytes

```
class P{static void M(){for(var i=65d;i<91;i+=.25)System.Console.WriteLine((char)i);}}
```

a full program...

Answer (score 1):

## [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb397926.aspx), 59 bytes

```
from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 104)select(char)(65+i/4)+"\n"
```

LINQ expression, try it with [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/Download.aspx). The `select` part is a bit too C#ist but I guess that fine.

```
from i                        // for each variable
in Enumerable.Range(0, 104)   // in the range 0, 26*4
select(char)(65+i/4)+"\n"     // get the letter and a newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 88 bytes

```cs
var s="";int i,j;for(i=0;i++<26;){for(j=0;j++<4;)s+=(char)(i+64)+"\n";}Console.Write(s);
```

Try it with this REPL shell: https://csharppad.com/

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 23 bytes

```
260[d4/PAP1+d364>M]dsMx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/IzCA6xUQ/wDHAUDvF2MzEzjc2pdi34v9/AA)

Since precision is 0 by default, 260, 261, 262, and 263 all return 65 when divided by 4. All we need to do, then, is start with 260 on the stack, and continue duplicating the top of stack, dividing by 4, printing that code point and a line feed and then incrementing by one until we hit 364 (91*4).

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
Z{4⌡T
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=WiU3QjQldTIzMjFU)

Answer (score 1):

## Taxi, <s>1215</s> 449 bytes

<s><sub><sup>(I am calling this the [Magna Carta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magna_Carta) byte count)</sup></sub></s>

It turns out to be *way* shorter to just hard code the text.

```
'A\nA\nA\nA\nB\nB\nB\nB\nC\nC\nC\nC\nD\nD\nD\nD\nE\nE\nE\nE\nF\nF\nF\nF\nG\nG\nG\nG\nH\nH\nH\nH\nI\nI\nI\nI\nJ\nJ\nJ\nJ\nK\nK\nK\nK\nL\nL\nL\nL\nM\nM\nM\nM\nN\nN\nN\nN\nO\nO\nO\nO\nP\nP\nP\nP\nQ\nQ\nQ\nQ\nR\nR\nR\nR\nS\nS\nS\nS\nT\nT\nT\nT\nU\nU\nU\nU\nV\nV\nV\nV\nW\nW\nW\nW\nX\nX\nX\nX\nY\nY\nY\nY\nZ\nZ\nZ\nZ' is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:w 1 r 3 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:n 1 r 2 r 1 l.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcxLC4JAGIXhv3J27gRt166y7K5drWgzyChD4ogzYf/eLEIOwfNtDnyvFS/Vts7oXvbGZEICMiUzEpI5WZAlWZE12ZAtiUhMdmRPDuRITuRMEnIhV3LrOVAGjVBWlTmERVIrK2vHIJCVtm6oYfXfOGzgocYABXwUbqzSx7OCQCWMkWUua@T6U@seY20soixTqfylaBmW347fndd12vYN)

Ungolfed / formatted:

```
'A\nA\nA\nA\nB\nB\nB\nB\nC\nC\nC\nC\nD\nD\nD\nD\nE\nE\nE\nE\nF\nF\nF\nF\nG\nG\nG\nG\nH\nH\nH\nH\nI\nI\nI\nI\nJ\nJ\nJ\nJ\nK\nK\nK\nK\nL\nL\nL\nL\nM\nM\nM\nM\nN\nN\nN\nN\nO\nO\nO\nO\nP\nP\nP\nP\nQ\nQ\nQ\nQ\nR\nR\nR\nR\nS\nS\nS\nS\nT\nT\nT\nT\nU\nU\nU\nU\nV\nV\nV\nV\nW\nW\nW\nW\nX\nX\nX\nX\nY\nY\nY\nY\nZ\nZ\nZ\nZ' is waiting at Writer's Depot.
Go to Writer's Depot: west 1st right 3rd left 2nd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office: north 1st right 2nd right 1st left.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 51 bytes

```
time {puts [format %c [expr (259+[incr i])/4]]} 104
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/JDM3VaG6oLSkWCE6Lb8oN7FEQTVZITq1oqBIQcPI1FI7OjMvuUghM1ZT3yQ2tlbB0MDk/38A)

Comment: Clever use of `time` to avoid the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, 53 Bytes

Simple solution, we're using the range `[260,363]` which is `65*4` and `90*4+3` (letter `A` and `Z`) to iterate.

Then we just have to do an euclidian division by 4 and print out each letter 4 times this way.

**Edit: Approved @MCAdventure10's edit that pointed out a rounding error that made only one `Z` being printed out, it wasn't deviating from my original idea and didn't change the byte count, thus,I approved it.**

```lua
for i=260,363 do print(("").char(math.floor(i/4)))end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 32 bytes

```
fori=0i<104i++print("%c"%65+i/4)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678/z8tvyjT1iDTxtDAJFNbu6AoM69EQ0k1WUnVzFQ7U99E8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 43 bytes

```fs
for i in 260..363 do printfn"%c"(char(i/4))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv3/Py2/SCFTITNPwcjMQE/P2MxYISVfoaAoM68kLU9JNVlJIzkjsUgjU99EU/P/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 19 bytes

```
L,91 65rbU€C4€*JbUn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99Hx9JQwcy0KCn0UdMaZxMgoeWVFJr3//@//IKSzPy84v@6mQA)

### How it works

```
L,			; Create an anonymous function
	91 65rbU	; Push [65 ... 90]	STACK = [65 66 ... 89 90]
	€C		; Convert to chars;	STACK = ['A' 'B' ... 'Y' 'Z']
	4€*		; Repeat each 4 times;	STACK = ['AAAA' ... 'ZZZZ']
	JbUn		; Join by newlines;	STACK = ['A\nA\n ... Z\nZ']
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ØAx4Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDMcKk8j///8DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.7, 78 bytes

```
x='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
for e in x:
    for d in range(0, 4):
        print e
```

Comment: Golfing challenge submissions have to make an attempt at golfing. In your code there is unnecessary white space, the variable `x` is declared once so could be inlined and the last for loop's body is not a compound statement so could be put on the same line. I also suggest reading [the Python tips page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 28 bytes

```
Print@Char=>Flat!4&`&=>65:90
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/P6AoM6/EwTkjscjWzi0nsUTRRC1BzdbOzNTK0uD/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

[**BRAINF**](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck) **115 BYTES...**

```
++++[->+++>+++>+++<<<]>+>+>+<<<++++[->>+++>+++<<<]>>+>+<<<+++++++++++++[->>>+++<<<]>>[->.<<.>>.<<.>>.<<.>>.<<.>>+<]
```

I know this isn't going to in any awards for being the smallest, but I just thought it would be funny to use one of the hardest to understand languages.

**Breakdown of Code**

Cell zero is used for counting for setup, cell 1 and 3 are used to print, and cell two is used to count for the printing sequence

0          1             2                    3
[setup][newline char][print counter][output char (set to A to begin)]

```
++++[->+++>+++>+++<<<]>+>+>+  sets cells 1, 2, and 3 to 13(new line)
<<<++++[->>+++>+++<<<]>>+>+   sets cells 2 and 3 to 26 (length of alphabet)
<<<+++++++++++++[->>>+++<<<]  sets cell  3 to 65(A)
>>[->.<<.>>.<<.>>.<<.>>.<<.>>+<] increments cell 3, prints alternating between cell 1 
                              and 3, and decrements cell 2.
```

[Here is a Brainf compiler to test it](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_brainfk_online.php) (use the one w/out any newlines)

Comment: Is it so hard to just say brainfuck? At the very least brainf*ck if you're that uncomfortable with swearing. Saying BRAINF just makes everyone confused about what you're referring to

Comment: also, the triple exclamation mark is a bit too excitable for almost twice the bytecount of the [previous brainfuck answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15911/76162)

Comment: @JoKing I wrote this before i realized that there was another Brainfuck program, sorry about that, i never got to fixing it

Comment: having a longer answer is okay, especially in a language like brainfuck. the [tips for golfing in brainfuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12973/76162) page might interest you for future submissions

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 39 bytes

```python
i=65;exec('print chr(i);'*4+'i+=1;')*26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWzNQ6tSI1WUO9oCgzr0QhOaNII1PTWl3LRFs9U9vW0FpdU8vI7P9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

### 05AB1E, 6 bytes

```
A€D€D»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8VHTGhcQPrT7/38A)

#### Explanation

```
A        # push lowercase alphabet
 €       # for each char:
  D      # duplicate it
   €D    # duplicate each char again
     »   # join by newlines
         # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 18 bytes

```
|
#104&h64+k,Z,Z,Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/v4ZL2dDARC3DzEQ7WycKBP//BwA)

## Explanation

```
|
                  use newline as delimiter
#104              default input n = 104
    &             print first n terms in sequence
                  each term is the next term in the comma-delimited sequence, restarting 
                  and incrementing k when the end of the terms list is reached
     h64+k        chr ( 64 + k )
          ,Z,Z,Z  next three terms equal the previous term
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 17 bytes

```
91,65>''+{...}%n*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/39JQx8zUTl1du1pPT69WNU/r/38A)

## Explanation

```
91,65>            # Genearate initial alphabet
      ''+         # Convert to a string
         {...}%   # For every item, copy 3 times
               n* # Join the resulting string by newlines
                  # (because a string is a codepoint array)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 16 bytes

```
@AZr@4?*{)'
}\mQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f/fwTGqyMHEXqtaU52rNiY38P9/AA)

```
@AZr@ # Array of A-Z as chars
4?*   # 4 of each as strings
{
 )'   # Add a newline between each letter
}\m   # Map for each string of 4 and concatenate
Q     # Pretty print for newlines instead of "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 40

Output per cell:

```
=ArrayFormula(CHAR(SEQUENCE(104,1,260)/4
```

If newlines are important, 49:

```
=ArrayFormula(JOIN("
",CHAR(SEQUENCE(104,1,260)/4
```

No, `Sequence` does not support floating point steps.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 26 bytes

```julia
@.print((('A':'Z')*"
")^4)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/30GvoCgzr0RDQ0PdUd1KPUpdU0uJS0kzzkTz/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 43 bytes

```hs
main=mapM(putStrLn.pure)$['A'..'Z']<*[1..4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM882N7HAV6OgtCS4pMgnT6@gtChVUyVa3VFdT089Sj3WRivaUE/PJPb/fwA)

This has two parts `mapM(putStrLn.pure)` takes a list of characters and prints each on it's own line.

`['A'..'Z']<*[1..4]` produces the list of desired characters.  It does this with the monadic operator `(<*)` which works like `(>>)` except it keeps the values from the first arguement instead of the second.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 21 bytes

```
=CHAR(ROW(260:363)/4)
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnHQ1v6GahNPEv61X?e=HHBGzl)

I think this would have worked when the question was asked if 104 cells were selected and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> were used.

Answer (score 1):

**Python 3, <s>46</s> 45 bytes**

```
print(*["\n%c"%(i//4+65)for i in range(104)])
```

**Python 3, 39 bytes**

```
for i in range(104):print(chr(i//4+65))
```

I prefer the first solution for being a true one-liner. But a correction of [Justin's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9498/justin) answer leads to a shorter solution.

Comment: You can save a byte with `"\n%c"%(i//4+65)` on your first program: [TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQytaKSZPNVlJVSNTX99E28xUMy2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw9DARDNW8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## F#, 57 bytes

```fs
for i in 97..122 do for _ in 0..3 do printf"%c\n"(char i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWzc3Py///Py2/SCFTITNPwdJcT8/QyEghJV8BJBYPEjPQ0zMGCRQUZeaVpCmpJsfkKWkkZyQCtWj@/w8A)

Loop through the alphabet (`for i in 97..122`), then through 4 times (`for _ in 0..3`), and finally print the character with a newline (`printf"%c\n"(char i)`).

Here is another one, 71 bytes:

```fs
for i in 97..122 do printf"%s"(String.replicate 4(string(char i)+"\n"))
```

Ungolfed code:

```fs
for i in 97..122 do for _ in 0..3 do printf "%c\n" (char i)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Noether](https://github.com/beta-decay/Noether), 22 bytes

```
65~i91(0~l4(iBP?!l)!i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8tPLclILfr/38y0LtPSUMOgLsdEI9MpwF4xR1MxU/P/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 21 bytes

```
eval '<<<'{A..Z}{,,,}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhZbU8sScxTUbWxs1Ksd9fSiaqt1dHRqIXJQJTClAA)

Comment: Nice one, taking advantage of the fact that a bare here-string (or here-doc) in zsh acts like there's a `cat` in front of it. Clever!

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 48 bytes

```
=flatten(sort(if({1,1,1,1},char(row(A65:A90)))))
```

Comment: you can get this down to 25 bytes if you port over [Axuary's Excel answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235083/61846) as `=Sort(Char(Row(260:363)/4` (Sheets handles arrays quite differently) or 38 bytes by optimizing your addresses, and removing the `if` function as `=Flatten(Sort(Char({1,1,1,1}*Row(65:90`

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-n`, 10 bytes

```
_MWV(zRL4)
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJfTVdWKHpSTDQpIiwiIiwiIiwiLW4iXQ==)

```
_MWV(zRL4)
    (zRL4)     ; repeat z="abcde...xyz" 4 times, forming the list [z,z,z,z]
  WV           ; weave the the 4 z's together, forming the string "aaaabbbb...yyyyzzzz"
_M             ; convert to a list
               ; implicitly joined by newlines by the -n flag and printed
```

Answer (score 1):

### **Excel**, 28 bytes.

```
=CHAR(SEQUENCE(104,,65,1/4))
```

*No need to drag it will spill if one uses* **MS365** or **Excel 2021**.

Answer (score 0):

## [///](http://esolangs.org/wiki////), 207 bytes

```
A
A
A
A
B
B
B
B
C
C
C
C
D
D
D
D
E
E
E
E
F
F
F
F
G
G
G
G
H
H
H
H
I
I
I
I
J
J
J
J
K
K
K
K
L
L
L
L
M
M
M
M
N
N
N
N
O
O
O
O
P
P
P
P
Q
Q
Q
Q
R
R
R
R
S
S
S
S
T
T
T
T
U
U
U
U
V
V
V
V
W
W
W
W
X
X
X
X
Y
Y
Y
Y
Z
Z
Z
Z
```

Answer (score 0):

## bash shell, 19 bytes

```bash
echo {A..Z}{,,,}'
'
```

Comment: This seems to print `\n` instead of actual newlines between characters. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1@h2lFPL6q2WkdHp1Y9Jk/9/38A "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: @WheatWizard Replace `\n` with a real line feed. It's more a wrong byte count

Comment: You can use ANSI quotes. `echo {A..Z}{,,,}$'\n'` That takes it to 21 bytes. You also have a leading space before every letter except the first A. You can fix that by using `printf %s\\n {A..Z}{,,,}` at a cost of taking it to 24 bytes.

Comment: yeah, thks for that.

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `sequences.repeating spelling`, 38 bytes

```factor
ALPHABET 4 repeat 10 interleaved print
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sLTG5JL9owU3L0GBPP3crheKC1JyczLx0heLUwtLUvOTUYr2i1ILUxBJUsdSKkqLEYoXMfAXrpaUlaboWN9UcfQI8HJ1cQxRMFCA6FAwNFDLzSlKLclITy1JTFAqKgDyI6gVQCkoDAA)

```
ALPHABET       ! "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
4 repeat       ! "aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffffgggghhhhiiiijjjjkkkkllllmmmmnnnnooooppppqqqqrrrrssssttttuuuuvvvvwwwwxxxxyyyyzzzz"
10 interleaved ! "a\na\na\na\nb\nb\nb\nb\nc\nc\nc\nc\nd\nd\nd\nd\ne\ne\ne\ne\nf\nf\nf\nf\ng\ng\ng\ng\nh\nh\nh\nh\ni\ni\ni\ni\nj\nj\nj\nj\nk\nk\nk\nk\nl\nl\nl\nl\nm\nm\nm\nm\nn\nn\nn\nn\no\no\no\no\np\np\np\np\nq\nq\nq\nq\nr\nr\nr\nr\ns\ns\ns\ns\nt\nt\nt\nt\nu\nu\nu\nu\nv\nv\nv\nv\nw\nw\nw\nw\nx\nx\nx\nx\ny\ny\ny\ny\nz\nz\nz\nz"
print          ! (print to stdout)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wren](https://wren.io/), 57 bytes

```wren
for(c in 65..90)System.write((String.fromByte(c)+"\n")*4)
```

[Try Wren](https://wren.io/try/?code=GYewTgFAxgBAlgOxgNgKwDp0E4AMBKAZQE8BnAFwFMBbdAdzDkoggLIYQHN1gwQqAhIkyh4A1ACIAOgnF4AVABY8QA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Headascii](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass#Headascii), 59 bytes

```
+++++[]]ONE.+++++[]]]]]++^[]]+[U{D-^)!:RP]PRP]PRP]PRP]PN][}
```

["Try it" on DSO](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIiwiIiwiKysrKytbXV1PTkUuKysrKytbXV1dXV0rK15bXV0rW1V7RC1eKSE6UlBdUFJQXVBSUF1QUlBdUE5dW30iLCIiLCIiLCIiXQ==) (links to a version which only supports number output, but should get the point across)

Alternatively, [try it here](https://replit.com/@thejonymyster/HA23), but code will have to be pasted in as shown:

```js
erun("+++++[]]ONE.+++++[]]]]]++^[]]+[U{D-^)!:RP]PRP]PRP]PRP]PN][}")
```

short breakdown:

```
+++++[]]O                                        save 10 to global array
         NE                                      go to next code block
.                                                code block separator
+++++[]]]]]++^                                   set r1 to 27
              []]+[                              set r2 to 55
                   U                             grab 10 from the global array
                    {D-^) :                   }  while --r1 + 1 != 0
                           RP                      send out ascii 10 (newline)
                             ]P                    send out ascii 10 + r2 (letter)
                               RP]PRP]PRP]P        (four times total)
                                           N][     r2++
                         !                       finally, print all 'send out' chars
```

However, I must note that if instead of using `erun` we run it with `lrun`, newlines are automatically appended at the end of each print (and `!` is no longer required because technically it's a Headass program), making this 38 byter possible:

## [Headass](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass) `lrun`, 38 bytes

```
+++++[]]]]]++^+++++[]][{D-^):N][]PPPP}
```

[DSO link, still prints as numbers](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIiwiIiwiKysrKytbXV1dXV0rK14rKysrK1tdXVt7RC1eKTpOXVtdUFBQUH0iLCIiLCIiLCIiXQ==), [must-paste-in-code interpreter link](https://replit.com/@thejonymyster/HA23)

Which... I guess its just dawning on me that that's a different.. Version? ...But I'm not going to go and mark all my Headas(s|cii) answers based on which "interpreter" they use unless it's actually relevant to the challenge :P

Oh and of course, a breakdown:

```
+++++[]]]]]++^                          set r1 to 27
              +++++[]][                 set r2 to 64
                       {D-^):        }  while --r1 != 0
                             N][]PPPP     print ++r2 four times
```