# Create a programming language interpreter

Tags: popularity-contest, interpreter, parsing

**Task:**

You must create an interpreter that can parse snippets of a programming language. The language does not need to be complex, but it must include the following syntactical elements:

- Ability to assign and read variables (could be as simple as `a`-`z` being premade variables)
- If statements (elseif and else are not required)
- Loops (counting to an arbitrary number, user access to counter is not required)
- Simple math with variables (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, greater/less than, equals)
- Print statements

**Rules:**

- You may not copy the syntax of another popular language.
- You need to write your own interpreter, not modification of another interpreter.
- You can write your interpreter in any language.
- Write a 99-bottles-of-beer example program in your language (see [here](http://99-bottles-of-beer.net/lyrics.html))
- This is a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so the most upvoted answer wins.

Comment: What are the requirements of the parser? Does it need to output some kind of syntax tree?

Comment: Request for clarification: Does the programming language have to have a special syntax for loops counting to an arbitrary number or does it just have to support those loops?

Comment: Is being able to push and pop from a stack enough to satisfy the variable requirement?

Comment: @tecywiz121 - yep

Comment: @Dennis - it must be able to loop a given number of times, defined at runtime

Comment: Kendall Frey's question about a massively important missimg part of the spec still needs an answer.

Comment: @KendallFrey - it must execute the code, no syntax tree or bootleg compilers are needed.

Comment: I believe that makes it an interpreter, no?

Comment: Kinda want to see Guido submit CPython.

Answer (score 18):

### DogeScript

The 99 bottles of beer program:

```
many amaze 99 time

such scare bottles-of-beer
such scream on-the-wall
many despair 13 time

such fail take-one-down-pass-it-around

wow

so amaze
so scare
so scream
so despair!

so amaze
so scare
so despair!

much amaze

so fail
so despair!

so amaze
so scare
so scream

so despair!
so despair!

very amaze

wow
```

The PHP interpreter:

```
<?php
$input=fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

//pre-process input
$input=preg_replace("/ +/", " ", $input); //replace any multiple spaces by a single space

//split into instructions by newlines
$instructions=explode("\n", $input);

$loopstartpoint= -1;
$variables=array();
$activevariable="";
for($instrpointer=0; $instrpointer<count($instructions); $instrpointer++)
{
    $tokens=explode(" ", $instructions[$instrpointer]);
    switch($tokens[0])
    {
        case "wow":
            if($loopstartpoint<0)
            {
                $loopstartpoint=$instrpointer+1;
            }
            else
            {
                if($variables[ $activevariable ])
                {
                    $instrpointer=$loopstartpoint;
                }
                else
                {
                    $loopstartpoint= -1;
                }
            }
            break;
        case "so":
            if(substr($tokens[1], -1)=="!")
            {
                echo chr($variables[ substr($tokens[1], 0, -1) ]);
            }
            else
            {
                echo $variables[ $tokens[1] ];
                echo " ";
            }
            break;
        case "very":
            $activevariable=$tokens[1];
            break;
        case "much":
            if(!isset($variables[ $tokens[1] ]))
                $variables[ $tokens[1] ]=0;
            if(count($tokens)==2)
            {
                $variables[ $tokens[1] ]--;
            }
            else
            {
                for($loop=0;$loop<$tokens[2];$loop++)
                {
                    $variables[ $tokens[1] ]--;
                }
            }
            $activevariable=$tokens[1];
            break;
        case "many":
            if(!isset($variables[ $tokens[1] ]))
                $variables[ $tokens[1] ]=0;
            if(count($tokens)==2)
            {
                $variables[ $tokens[1] ]++;
            }
            else
            {
                for($loop=0;$loop<$tokens[2];$loop++)
                {
                    $variables[ $tokens[1] ]++;
                }
            }
            $activevariable=$tokens[1];
            break;
        case "such":
            $variables[ $tokens[1] ]=$tokens[2];
            $activevariable=$tokens[1];
            break;
    }
}
?>
```

The syntax as it currently stands:

```
wow - start and end loops, end of loop checks if active variable is 0 and loops if not
so without ! - print variable's value
so with ! - print variable's ASCII character
much - decrement this variable
many - increment this variable
such - set variable
very - make variable active
x time - does previous statement x times

Variables are initially 0.
```

Try it [here](http://ideone.com/Gz0ZBT).
Any suggestions for improvement are welcome.

Comment: prgramming lvl = 100

Comment: Do you know that it [already exists](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Dogescript)?

Comment: No, I'd never seen that. Bummer, I thought I was being original. :-(

Answer (score 10):

## BrainBack : A stack based compiled language running on BrainFuck

*NB: Spec was changed from "creating a parser" to "create an interpreter" after i posted this answer. This answer is a compiler which also parses source code.*

The name is a pun on *Back* being the opposite of a well known stack based language and *Brain* indicating it's esoteric nature. It looks a little like BrainFuck (though isn't), but it's compiler runs on BrainFuck and it's compiled object code ends up as BrainFuck binaries.

The language: *==destroys it's arguments

- `"constant"` prints constant
- `#`          prints top of stack as number
- `>`          duplicates the top of stack
- `<num>`      push constant number `<num>` as a value to top of stack
- `<`          remove top of stack
- `-`          substract topmost from the second topmost*
- `+`          add topmost to second topmost*
- `!`          not toggles positive / zero*
- `[ ... ]`    does a while top of stack not zero, very similar to BrainFuck

99 bottles of beer with correct lyrics in BrainBack:

```
100
[
 1 -
 > ! [ < 0 0 "No more" ] < [ # 0 ] <
 " bottle"
 > 1 - [ < 0 "s" ] < 
 " of beer on the wall, "
 > ! [ < 0 0 "no more" ] < [ # 0 ] <
 " bottle"
 > 1 - [ < 0 "s" ] < 
 " of beer.
"
 > ! [ < 0 0 "Go to the store and buy some more, " ] < 
     [ "Take one down and pass it around, " 0 ] <

 > ! [ < 1 0 0 "99" ] < [ > 1 - > !  [ < < 1 0 0 "no more" ] < [ # 1 - 0 ] ] <
 " bottle"
 [ < 0 "s" ] <
 " of beer on the wall.

"
]
```

The BrainBack compiler, written in [Extended BrainFuck](http://sylwester.no/ebf/)

```
;;; Macros

;; utility function that substracts 
;; ^2 from ^0 without reduceing ^2 
;; below zero. ^1 needs to be zero
{substract 
  (<<[->]>[<]>-)
}


;; Main macro is the main  program and
;; has the overal structure of the program.
;; every macro here is define in order below.
{main
  :i
  :wrk
  :tmp
  :else
  :sub 
  $i+(
  ; switch ( $wrk ) cases '"#><-+![]9;' using $tmp,$else
  $tmp+++++(-$wrk------)+$wrk---; !
  ($wrk-; "
    ($wrk-; #
      ($wrk--------; +
        ($wrk--; -
          ($wrk--- $tmp- $else 9+ &substract $tmp+ $wrk; 0-9
            ($wrk--; ;
              ($wrk-; <
                ($wrk--; >
                  ($tmp++++(-$wrk------)+$wrk+; [
                    ($wrk--; ]
                      (#(-) $tmp(-)  no matches)
                        $tmp (- #match 'cl'  &close        )
                    ) $tmp (- #match 'op'    &open         )
                  ) $tmp (- #match 'gt'      &dup          )
                ) $tmp (- #match 'lt'        &slash        )
              ) $tmp (  #match 'c'           &comment      )
            ) $tmp (- #match 0 to 9          &read_number  )
          ) $tmp (- #match 'minus'           &sub          )
        ) $tmp (- #match 'plus'              &add          )
      ) $tmp (- #match '#'                   &print_number )
    ) $tmp (- #match '"'                     &print_string )
  ) $tmp (- #match 'not'                     &not          )

  $i(-)$tmp#,+(-(-$wrk+$i+)))
  10+.
}

;; implements close bracket
{close 
    |" close"(-)
    $i.
}

;; implements open bracket
{open 
    |" open"(-)
    $i.
}

;; implements dup/>
{dup
    |"dup [->>+<<]>>[-<+<+>>]<
"
     (-)
}

;; implements slash/<
{slash
     |"slash [-]<
"
     (-)
}

;; implements comment
{comment
  [,10-]
}

;; implements read_number/<number>
;; makes code that if run makes 
;; the constant
{read_number
  ;TODO: compiler_read_constant_number
   $wrk|"number"(-)
#  $wrk 6+ (- $i 8-)
  ~"+>"<.(-)
  $i+(-(-$wrk.)
     #$else, $tmp 6+ (- $else 8-)
     $else(-$tmp+$i+)
     $sub 9+ &substract
     $else+
     $tmp((-) $i(-) $else-)
     $else(-|"[->++++++++++<]>[-<+>]<"(-)$i+)
     )
   $wrk(-)
   |"
"(-)
}

;; implements sub/-
{sub
     |"sub [-<->]<
"
     (-)
}

;; implements add/+
{add
     |"#add [-<+>]<
"
     (-)
}

;; implements print_number/#
{print_number
  |"print [->+<]>[-<+>>+<]>
    [>++++++++++<
    [->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]
    +>[-]>[-<<+>>]>[-<<+>>]<<]
    +<[>-<[<]]>[>]
    <[>++++++[-<++++++++>]<-.[-]<]<
"(-)
 
}

;; implements print_string/"..."
;; this outputs EBF code making the
;; object code EBF
{print_string
  |"print >|"(-) 
  $i(-$wrk+$else+)
  $wrk($tmp(-$wrk+)$wrk.,$else(-$tmp+$wrk-$i+)$i(-$else+))
  $tmp(-)$else.(-)|"[-]<
"(-)
}

;; implements not/!
;; creates code that negates top of stack
{not
  |"not >+<[[-]>-]>[<+>->]<<
"(-)
}

&main
```

To compile BrainBack:

```
bf ebf.bf < BrainBack.ebf > BrainBack.bf
```

To compile a BrainBack program:

```
bf BrainBack.bf < 99.bb > 99.ebf # compile from bb to ebf
bf ebf.bf < 99.ebf > 99.bf       # compile from ebf to bf
```

Run the binary:

```
bf 99.bf
```

Here i use [bf](http://pkqs.net/%7Esbeyer/) which is available in most debian distros. `beef` and others can be used as well. Both EBF compiler, BrainBack and its object code becomes quite compatible BrainFuck binaries.

It probably should be extended to print a cell as ascii `.`, be able to read a byte in `,` and to have various `swap` operations to be more useful. It's absolutely needed in order to make a BrainBack compiler or interpreter in BrainBack.

Comment: Wow! You're at 1337 rep points right now ... almost don't want to upvote and spoil the number! :)

Answer (score 6):

## €

I spend most of my time on PHP scripts and it brought me a question: why am I forced to use `$` for my variables names? `€` is my local currency, so let's use it! Since € is used in many countries, I used some words from EU languages as keywords.

```
€beers gleich 99
€bottles gleich bottles of beer
€bottles_on_the_wall gleich bottles of beer on the wall

mientras €beers topogleich 3
    afficher €beers €bottles_on_the_wall
    afficher , €beers €bottles
    afficher . NETHERLANDS
    odejmowanie €beers
    
    afficher Take one down and pass it around, €beers
    afficher €bottles_on_the_wall
    afficher . NETHERLANDS NETHERLANDS
sartneim

afficher 2 bottles of beer on the wall, 2 bottles of beer. NETHERLANDS
afficher Take one down and pass it around, 1 bottle of beer on the wall.
afficher NETHERLANDS NETHERLANDS

afficher 1 bottle of beer on the wall, 1 bottle of beer. NETHERLANDS
afficher Take one down and pass it around, no more bottles of beer on the wall.
afficher NETHERLANDS NETHERLANDS

afficher No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer. NETHERLANDS
afficher Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.
afficher NETHERLANDS NETHERLANDS
```

Keywords:

- `gleich` is *equal* in German
- `mientras` is *while* in Spanish
- `topo` is *greater* in Portuguese (update: it should be *maior* instead, thanks to [daHugLenny](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56258/dahuglenny) for the tip)
- `odejmowanie` is *subtract* in Polish
- `afficher` is *print* in French
- newlines are called `nl` sometimes, and the TLD of `NETHERLANDS` is `nl`, so I defined a constant `NETHERLANDS` to display newlines

I cheated a little bit since there is no `if` keyword, I chose to directly print the last two lines.

### Interpreter in Python

The interpreter won't do more than execute the script to display 99 bottles of beers.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655836/writing-an-xml-file-that-contains-a-euro-symbol-in-python-using-xml-etree/12655861#12655861

# =             gleich (german)
# while         mientras (spanish)
# >             topo (portuguese) (it should be "maior" instead)
# subtract      odejmowanie (polish
# print         afficher (french)
# newline       NETHERLANDS

import sys, codecs

class euro:
    symbols = {}
    sign = u'€'
    
    def executeLine(self, line):
        s = line.split(' ')
        
        if s[0] == 'afficher':
            buffer = []
            
            for a in s[1:]:
                if (a == ''):
                    continue
                elif (a[0] == self.sign):
                    buffer.append(str(self.getSymbol(a)))
                elif (a == 'NETHERLANDS'):
                    buffer.append("\n")
                else :
                    buffer.append(a)
                
            sys.stdout.write(' '.join(buffer))
            # @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499073/printing-without-newline-print-a-prints-a-space-how-to-remove/4499172#4499172
        elif s[0] == 'odejmowanie':
            self.setSymbol(s[1], (int(self.getSymbol(s[1])) - 1))
        elif (len(s) >= 3) and (s[1] == 'gleich'):
            self.setSymbol(s[0], (' ').join(s[2:]))
    
    def executeBlock(self, lines, statement):
        while (self.getStatement(statement)):
            for line in lines:
                self.executeLine(line)
    
    def getStatement(self, statement):
        if (statement[1] == 'topogleich'):
            return self.getSymbol(statement[0]) >= int(statement[2])
    
    def setSymbol(self, name, value):
        name = self.withoutEuro(name)
        self.symbols[name] = value
    
    def getSymbol(self, name):
        #~ print symbols, withoutEuro(name)
        name = self.withoutEuro(name)
        if name in self.symbols:
            value = self.symbols[name]
            
            return value
        else :
            print "\n-----\n",'Error: "', name, '"is not in', self.symbols, '-----'
            
            #~ sys.exit()

    def withoutEuro(self, string):
        return(string.replace(self.sign, ''))
    
    def parseFile(self, f):
        linesStack = []
        
        for line in codecs.open(f, 'r', 'utf-8'):
            line = line.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '')
            s = line.split(' ')
            
            if (len(s) == 1) & (s[0] == '') :
                continue
            
            if (s[0] == 'mientras'):
                statement = s[1:]
                
                linesStack.append(line)
            elif (s[0] == 'sartneim'):
                linesStack.append(line)
                
                self.executeBlock(linesStack, statement)
                
                linesStack = []
                statement = ''
            elif (len(linesStack) > 0):
                linesStack.append(line)
            else:
                self.executeLine(line)

euro = euro()
euro.parseFile(sys.argv[1])
```

To run it, save both files then run the Python file with the `.eu` script as an argument:

```
python euro.py euro.eu
```

Comment: +1! Reminds me of 'If PHP Were British': https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/if-php-were-british/

Comment: This language has been documented on [Esolang](https://esolangs.org/wiki/%E2%82%AC).

Comment: `topo` is _top_ in Portuguese

Comment: @daHugLenny I'm sorry for the mistake. Is *maior* the correct translation of *greater*?

Comment: @A.L yes. (_comments need to be at least 15 chars_)

Answer (score 5):

## 1Lang

1Lang is a functional prefix language like LISP or Scheme but without parentheses that makes it a bit harder to read when all unnecessary white-space is removed. Parentheses can be removed since all functions and operators take a known number of parameters.

Braces are required to delimit function body and conditional consequence and alternate code blocks which can consist of a list of statements.

In LISP, Factorial might be defined like this:

```
(defun fact (x) (if (< x 2) 1 (* x (fact (- x 1))) ) )
```

in 1Lang this would be

```
@Fx{ ? < x 2 {1} {* x F -x1} }
```

which can be reduced to

```
@Fx{?<x2{1}{*xF-x1}}
```

1Lang currently supports no side-effects.

1Lang is written in bash so it currently shares some bash limitations such as integer range.

```
a-z are variables. Variable are either integers, strings, or lists.
```

NB: Lists are not fully implemented.

```
A-Z are functions
```

Integers are bash integers (up to -2^32 to 2^31-1 I think). Negative numbers can not be directly used. To enter a negative, subtract it from zero. eg. -5 would be entered as -0 5. This limitation is because 1Lang is a work in progress and negative numbers were not needed for this application. I am considering using ~ as a unary negative operator which would allow -5 to be input as ~5.

White-space is required to delineate integers. eg. +2 3

```
: means assign                                    eg. :c34 to assign 34 to c
+-*/% are binary integer operators                eg. +12 34
&|^ are binary bit-wise operators
! is unary boolean not
~ is unary one's complement
? is a if-then-else function-like operator.       eg. ?=x3{*xx}{0} is x=3 return x*x else 0
+ is also a binary string concatenation operator  eg. +99" bottles"
* is also a string repetition operator            eg. *5" hello" or *" hello"5
@ defines a function                              eg. @Fx{?<x1{1}{*xF-x1}}
```

Function parameter names may overload callers variables.
All variables assigned within a function are local.

Printing is not necessary (although it could be useful) because like LISP every statement returns a value, and last value returned is printed.

```
eg. +2 3 prints 5
```

An unexpected behaviour of prefix notation without parentheses is that string concatenation can actually be easy to write. Say you want to concatenate `"a" " quick" " brown" " fox"`, one might write:

```
+++"a"" quick"" brown"" fox"
```

But a more readable and less error prone method is this:

```
+"a"+" quick"+" brown"" fox" (Note missing + between last terms)
```

or

```
+"a"+" quick"+" brown"+" fox"""
```

99 Bottles of beer code:

```
:b" of beer"
:w" on the wall"
:t"Take one down and pass it around, "
:s"Go to the store and buy some more, "
:c", "
:n".\n"
@Bx{?=x0{+"No more bottles"b}{+x+" bottle"+?=x1{""}{"s"}b}}
@Fx{?=x0{+B0+w+c+B0+n+s+B99+wn}{+Bx+w+c+Bx+n+t+B-x1+w+n+"\n"F-x1}}
F99
```

Function B returns "No more bottles" or "1 bottle" or " bottles" depending on x.

Function F returns normal verses or final verse. A normal verse is concatenated with following verse by recursively calling F with -x1. When x is 0, F returns final verse.

This generates (for F5 meaning start at 5 bottles of beer...):

```
> F5
5 bottles of beer on the wall, 5 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 4 bottles of beer on the wall.

4 bottles of beer on the wall, 4 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 3 bottles of beer on the wall.

3 bottles of beer on the wall, 3 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 2 bottles of beer on the wall.

2 bottles of beer on the wall, 2 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 1 bottle of beer on the wall.

1 bottle of beer on the wall, 1 bottle of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, No more bottles of beer on the wall.

No more bottles of beer on the wall, No more bottles of beer.
Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.
<End>
```

### 1Lang interpreter (written in bash) in under 500 lines.

```
#!/bin/bash

LC_ALL=C  # else [a-z] and [A-Z] misbehave

# functions return result on stdout
# functions have an environment

# Requirements:
# * minimise size
#   -> eliminate delimiters
#   -> single letter variables and functions
#   -> no precidence
#   -> no overloading
# * 

# string "text with \characters as per printf"
# numbers 123
# functions F3
# Built-ins +-*/%^ &|~ ! etc.
# assignment :v12 :v"string"

log(){  local m="${l:p}" m="${m//[$NL]/\n}" v="${FUNCNAME[1]}"; echo "$v: l=[${l//[$NL]/\n}] ch=[${ch/[$NL]/\n}] next=[$m]" >&2; }
logr(){ local m="${l:p}" m="${m//[$NL]/\n}" v="${FUNCNAME[1]}"; echo "$v: l=[${l//[$NL]/\n}] ch=[${ch/[$NL]/\n}] next=[$m] ret=[${ret//[$NL]/\n}]" >&2; }
logv(){ local        v="${FUNCNAME[1]}"; echo "$v: ret=[${ret//[$NL]/\n}]" >&2; }
logm(){ local m="$1" v="${FUNCNAME[1]}"; echo "$v: ${m//[$NL]/\n} in [${read//[$NL]/\n}]." >&2; }

msg(){ echo -En "$1" >&2; }
msn(){ echo -E  "$1" >&2; }

# ==========
# Line layer
# ==========

declare l
readline(){ read -rp"1lang> " l; }

#==================
# Environment Layer
#==================

declare -A v t  # variables and variable type
declare ret typ  # all bash function return these values

# assign = : var expression
assign(){
  local var
  readch
  var && var=$ret || { logm "ERROR: variable name expected"      ; return 1; }
  exp             || { logm "ERROR: value or expression expected"; return 1; }
  v["$var"]="$ret"
  t["$var"]="$typ"
}

# get variable value
get(){
  local var
  var && var=$ret || { logm "ERROR: variable name expected"; return 1; }
  ret=${v["$var"]}
  typ=${t["$var"]}
}

declare -A func fpar 
declare -iA fnum                 # functions
# define = @ F param* { body } 
define(){
  local fn par body
  readch
  fn && fn=$ret || { logm "ERROR: function name expected"; return 1; }
  fpar[$fn]=                     # zero parameters
  fnum[$fn]=                     # zero parameter counter
  while var;do                   # read parameters
    fpar[$fn]+=$ret
    fnum[$fn]+=1                 # cound parameters
  done
  # get body but remove block delimiters
  skip "{" "}" && body="${ret:1: -1}" || { logm "ERROR: function body expected"; return 1; }
  readch                         # skip }
  func[$fn]="$body"              # store function body
  ret="@$fn${fpar[$fn]}{$body}"
  typ='f'
}

apply(){
  local fn=$ch n c s; local -i N q
  readch
  N=${fnum[$fn]}   # number of parameters
  n=${fpar[$fn]}   # parameters
  s=${func[$fn]}   # function body
  c=
  for((q=0; q<N; q++)){
    exp || { logm "ERROR: value expected"; return 1; }  
    c+="v[${n:q:1}]=\"$ret\"; "  # add value to script
    c+="t[${n:q:1}]=\"$typ\"; "  # add type to script
  }
  # parse function in a subshell and echo result and type back 
  # subshell means all variable changes in function are local
  c+="parse <<<'$s'; echo -E \"\$typ\$ret\""  # combine type and value
  ret=
  typ=
  ret="$( eval "$c" )" || { logm "ERROR: function application failed"; return 1; }
  typ="${ret::1}"  # extract type
  ret="${ret:1}"   # get actual return value
}

# bash oddities:

# [[ 1 -eq 1 ]] -> 0 or success
# [[ 1 -eq 2 ]] -> 1 or failed

# x=1\<2 -> a=1 (true)
# x=1\<1 -> a=0 (false)

# ((1==1)) -> 0 or success
# ((1==2)) -> 1 or failed

# declare -i a; a=1==1 -> a=1 (true)
# declare -i a; a=1==2 -> a=0  (false)

binary(){
  local -i iret; local op=$ch a b at bt
  readch
  exp && { a="$ret"; at=$typ; } || { logm "ERROR: initial expression expected"; return 1; }
  exp && { b="$ret"; bt=$typ; } || { logm "ERROR: second expression expected"  ; return 1; }
  ret=
  typ=
  case "$at$bt" in
    nn)  # num op num
      case "$op" in
        [\*]) iret=a*b;;
        [\^]) iret=a**b;;
        [\+]) iret=a+b;;
        [\-]) iret=a-b;;
        [\/]) [[ b -ne 0 ]] && { iret=a/b; } || { logm "ERROR: division by 0"       ; return 1; };;
        [\%]) [[ b -ne 0 ]] && { iret=a%b; } || { logm "ERROR: modulo division by 0"; return 1; };;
        [\&]) iret=a\&b;;
        [\|]) iret=a\|b;;
        [\#]) iret=a\^b;;
        [\=]) iret=a==b;;
        [\<]) iret=a\<b;;
        [\>]) iret=a\>b;;
      esac
      ret=$iret
      typ='n';;  # result is always a decimal number
    ss)  # string op string
      case "$op" in
#        [\*]) arith=a*b;;  # combine?
#        [\#]) arith=${}a**b; type='s';;
        [\+]) ret="$a$b"; typ='s';;  # concatenate
        [\-]) ret="${a//$b}"; typ='s';;  # remove substrings
        [\=]) [[ $a = $b ]]; ret=$?; typ='n';;
        [\<]) [[ $a < $b ]]; ret=$?; typ='n';;
        [\>]) [[ $a > $b ]]; ret=$?; typ='n';;
      esac;;
    ns)  # num op string  =3"hello"  ="hello"3  ="3"3  =3"4"
      case "$op" in
        [\+]) ret="$a$b"; typ='s';;  # concatenate
        [\*]) ret=$(eval echo \"\${b[0]\"{1..$a}\"}\"); typ='s';;  # repeat b a times
        [\=]) ((${#b}==a)); ret=$?; typ='n';;  # length b is a
#        [\<]) [[ $a < $b ]]; arith=$?; typ='n';;
#        [\>]) [[ $a > $b ]]; arith=$?; typ='n';;
      esac;;
    sn)  # string op num  *"hello"3  ="3"3  =3"4"
      case "$op" in
        [\+]) ret="$a$b"; typ='s';;  # concatenate
        [\*]) ret=$(eval echo \"\${a[0]\"{1..$b}\"}\"); typ='s';;  # repeat a b times
        [\=]) ((${#a}==b)); ret=$?; typ='n';;  # length a is b
#        [\<]) [[ $a < $b ]]; arith=$?; typ='n';;
#        [\>]) [[ $a > $b ]]; arith=$?; typ='n';;
      esac;;
    *) logm "ERROR: undefined operation [$op] for [$a] [$at] and [$b] [$bt]"; return 1;
  esac
  return 0
}

# FIXME: string ops?
unary(){
  local -i iret; local op="$ch"
  readch
  exp || { logm "ERROR: expression expected"; return 1; }
  case "$op" in
    [\!]) iret=\!ret;;
    [\~]) iret=\~ret;;
  esac
  ret=$iret
  typ='n'  # result is always a decimal number
}

#==============
# Control Layer
#==============

# iff = ? boolean { consequence block } { alternative block }
# ?<1 2{+4 5}{+1 2}
iff(){
  local -i c; local iff ift
  readch
  exp && c=$ret || { logm "ERROR: value or expression expected"; return 1; }
  [[ c -eq 1 ]] && {  # true so do consequence
    ws
    block && { iff="$ret"; ift="$typ"; } || { logm "ERROR: consequence block error"; return 1; }
    ws
    skip "{" "}" || { logm "ERROR: alternate block expected"; return 1; }
    ret="$iff"
    typ="$ift"
  } || {
    ws
    skip "{" "}" || { logm "ERROR: consequence block expected"; return 1; }
    ws
    block || { logm "ERROR: alternate block error"; return 1; }
  }
}

#==============
# Symbols Layer
#==============

# fn = [A-Z]
fn(){
# FIXME: make evalu?
  [[ $ch = [A-Z] ]] || return 1
  ret=$ch
  typ='c'
  readch
}

# var = [a-z]
var(){
# FIXME: make evalu?
  [[ $ch = [a-z] ]] || return 1
  ret=$ch
  typ='c'
  readch
}

# list = ( token* )
# FIXME: not finished and no operators support lists
list(){
  local list=$ch prev
  readch
  while [[ $ch != ')' ]];do
    exp || { logm "ERROR: expression expected"; return 1; }
    case $typ in
      [n]) list+=" $ret";;
      [s]) list+="$ret";;
      [l]) list+="$ret";;
    esac
    ws
  done
  ret="$list$ch"
  readch
  typ='l'
  return 0
}

#============
# Token Layer
#============

# char = ' echoch
#echoch = \ {special echo escape character} | {char}
char(){
  readch
  case "$ch" in
    [\\]) escch || { logm "ERROR: escape character expected"; return 1; };;
       ?) ret="$ch"; readch
  esac
  typ='c'
}

# escaped characters are a pain
# use read with -r to read in verbatim - no escaping
# use echo -E to write out verbatim (except \\ may be processed)

declare escchS
declare ECHO='abefnrtv'
# double \\ for a \
escch(){
  local ESC="$ch"
  readch    # skip \
  case "$ch" in
    [$ECHO])                   printf -v ret "%b" "$ESC$ch"; readch;;
       [\\]) ret="\\"; readch;;
       [\"]) ret="\""; readch;;
      [0-7])         onum && { printf -v ret "%b" "$ESC$ret"   ; } || { logm "ERROR: octal number expected"; return 1; };;
       [xU]) readch; hnum && { printf -v ret "%b" "${ESC}x$ret"; } || { logm "ERROR: hex number expected"  ; return 1; };;
          ?) ret="$ch"
             [[ $escchS ]] || {
               tidyReadCh
               logm "WARNING: only octal, hex, unicode, and [$ECHO\\\"] characters need to be escaped with '$ESC'"
               logm "WARNING: [$ch] in [$l] does not need to be escaped"
               escchS="OFF"
             }
             readch
  esac
  typ='c'
}

#  num =  digit  digit*
# onum = odigit odigit*
# onum = hdigit hdigit*

num(){  local num; num=$ch; readch; while  digit;do num+=$ret; done; ret=$num; typ='n'; }
onum(){ local num; num=$ch; readch; while odigit;do num+=$ret; done; ret=$num; typ='n'; }
hnum(){ local num; num=$ch; readch; while hdigit;do num+=$ret; done; ret=$num; typ='n'; }

#  digit = [0-9]
# odigit = [0-7]
# odigit = [0-9a-fA-F]
digit(){  [[ $ch == [0-9]       ]] || { ret=-1; return 1; }; ret=$ch; typ='s'; readch; }
odigit(){ [[ $ch == [0-7]       ]] || { ret=-1; return 1; }; ret=$ch; typ='s'; readch; }
hdigit(){ [[ $ch == [0-9a-fA-F] ]] || { ret=-1; return 1; }; ret=$ch; typ='s'; readch; }

# string = " char* "
# char = escch | {any character}
string(){
  skip "\"" "\"" || { logm "ERROR: quoted string expected"; return 1; }
  ret="${ret:1: -1}"
  typ='s'
  return 0
}

# ==========
# Char layer
# ==========

declare ch read
declare -i p L COUNT
readch(){
  if [[ p -eq L ]]; then  # need more code
    readline || { ch=; p=L=0; l="EOF"; return 1; }
    l+=$NL;
    p=0
    L=${#l}
  fi
# FIXME: remove once eady - prevents bash consuming all memory  
  COUNT+=1
  ((COUNT>100000)) && { logm "FAILSAFE: too many charcters read"; return 1; }
  ch="${l:p:1}"
  read+="$ch"
  p+=1  # queue next character
}

# skip = SS content* ES
# content = ch | escch | skip(SS ES)
# string = " ch* "
skip(){
  local s="$1" e="$2" b="$ch"
  typ='z'                    # code fragment
  [[ $ch != $s ]] && return  # nothing to skip
  readch
  while [[ -n $ch ]];do
    case "$ch" in
        $e)                 b+="$e"  ; readch; ret="$b"; return 0;;
        $s) skip "$s" "$e"; b+="$ret";;
      [\\]) escch         ; b+="$ret";;
      [\"]) skip "\"" "\""; b+="$ret";;
         ?)                 b+="$ch" ; readch
    esac
  done
  ret="$b"
  logm "ERROR: unexpected EOF"
  exit 1
}

# FIXME: still required?
shopt -s extglob
shopt -u nocasematch

declare NL; printf -v NL "%b" "\n"                 # echo $NL | hexdump -C
declare WS; printf -v WS "%b" " \n\t\r"            # define whitespace

# FIXME: should it set ret and typ? 
ws(){ while [[ $ch == [$WS] ]];do readch; done; }  # skip any WS

#=====
# eval
#=====

# exp = [0-9] num
#       | " string "
#       | : assignment
#       | @ function definition
#       | [-+*/%^] binary operation
#       | [&|#<>=] boolean operation
#       | [!~] unary operation
#       | [A-Z] function application
#       | [a-z] variable
#       | ? if expression
#       | { expression* } block expression
#       | ( expression* ) list of expressions

# spare prefix characters [ '$[]_\;, ]
# [v  head of list
# ]v tail of list

exp(){
  ws
  case "$ch" in
              [0-9]) num    || { logm "ERROR: number expected"               ; return 1; };;
#               [\']) char   || { logm "ERROR: char expected"                 ; return 1; };;
               [\"]) string || { logm "ERROR: string expected"               ; return 1; };;
               [\:]) assign || { logm "ERROR: assignment expected"           ; return 1; };;
               [\@]) define || { logm "ERROR: function definition expected"  ; return 1; };;
           [-+*/%^]) binary || { logm "ERROR: binary expression expected"    ; return 1; };;
       [\&\|#\<\>=]) binary || { logm "ERROR: binary expression expected"    ; return 1; };;
              [\!~]) unary  || { logm "ERROR: unary expression expected"     ; return 1; };;
              [A-Z]) apply  || { logm "ERROR: function failed"               ; return 1; };;
              [a-z]) get    || { logm "ERROR: variable name expected"        ; return 1; };;
               [\?]) iff    || { logm "ERROR: boolean expression expected"   ; return 1; };;
               [\{]) block  || { logm "ERROR: code block expected"           ; return 1; };;
               [\(]) list   || { logm "ERROR: list expected"                 ; return 1; };;
                 '') ret=;       logm "ERROR: unexpected EOF"                ; return 1;;
                  *) ret="$ch"                                               ; return 1;;
  esac
  return 0
}

# block = { code }
block(){
  readch                         # skip {
  while [[ $ch != "}" ]];do
    exp || { 
      tidyReadCh
      logm "WARNING: ignoring previous error or unknown symbol [$ch]"
      [[ errors+=1 -gt 5 ]] && { logm "ERROR: exiting due to too many warnings"; exit 1; }
    }
    ws
  done
  readch    # skip }
  return 0
}

#=====
# repl
#=====

# pass an expression on stdin- not used withing same ebvironment - called by apply
parse(){
  p=L  # force readline
  ch=
  read=
  readch  # clears ch
  while [[ $ch && $ch != '.' ]];do
    exp || { logm "ERROR: expression expected"; return 1; }
    read=$ch
    ws
  done
# last expression is returned as result
}

tidyReadCh(){
  tidyRead
  ch="${ch//[$NL]/\n}"
}
tidyRead(){
  read="${read//[$NL]}"
}

# repl = eval* EOF
# eval = evalu | readch
repl(){
  readch
  while [[ $ch && $ch != '.' ]];do
    exp && {
      tidyRead
      msn "> $read"  # echo line except for WS
#      echo -E "$ret [$typ]"
      echo -E "$ret"
      read=$ch
    } || {
      tidyReadCh
      msn "> $read"
      logm "WARNING: ignoring previous error or unknown symbol [$ch]"
      read=
      readch
      [[ errors+=1 -gt 5 ]] && { logm "ERROR: exiting due to too many warnings"; exit 1; }
    }
    ws
  done
  msn "<End>"
}

#=====
# test
#=====
# FIXME: negative numbers

msn "1Lang"

repl <<<'
:b" of beer"
:w" on the wall"
:t"Take one down and pass it around, "
:s"Go to the store and buy some more, "
:c", "
:n".\n"
@Bx{?=x0{+"No more bottles"b}{+x+" bottle"+?=x1{""}{"s"}b}}
@Fx{?=x0{+B0+w+c+B0+n+s+B99+wn}{+Bx+w+c+Bx+n+t+B-x1+w+n+"\n"F-x1}}
F99
'
```

Comment: I would have loved it even more if `@Mfxy{fxy}M+3 4` worked but then you need to join the function and variable namespace. It took a while to compute 99 beers :p

Comment: @Sylwester, thanks for your interest. I'm glad your tried it and also that it worked. Yes, bash is slow, and using bash to interpret another language (especially using subshells) is just interesting, but not useful. M+3 4 would not be correct as +3 4 would be evaluated first in apply. M\xy{+xy}3 4 might be a syntax that would work.

Comment: hmmm. seems my description has triggered markup language rules and bits are missing.

Comment: Yes, so that when it has `cons` you can `map` `M\x{*x2}C1C2C3C4/ => (2 4 6 8)`

Answer (score 4):

## Half (interpreter/translator in Windows Batch)

I don't know why I'm answering so many puzzles in windows batch, for some sick reason I think I'm enjoying it :P Anyways, this is similar to something I worked on for fun a while ago, a basic language that's translated to windows batch by a script that is also written in windows batch. It's not particularly amazing, but it works.

### 99 Bottles of Beer

```
# Initialize variables
bottles ~ 99
# You can't directly compare a literal value
zero ~ 0

# This makes a point 'loop' that can be jumped to or used as a subroutine
mark loop
    write $ bottles
# You only need quotes when you have leading or trailing spaces
    print ~ " bottles of beer on the wall,"
    write $ bottles
    print ~ " bottles of beer."
    print ~ Take one down and pass it around,
    bottles @ bottles-1
    if
    bottles equ zero
        jump none
    endif
    write $ bottles
    print ~ " bottles of beer on the wall."
    print ~
jump loop

mark none
    print ~ no more bottles of beer on the wall.
    print ~
    print ~ No more bottles of beer on the wall,
    print ~ No more bottles of beer.
    print ~ Go to the store and buy some more,
    print ~ 99 bottles of beer on the wall.
```

### Syntax

Only three tokens are recognized on each line, separated by spaces.

# is a comment.

In most cases where a value is needed, a `$` in the second token signifies that the third should be treated as a variable name, whereas a `~` denotes a literal value.
General instructions take the form `<instruction> [$~] <name>`. Setting a variable takes the same form, but is implemented whenever  is not recognized.

Defined commands:

- `print` and `write` both write output, but `write` does not add a newline. Needs $ or ~.
- `mark` creates a point that can be jumped to or called as a subroutine.
- `jump` equivalent of goto in batch (or any language for that matter).
- `proc` calls a subroutine. Equivalent of `call :label`.
- `return` returns from a subroutine. Will exit the program when not inside one.
- `if` conditional instruction. Takes comparison from the next line, in the form `<var1> <operator> <var2>`. Operators are the same as `if`'s in batch, ie. `EQU, NEQ, LSS, LEQ, GTR, GEQ`. Will execute instructions after it only if the comparison is true.
- `endif` ends an if statement.
- `cat` concatenates two variables. `cat a b` will store the value of ab in a.

When none of these commands are found, the expression is treated as a variable assignment, using the first token as the variable name. `$` and `~` behave the same as in `print`, but there is also a `@` identifier. This treats the last token as a mathematical expression, passed to `set /a`. It includes most operators. If none of the three identifiers are found, this is a syntax error and the interpreter exits.

### Interpreter (Windows Batch)

The interpreter actually translates the code into windows batch, places it in a temporary file and executes it. While it recognizes syntax errors in the Half language, the resulting batch script may cause issues, especially with special characters like parentheses, vertical bars etc.

```
@echo off

REM Half Interpreter / Translator

if exist ~~.bat del ~~.bat
if not exist "%1" call :error "File not found: '%1'"
set error=
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
call :parse "%1" 1>~~.bat
if exist ~~.bat if not "error"=="" ~~.bat 2>nul
goto :eof

:parse
set ifstate=0
echo @echo off
echo setlocal
echo setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "eol=# tokens=1,2* delims= " %%a in (%~1) do  (
    if "!ifstate!"=="1" (
        if /i not "%%b"=="equ" if /i not "%%b"=="neq" if /i not "%%b"=="lss" if /i not "%%b"=="leq" if /i not "%%b"=="gtr" if /i not "%%b"=="geq" call :error "Unknown comparator: '%%b'"
        echo if "^!%%a^!" %%b "^!%%c^!" ^(
        set ifstate=0
    ) else (
        if "%%a"=="print" (
            if "%%b"=="$" (
                echo echo.^^!%%c^^!
            ) else if "%%b"=="~" (
                echo echo.%%~c
            ) else call :error "Unknown identifier for print: '%%b'"
        ) else if "%%a"=="write" (
            if "%%b"=="$" (
                echo echo^|set/p="^!%%c^!"
            ) else if "%%b"=="~" (
                echo echo^|set/p="%%~c"
            ) else call :error "Unknown identifier for write: '%%b'"
        ) else if "%%a"=="mark" (
            if not "%%c"=="" call :error "Unexpected token: %%c"
            echo :%%b
        ) else if "%%a"=="jump" (
            if not "%%c"=="" call :error "Unexpected token: %%c"
            echo goto :%%b
        ) else if "%%a"=="proc" (
            if not "%%c"=="" call :error "Unexpected token: %%c"
            echo call :%%b
        ) else if "%%a"=="return" (
            if not "%%c"=="" call :error "Unexpected tokens: %%b %%c"
            if not "%%b"=="" call :error "Unexpected token: %%b"
            echo goto :eof
        ) else if "%%a"=="if" (
            if not "%%c"=="" call :error "Unexpected tokens: %%b %%c"
            if not "%%b"=="" call :error "Unexpected token: %%b"
            set ifstate=1
        ) else if "%%a"=="endif" (
            if not "%%c"=="" call :error "Unexpected tokens: %%b %%c"
            if not "%%b"=="" call :error "Unexpected token: %%b"
            echo ^)
        ) else if "%%a"=="cat" (
            echo set "%%b=^!%%b^!^!%%c^!"
        ) else (
            if "%%b"=="$" (
                echo set "%%a=!%%c!"
            ) else if "%%b"=="~" (
                echo set "%%a=%%~c"
            ) else if "%%b"=="@" (
                echo set/a"%%a=%%c"
            ) else call :error "Unknown tokens '%%a %%b %%c'"
        )
    )
)
echo endlocal
goto :eof

:error
echo.Parse Error: %~1 1>&2
set error=1
goto :eof
```

Comment: [I'm stealing your idea (and crediting your (public domain) post)](https://github.com/catb0t/half)

Answer (score 4):

## Flex Bison

Assign variable, if else condition block and some other addition, subtraction operation.

Laxical file `lex.l`

```
%{
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
%}

 var [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*
 digit [0-9]+
 comment \*\*[A-Za-z0-9\*\/\+\-\(\)\"\' \t;:=]*\n

 %%
 print {return(PRINT);}
 save {return(SAVE);}
 {digit} {yylval=atoi(yytext);return(DIGIT);}
 {var} {yylval=strdup(yytext);return(VAR);}
 \* {return(M_SIGN);}
 \/ {return(D_SIGN);}
 \+ {return(A_SIGN);}
 \- {return(S_SIGN);}
 \( {return(L_BRACE);}
 \) {return(R_BRACE);}
 = {return(E_SIGN);}
 ; {return(S_COLON);}
 : {return(COMMA);}
 \n {return (NW_LINE);}
 [ \t] /*skip*/;
 {comment} /*skip*/;
 %%
```

Parser file `com.y`

```
  %{
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    FILE *save_p;
    int new_line=1,stack_top=0,trigger=1;
    void value_store(int);
    int check_srore(char name_var[],int);
    void error(int);

    struct store
    {
     int var_value;
     char var_name[10];
     }info[10];        

    %}

      %token PRINT SAVE S_COLON L_BRACE R_BRACE DIGIT VAR COMMA NW_LINE
      %left A_SIGN S_SIGN
      %left D_SIGN M_SIGN
      %right E_SIGN



      %%
      commands : 
         | commands command
          ;
      command : expers
        | print
        | save
        | NW_LINE{new_line++;}
          ;

           save : SAVE expr etest {fprintf(save_p,"%d\n",$2);}
            ;

           expers  : store_val equal expr etest{value_store($3);}
        ;

           print    : PRINT expr etest {printf("%d\n",$2);} 
              ;

           etest    : S_COLON
        | DIGIT {error(0);}|PRINT{error(0);}|SAVE{error(0);}
         | VAR{error(0);}|COMMA{error(0);}
         ;

           store_val : VAR {check_store($1,0);}
          ;

           expr    : expr A_SIGN expr      { $$ = $1 + $3; } 
                | expr S_SIGN expr      { $$ = $1 - $3; }
                | expr M_SIGN expr      { $$ = $1 * $3; }
                    | expr D_SIGN expr      { $$ = $1 / $3; }
                | L_BRACE expr R_BRACE  { $$ = $2; }
                | DIGIT
                | retriv_var
                ;

             equal   : E_SIGN
             ;

             retriv_var : VAR { $$=check_store($1,1); }
           ;            

        %%

        #include "lex.yy.c"

        void error(int temp)
         {
                char *err[]={
                     "Statement Missing\n",
                 "Compund Statement Missing\n",
                     "Variable need a value\n",
                     "Invalid Argument\n"  
          };
             printf("In line no.%d:\t%s",new_line,err[temp]);   
         exit(1);
        } 

      void value_store(int store_val)
      {
       stack_top--;
      info[stack_top++].var_value = store_val;
      }

   int check_store(char name_var[],int status)
   {
     int temp = 0;
   do{
    if(strcmp(info[temp].var_name,name_var)==0)
    {
   trigger=0;
       if(status)
   {  
          trigger=1;
      return (info[temp].var_value);
   }          
     }
    temp++;     
   } while(temp<stack_top);

    if(trigger)
    {    
if(status)
{
  trigger=1;
      error(2);
}
    else
strcpy(info[stack_top++].var_name,name_var);
   }
      else trigger=1;

  }

  int yyerror(const char *str)
  {
    fprintf(stderr,"error: %s\n",str);
  }


  main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {       

if(argc != 3)
{
     error(3);
}
   yyin = fopen(argv[1],"r");
   save_p = fopen(argv[2],"w");
   yyparse();
   fclose(yyin);
   fclose(yyout);
  }
```

Compile

1. List item
2. flex lex.l
3. bison com.y
4. gcc -o compiler com.tab.c -lfl

Run

compiler in.txt ou.txt

Input file

a = 3 + (4 *7) -9;
print a;
c = a+45;
print c;

**This is comment
save c;

** save c in the file
print c*(a+32);

Output file
67

Answer (score 3):

I give you:

## Small Instruction Set Interpreter (SISI)

The syntax draws on BASIC and assembly. It has four statements: `set`, `print`, `jump` (unconditional goto), and `jumpif` (conditional goto). Every statement must be preceded by a line number. Supported data types are integers and strings.

The interpreter itself can be found in Python 3 [on Github](http://github.com/dloscutoff/esolangs/tree/master/Sisi) (sisi.py). The 99 Bottles of Beer program is there as well, but I'll reproduce it here:

```
10 set x 99
20 set bottles " bottles "

100 set line x + bottles
110 set line line + "of beer on the wall, "
120 set line line + x
130 set line line + bottles
135 set line line + "of beer."
140 print line

200 set x x - 1
210 set none x = 0
220 jumpif none 400
230 set multiple x > 1
240 jumpif multiple 300
250 set bottles " bottle "

300 set line "Take one down and pass it around, " + x
310 set line line + bottles
320 set line line + "of beer on the wall."
330 print line
340 print ""
350 jump 100

400 print "Take one down and pass it around, no more bottles of beer on the wall."
410 print ""
420 print "No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer."
430 print "Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall."
```

Answer (score 2):

## Interpreter

For instructions on how to run this code, take a look at my other answer: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19935/13186

## 99 Bottles of Beer

### The Program

```
 bottles of beer on the wall, @ bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, @ bottles of beer on the wall.

@ bottle of beer on the wall.

1 bottle of beer on the wall, 1 bottle of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, no more bottles of beer on the wall.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

#9.{
    !#48.+

    !<#57.<#0.^<!<#57.<#1.^<!<#56.<#64.^<
    !<#56.<#0.^<!<#56.<#1.^<!<#55.<#64.^<
    !<#55.<#0.^<!<#55.<#1.^<!<#54.<#64.^<
    !<#54.<#0.^<!<#54.<#1.^<!<#53.<#64.^<
    !<#53.<#0.^<!<#53.<#1.^<!<#52.<#64.^<
    !<#52.<#0.^<!<#52.<#1.^<!<#51.<#64.^<
    !<#51.<#0.^<!<#51.<#1.^<!<#50.<#64.^<
    !<#50.<#0.^<!<#50.<#1.^<!<#49.<#64.^<
    !<#49.<#0.^<!<#49.<#1.^<!<#48.<#64.^<
    !<#48.<#0.^<!<#48.<#1.^<!#1.-<#57.<#64.^<
    _
?}

#57.<#0.^<#57.<#1.^<!<#56.<#64.^<
#56.<#0.^<#56.<#1.^<!<#55.<#64.^<
#55.<#0.^<#55.<#1.^<!<#54.<#64.^<
#54.<#0.^<#54.<#1.^<!<#53.<#64.^<
#53.<#0.^<#53.<#1.^<!<#52.<#64.^<
#52.<#0.^<#52.<#1.^<!<#51.<#64.^<
#51.<#0.^<#51.<#1.^<!<#50.<#64.^<
#50.<#0.^<#50.<#1.^<!<#49.<
#94.^<

$
```

Answer (score 2):

## 99ISC

99ISC uses an arbitrarily-sized integer-oriented memory. Memory is indexed by a non-negative integer. All values in memory are initialized with their address. Eg. At runtime, address 0 contains value 0 and address 9 contains value 9.

99ISC has two instructions. The first prints out the 99 Bottles of Beer on the Wall routine. Its syntax is a single line, as below. Execution continues with the next line in the program.

```
.
```

The second instruction is a "subtract and branch if not equal to zero" instruction. Its syntax is a single line, as below.

```
x y z
```

`x` is the address of the number to be operated on, `y` is the address of the number being subtracted, and `z` is the next line to execute if the result of the subtraction is not zero. Otherwise, execution proceeds with the next line.

The presence of the "subtract-and-branch-if-not-zero" instruction makes 99ISC an OISC (One Instruction Set Computer) and therefore Turing complete.

Here is a program that erases the first 10 values in memory and then prints the 99 Bottles of Beer on the Wall routine.

```
1 1 0
2 2 0
3 3 0
4 4 0
5 5 0
6 6 0
7 7 0
8 8 0
9 9 0
.
```

And here is a 99ISC interpreter, in Python.

```
def interpret(filename):
    mem = range(0, 10)
    print mem

    with open(filename) as f:
            lines = f.readlines()

    ptr = 0
    while ptr < len(lines):
            line = lines[ptr]

            if line.strip() == ".":
                    for i in range(99,0,-1):
                            text = str(i) + " bottles of beer on the wall, " + str(i) + " bottles of beer.\nTake one down and pass it around, " + str(i-1) + " bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n"
                            print text.replace("0", "No more")
            else:
                    toks = map(int, line.split())
                    mem[toks[0]] = (mem[toks[0]] - mem[toks[1]]) & 0xFF
                    if mem[toks[0]] != 0:
                            ptr = toks[2]
                    else:
                            ptr += 1
```

Comment: I guess this breaks the "best practices" rules for golf questions. With a generic print statement in place of "." it would still work, but I'll be damned if I'm going to write the 99BOB program!

Comment: Last 2 verses need a bit more work.

Answer (score 1):

### Pogo

https://github.com/nrubin29/Pogo

```
method main:void
    declare(integer,i,99)
    while i > 0
        print(i "bottles of beer on the wall")
        math(i - 1) i
    end
end main
```

Comment: I'm having problems seeing that this prints the 99 bottles lyrics.

Comment: First, I declare an integer named `i` and set it equal to 99. Then, while i is greater than 0, I print `i bottles of beer on the wall` and subtract one from `i`. If the problem is that I'm lacking some of the lyrics, I can add more.

Comment: A link to lyrics was (or now is) provided. Last few verses are a bit more complicated.