# Count how many characters are in the program's source

Tags: code-golf, string

Write a program that counts and prints the number of characters in it's own source code to standard output.

The number must be generated from counting the characters.

This Ruby solution would not be allowed:

```
puts 6
```

because it is not calculated. Spaces, tabs, new lines, etc **should be counted**.

The program must be smallest possible in any programming language.

Comment: If you post another challenge, I strongly suggest using [this template](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1511/18487).

Comment: My guess, make a program that will count how many characters are used in the programs code, so basicly count the characters in your source and make it as short as possible. Is this really being downvoted for poor english?

Comment: I made a winner!  **PHP**, 1 character:  `1`

Comment: Something like `echo 'wc -c $0' > x ; sh x`... I think this is a nice question, maybe the rules should be a little more precise...

Comment: So is this [tag:code-golf] then?

Comment: Whatever tags it should have, it's a rubbish question. It's like making a cheating "quine" without even having the interest of being a quine.

Comment: Must it actually read the source code, or is a stat on the source code file good enough ?

Comment: *The program must be smallest possible in any programming language.* The halting problem makes this challenge impossible.

Answer (score 10):

## Bash, 10

Pretty boring, but:

- Prints the code size in bytes, and nothing else.
- Filename may contain spaces.

Make sure that the file doesn't have a new line at the end! If it does, it will output `11`.

```bsh
wc -c<"$0"
```

If the file doesn't have spaces in its name, you can get 8 characters:

```bsh
wc -c<$0
```

Comment: since others are specifying the filename, you should be able to count this as 8

Comment: Actually, on that note, you could specify it as being named `a` and just have `wc -c<a`.

Answer (score 8):

## CJam / GolfScript - 11

CJam:

```
{`"_~"+,}_~
```

GolfScript:

```
{`".~"+,}.~
```

This actually generates its own source code (like a quine) and then calculates the string length.

Answer (score 6):

## [PYG](https://gist.github.com/Synthetica9/9796173) (9, and actually calculated)

Calculates the length of the source code (`Q`) with the builtin string length checker `len`, and prints (`P`) the result:

```
P(len(Q))
```

Comment: Nice golfing of Python.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>30 22 20</s> 18

```ruby
p IO.read($0)=~/$/
```

Comment: You could make it a touch shorter by using a regex match to calculate the length: `p File.read($0)=~/$/`

Comment: @Chron thanks, fixed

Comment: you could reduce to 18 : `p IO.read($0)=~/$/`

Comment: Even better, 15: `p open($0).size`

Answer (score 3):

## perl, 9 bytes

No trailing newline.

```
print-s$0
```

Running it looks like this:

```
$ echo -n 'print-s$0' >/tmp/foo.pl
$ perl /tmp/foo.pl ; echo
9
```

Comment: `-M5.01` is free, so you can reduce this by two bytes by using `say` instead of `print`. (Tested on Strawberry 5.20.2.)

Answer (score 2):

## BASH (builtins only) - 18

```
$ cat bash ; echo # no final newline in file
a=`<$0`
echo ${#a}
$ ls -l bash 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yeti yeti 18 18. Mai 07:11 bash
$ ./bash 
18
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 31

Save the file as `'l'`

```
print len(file.read(file('l')))
```

Outputs `34`

Comment: Might as well name it `l`... Saves 3 chars

Answer (score 1):

### Fortran 78

```
character*78::a;open(unit=9,file='c.f90');read(9,'(a78)')a;print*,len(a);end
```

File IO isn't the best in Fortran, so we have to waste space opening the file & then reading from it. Had I not specified the `a78` (78 characters), then it would stop at the comma next to `file` (silly [list-directed IO](http://www.adt.unipd.it/corsi/Bianco/www.pcc.qub.ac.uk/tec/courses/f90/stu-notes/F90_notesMIF_10.html)).

Answer (score 1):

## HTML + Javascript (jQuery): 48

Save this script as `script.html` and open it with a browser.

```
<script>alert($('body').html().length)</script>
```

Comment: You also need to include any library with a `$` function. Otherwise this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

## Rebol, 40

```
print length? read system/options/script
```

Answer (score 1):

## VIM - 43

Add this in your `.vimrc` file :

```
:echo strlen(join(readfile(".vimrc")),"\n")
```

But it will only work if you are in your home when executing vim.

More generic solution `vim ~/.vimrc` (**46 chars**) :

```
:echo strlen(join(readfile(bufname("%")),"\n"))
```

Comment: Your first solution seems to have one too many rightparens.

Comment: @Aurel300 yup thx. fixed

Answer (score 1):

## PHP - 22

```
<?=filesize(__FILE__);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>28</s> 27 bytes

I got 2̶8̶ 27 characters, plus file name and extension (4 in this case for 'f.py') The minimum value for this is 3̶2̶ 31, if there was a 1 letter file name and the `.py` exension:

```
print(len(open("f.py").read()))
```

EDIT:
The bite count is actually 27 rather than 28, thanks @mbomb007 for pointing that out

Comment: [The byte count is wrong.](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#print%28len%28open%28%22f.py%22%29.read%28%29%29%29)

Comment: Why not just `f`?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere The program I use to execute the program doesn't run unless the file is a `.py` file, so it was out of habit that I put that. But, as you say, using `f` instead of `f.py` would lower the byte count from 31 to 28 (including the filename)

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript 78

```
<script id="s">
function f(){document.write(document.getElementById("s").innerHTML.length);}
</script>
```

Comment: You may save 2 chars removing quotes from `id="s"`

Comment: also, the stdout of javascript is `alert` so you may save lot of chars replacing the `document.write`

Comment: This isn't pure javascript.

Answer (score 0):

## J - 16 char

J can `read($0)` itself too, you know! Not all that well, but...

```
echo#1!:1]1{ARGV
```

A more natural solution in the interpreter REPL, in which we do the normal quine thing and then take the length, costs **24 chars**:

```
#(,2#{:),~'#(,2#{:),~'''
```

`,~` appends the string to itself, `(,2#{:)` appends two copies of the trailing single quote, and `#` takes the length.

Answer (score 0):

## [Extended BrainFuck](http://sylwester.no/ebf/): 12

```
,(>+<,)>55+.
```

Usage:

```
beef ebf.bf < cnt.ebf > cnt.bf
beef cnt.bf < ent.ebf
```

Output:

```
C
```

Which is 12 in hex. If you add a linefeed in the file it will output a `D` for 13 so it's definitely counting the characters in the source.

Comment: I wonder how fun it would be to program in something that adds GolfScript functionality to Extended BF...Makes me tempted to spec out a more fully featured BF derivative that combines a lot of things invented by other BF derivatives (limited networking support, early termination, timing from NetFuck, significant comment syntax and function/macro support from cbrain, multithreading support from Brainfork, etc.) with some things from GolfScript (like variables) and a few additions of mine for utility reasons (modules, anyone?).

Comment: @impinball EBF has variables and macros and it would have been difficult to make [LISP in it](http://sylwester.no/zozotez/) without it. A major design goal of `EBF` was that it should produce pure `BF` object code that runs under any BF implementation. Making just an interpeter/compiler that has added primitives like `pbrain` is IMO cheating. A cleaner approach to get feature like file I/O would be to implement message passing through stdin/stdout so that you could make a program X that implements the protocol that run standard brainfuck interpreter/compiler Y and intercept the I/O.

Comment: Just leisurely wondering. I wouldn't add half a million primitives. I was pondering the idea of modular BF that includes some useful other stuff like what EBF and NetFuck has. Make a more useful(ish) BF. I wouldn't use pbrain's comment syntax, because it would be easier to use the more common empty register comment. I still would want to include native file I/O, but not by flooding with primitives.

Comment: @impinball EBF is a more useful BF since it provides more primitives front end without demanding it from it's back end. BTW: I have made a joke compiler called [BrainBack](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23426/11290) that is a Forth type language like GolfScript. I wrote the compiler in EBF and it compiles to EBF :)

Comment: Ok... Could you reread my comment... I sent it earlier than I intended.

Comment: Or maybe I could implement modules, implementing a few in native code, but it only adding two more primitived to EBF: the module import and module export. Modules with optional native ones (both plugin and standard library) could almost make it real world useful. That would probably be best. The one issue will be circular dependencies (my pet project of a JS compiler will teach me how to manage that).

Comment: @impinball I've though about these things but I'm leaving it outside of EBF for my Scheme to BF project by specifying a message passing API. eg. my BF program outputs "This needs BF APIv1" and my API implementation intercepts I/O so it answers this. After that you need to opcode your output after the spec. 1 might be "fork" and the first byte read in would then indicate if you are parent or child. 2 + ascii0 file path might be open file and you'll get a file handle on the next byte read. Such a thing can extend BF to support any OS feature without extending the actual language.

Comment: @impinball modules import could easily be implemented by the front end and compile it to pure BF or message passing calls. How should it react for unavailable modules? You can send me a link when you got your project up and running as I'd love to see it :)

Comment: I haven't really put too much serious thought into it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hy** (38 characters):

```
(defmain [n] (print (.read (open n))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## dc - 8

Not sure if this is allowed, but calculates the length of the macro(the part in the square brackets and adds 4(which is the length of the part outside the macro)).

```
[Z4+p]dx
```

Answer (score 0):

### Lua: 42

```
print(string.len(io.open('l',"r"):read()))
```

Pretty straight-forward, you must save the file as `l` and call it as `lua l`.

Comment: In lua read only is the default, so you can remove the "r". You can use # instead of string.len to make it even shorter.

Answer (score 0):

## K,13

```
1@$#,/0:.z.f;
```

/

```
$ q a.k -q
13
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3: 33 or 37

```
print(len(open(__file__).read()))
print(len(open(__file__,'b').read()))
```

First if you only count the characters, second if you want to count the number of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (Node.js) - 60

```
console.log(require('fs').readFileSync(__filename).length);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 157 characters

Since nobody has done Java yet...

```
public class A{public static void main(String[]a) throws Exception{System.out.print(new java.util.Scanner(new java.io.File("A.java")).nextLine().length());}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! Answers to code golf challenges here are typically prefixed with a header mentioning the language the code is written in and its amount of characters. I've edited it in for you this time, but it would be great if you could include one in your future code golf solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Cause ya know, java.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP - 44

Save this as `c`

```
<?$f=fopen("c","r");echo strlen(fgets($f));
```

Comment: Why do you store $f? `echo strlen(fgets(fopen("c","r")));`

Comment: `<?=strlen(fgets(fopen(c,r)));`, 29 bytes: Neither `c` nor `r` need quotes; and echo-tag is shorter than `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript

**42 - ES5**

```javascript
(function a(){alert((a+"()()").length)})()
```

**37 - ES6**

```javascript
(a=x=>{alert((a+"(a=)()").length)})()
```

Comment: And also, a self invoking function is longer, than actually calling it

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (pure - no HTML nor JQuery) 41 bytes

```
function f() {alert((f+"f()").length)}f()
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Dyalog APL](https://dyalog.com), 8 bytes

The niladic function `f`:

```
≢∊⎕NR'f'
```

Notice that this prints 10 because APL counts (and stores) the function header (name + newline). However, PPCG practice is not to count this header. The entire program can be displayed with

```
      ↑⎕NR'f'
```

Giving:

```
f
≢∊⎕NR'f'
```

---

`⎕NR'f'` the **N**ested (i.e. a list of character lists) **R**epresentation of `f`

`∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten)

`≢` tally

Answer (score 0):

## RProgN, 3 bytes.

```
Q L
```

Simply, Q is the function that pushes the source code to the stack, and L is the function that gets the length of the string on top of the stack. The stack is then implicitly printed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/rprogn#@x@o4PP/PwA)

Answer (score 0):

### awk, 13 bytes

```
$0=length($0)
```

Write it to a program file `program.awk` and

```
$ awk -f program.awk program.awk
13
```