# It was just a bug

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, number, kolmogorov-complexity

Inspired by the bugged output in [*@Carcigenicate*'s Clojure answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109197/52210) for the [Print this diamond](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8696/print-this-diamond) challenge.

### Print this exact text:

```
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0
1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
1234567890
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0
1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0
```

(From the middle outward in both directions, each digit is separated by one more space than the previous line.)

### Challenge rules:

- There will be no input ([or an empty unused input](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12681/are-we-allowed-to-use-empty-input-we-wont-use-when-no-input-is-asked-regarding)).
- Trailing spaces are optional.
- A single trailing new-line is optional.
- Leading spaces or new-lines are not allowed.
- Returning a string-array isn't allowed. You should either output the text, or have a function which returns a single string with correct result.

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer, so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code.
- Also, please add an explanation if necessary.

Comment: Is outputting an array of strings - 1 string per line - allowed?

Comment: @Shaggy Sorry, in this case it should either return a single string with new-lines, or output the result. I've added this as rule to the challenge.

Comment: No worries, Kevin; was just chancing my arm to see if I could save myself a couple of bytes.

Comment: @Shaggy Hehe. What other reason would we have to ask question in a code-golf challenge, besides having the purpose of saving those few bytes? ;)

Comment: Ha, that's awesome. I was wondering why that answer suddenly got so much attention. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 11 bytes

```
8╤{± *♂r╫up
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/i0dQl1Yc2Kmg9mtlU9Gjq6tKC//8B)

### Explanation

```
8             push 8
 ╤            range(-n, n+1)
  {           for each element in range:
   ±          absolute value
              space character
     *        multiply space character x number of times
      ♂r      push 10, create range
        ╫     left-rotate list (0 goes to the end)
         u    join with separator (joins using x spaces)
          p   print with newline
```

Has a trailing newline in the end from printing. @ovs found a mistake in the original code that could be fixed by switching the first `9` to an `8`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `9` should be an `8` instead. This has more lines in the output than the text in the challenge.

Comment: Good catch! This was a long time ago, and I guess that I must've just thought that the outputs were identical.

Answer (score 70):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/),  <s>59 57 56</s> 55 bytes

```python
i=8;exec"print(' '*abs(i)).join('1234567890');i-=1;"*17
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWwjq1IjVZqaAoM69EQ11BXSsxqVgjU1NTLys/M09D3dDI2MTUzNzC0kBd0zpT19bQWknL0Pz/fwA)

> *@Leaky Nun helped golfing this a lot, @Praind Suggested a method to save 1 byte, which I formerly thought of, but forgot to edit, @CotyJohnathanSaxman suggested changing the loop.*

---

## Explanation

- `i=8` - Assigns the value `8` to a variable called `i`.
- `exec"..."*17` - Execute that block of code (`...`) 17 times.
- `print(...)` - Output the result.
- `' '*abs(i)` - Create a String with a space repeated `|i|` times.
- `.join('1234567890')` - Interleave the string created above with `1234567890`, such that `|i|` spaces are inserted between the digits.
- `i-=1` - Decrement `i`, and by executing it 17 times, it reaches `-8`, which creates te repetitive pattern with the help of `abs()`.

Comment: [76 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcE7DoAgDADQ3VN0ozVqVPwAt9EoWodCkMXT43vxy3cQXcpxevCYycXEkhEVqDpT9wQWVMOop3lZje0VUeVDAgYWSJtcJ5qmtU07kPO47S8yUSk/)

Comment: @LeakyNun Just updating with [77](https://tio.run/##DYm7DoAgDAB/ha1gGsNb9FeMq7EOhRAWvx47XHK5a994Koc579oVKeKz4IYZE0YM6NGhFbx4lJblletonXhoDQoWMutbiTU4H2LKW9ktGDPnDw) :P

Comment: [62 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFJDoAgDADAr/RGa8CIuIC/wcSlHgpBLr4eZ/JX7ySutTMVYGCBEuU60GsTtLG05cJSERWoLu4vMlH/JBZUdnTTvKw@DIqotR8)

Comment: [59 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1VQ9dCx1LTqqAoM69EQ0NdQV0rMalYI1NTUy8rPzNPQ93QyNjE1MzcwtJAXVPz/38A)

Comment: This is farm more impressive than 25 bytes in any golfing language imho.

Comment: @Jylo Thanks, but the 25 byte-solutions are very impressive, since they show lots of golfing efforts made by their authors. You should first know what each character in their source means, and then you will understand how beautifully golfed they are.

Comment: You can save one more byte by losing the 'range' for a 'while'. <a href="https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9NW14KrPCMzJ1Uh08bSqqAoM69EQ11BXSsxqVgjU1NTLys/M09D3dDI2MTUzNzC0kBd0zpT29bw/38A" title="56 bytes">Try it online!</a>

Comment: You can save another byte. Start with positive 8 and decrement it at the end. With that you omit the minus character :)

Comment: Just a noob programmer asking a noob question: Can't you replace i-=1 with i--, saving a byte?

Comment: @JasonChen No, Python does not allow that syntax, because that's specific to C-like languages.

Comment: Possible inspiration: Can be done without `exec` [in 55 bytes as well](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWgqs8IzMnVSFT29KqoCgzr0RDXUFdKzGpWCNTU1MvKz8zT0Pd0MjYxNTM3MLSQF3TOlPX1vD/fwA "Python 2 – Try It Online"). Used a similar approach [to get Python 3 down to 57 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/130085/70305). Didn't see any obvious way to get it shorter, by omitting `exec`, but figured I'd mention it as a possibility.

Answer (score 38):

## Vim, 35 bytes:

```
i1234567890<esc>qqYP:s/\d/& /g
YGp{q7@q
```

Explanation:

```
i1234567890<esc>    " insert '1234567890'
qq                  " Record the following into register 'q'
  Y                 "   Yank a line
   P                "   Paste it above us
    :s/\d/& /g      "   Put a space after each number
Y                   "   Yank this line
 G                  "   Move the end of the buffer
  p                 "   Paste the line
   {                "   Move the beginning of the buffer
    q               " Stop recording
     7@q            " Call macro 'q' 7 times
```

Comment: I don't even care that this isn't the winner, it's beautiful.

Comment: @MrDuk Thankyou! I'm glad you like it :)

Answer (score 24):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E),  <s>14</s>  13 bytes

```
17F9ÝÀN8αð×ý,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v8wNWFiMWX//zE3RjnDncOATjjOscOww5fDvSz//w)

**Explanation**

```
17F            # for N in [0 ... 16] do
   9Ý          # push [0 ... 9]
     À         # rotate left
      N8α      # compute the absolute difference between N and 8
         ð×    # push that many spaces
           ý   # merge the list of digits with the space string as separator
            ,  # print
```

Comment: Hmm...you could've beaten SOGL if you didn't need the `s`...does it make sense to join a string with a list or a list with a string? I'll suggest improvement to Adnan. Oh, and there's `.∊` for `û»`.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: Or I could switch up my method and save that 1 byte I needed :)

Comment: Sorry already upvoted.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: I don't see what that has to do with anything. Thanks for notifying me that I needed to golf my answer :)

Comment: That means I'd have upvoted again...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer let me do it for you.... Here we go.

Comment: `8F9ÝÀNð×ý}».∊` I done did made a spaceship maw! And I was all excited about suggesting a 12-byte edit.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: Hehe, yeah I made a spaceship while golfing as well :)

Comment: Hi, someone else just posted [a 12-byte solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146574/52210). Since it's been a couple of months ago since I accepted yours, I'm not sure what the policy is. Since the other one is shorter, I'm thinking about accepting that one, but since I feel it's also unfair to you I'd like to ask your opinion about this first as well. Should I leave the accepted mark, or accept another answer if a shorter one comes up in the future?

Comment: There are lots of alternate 13s, like `9LRûv9ÝÀÀyjÁ,` or `9LR©ûv®yjR?0,`. It feels like 12 should be possible.

Answer (score 24):

## C64 ASM, 358 bytes (102 bytes compiled with basicstub)

This is the closest I could get due to obvious limitations:

[image: C64]

```
jsr $E544
lda #9
sta $FD
nl1: jsr dl
jsr il
dec $FD
bne nl1
inc $FD
nl2: ldy $FD
cpy #9
bne nt1
bl: jmp bl
nt1: iny
sty $FD
jsr dl
jsr il
jmp nl2
dl: clc
ldx #$31
ldy #0
lp: txa
sm: sta $0400, y
inx
cpx #$31
bne c1
rts
c1: cpx #$3A
bne nt2
ldx #$30
clc
nt2: tya
adc $FD
cmp #40
bcc c2
rts
c2: tay
jmp lp
il: lda sm+1
adc #39
bcc nc
inc sm+2
nc: sta sm+1
rts
```

(Could probably be optimized quite a bit)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Please use code tag to post pretty. I edited you post. After changes apply you can see, what changed by clicking edit

Comment: I've just checked and it won't even fit on an 80 cols PET as the first and last line require 82 columns.

Answer (score 17):

## TSQL, <strike>220</strike> 148 bytes

Improvement posted by ZLK:

```
DECLARE @ VARCHAR(MAX)=''SELECT TOP 17@+=REPLACE('1@2@3@4@5@6@7@8@9@0','@',SPACE(ABS(9-RANK()OVER(ORDER BY object_id))))+'
'FROM sys.objects PRINT @
```

Output:

```
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0
1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
1234567890
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0
1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0
```

Comment: `DECLARE @ VARCHAR(MAX)=''SELECT TOP 17@+=REPLACE('1@2@3@4@5@6@7@8@9@0','@',SPACE(ABS(9-RANK()OVER(ORDER BY object_id))))+'
'FROM sys.objects PRINT @`

Comment: Replace `sys.objects` with `sysobjects`, and 1object_id` with `id` I looked for shorter tables in the `sys` schema, but nothing short had columns as short as `sysobjects`

Comment: And you can save another few bytes by changing the inner `CAST` (with the `POWER(10)`) to `VARCHAR`

Comment: In fact, avoid all that replace stuff by using `LOG10` and `REPLICATE`: `DECLARE @o VARCHAR(MAX)=''SELECT TOP 17 @o+=REPLACE('1@2@3@4@5@6@7@8@9@0','@',replicate(' ',LOG10(POWER(10,ABS(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY id)-9)+1)/10)))+'
'FROM sysobjects PRINT @o`

Comment: You can change the variable name to just `@` to shave off 3 characters.

Answer (score 14):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 22 bytes

```apl
↑∊¨(1+|¯9+⍳17)↑¨¨⊂1⌽⎕D
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPdqRRItU181NF1aIWGoXbNofWW2o96NxuaawJFD604tOJRV5Pho569j/qmuoDU/wdqAAA)

`⎕D` **D**igits from zero to nine

`1⌽` rotate one step right (puts zero at end)

`⊂` enclose (to treat as unit)

`(`…`)↑¨¨` for *each* of these numbers, take that many characters from *each* of the letters:

`⍳17` one through seventeen

`¯9+` subtract nine

`|` find the absolute values

`1+` add one

`∊¨` enlist (flatten) each

`↑` change one layer of depth into a level of rank (matrify)

Comment: In a compact language like this it seriously takes two bytes to add one?

Comment: @aschepler Yes. APL is not a golfing language, and doesn't have an increment primitive. J does, but it takes two bytes; `>:`.

Comment: `APL is not a golfing language` ... `↑⊃¨,/¨(1+|¯9+⍳17)↑¨¨⊂1⌽⎕D` ... ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for getting my attention back to this one. I could golf 3 bytes.

Answer (score 14):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>58</strike> 55 bytes

```hs
unlines["1234567890">>=(:(' '<$[1..abs n]))|n<-[-8..8]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyflfraus4OPo5x7q6O6q4BwQoKCsW8tVYRvzvzQvJzMvtThaydDI2MTUzNzC0kDJzs5Ww0pDXUHdRiXaUE8vMalYIS9WU7Mmz0Y3WtdCT88iNvZ/bmJmnoKtQkFpSXBJkU@eQsV/AA)

This is basically @nimi 's solution :)

Answer (score 12):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-R`, <s>19</s> <s>18</s> <s>16</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
Aõ%A
£qYçÃÔÅê
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=QfUlQQqjcVnnw3cgxeo=&input=LVI=) or [try it online](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3/HwVlVHrkOLCyMPLz/cXK5wuPXwqv//dYMA)

---

### Explanation

```
A             :10
 õ           :Range [1,10]
  %A         :Modulo each by 10
\n           :Assign to variable U
£            :Map each element at 0-based index Y
 q           :  Join U with
  Yç         :   Space repeated Y times
    Ã        :End map
     Ô       :Reverse
      Å      :Slice off first element
       ê     :Mirror
             :Implicitly join with newlines and output
```

Comment: Nice. My 16-byte solution was `9ÆAõ%A qXîÃw ê ·`

Answer (score 12):

## [Java 11 (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 98 bytes

```java
o->{for(int i=-9;++i<9;)System.out.println("".join(" ".repeat(i<0?-i:i),"1234567890".split("")));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU7LTsMwELz3K1Y@xSqxypuQtBwQR8ShR9SD67pljWNb9rqAqnx7cAp7GWkeO2PkUdZm9zmGvLWoQFmZErxKdHCaAfyziSQVOHrcQV@0ak0R3eF9AzIeEgf6iP4rwcu30oHQ/2UBTHkuMqEV@@zUJIhn71LudezetkYrWkFcjr5enfY@VugIcFk37XyOXdPy9U8i3QufSYRSR9ZVjAnjSz8DJqIOWlKF3eKpxkfkF@zy6vrm9u7@oVkwkYJFKn7OeTuMcL72vCoKqaadlcvW8okbZsP4Cw)

- -14 bytes by switching to JDK 11, which now has a native `String::repeat`.

## Previous answer ([Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/)), <s>113</s> 112 bytes

```java
o->{for(int i=-9;++i<9;)System.out.printf("".join("%1$"+(i<0?-i:i>0?i:"")+"s","1234567890".split(""))+"%n","");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7LasMwEEX3@YpBNGDhWjh9O3acRemydJFl6EJR7HRcWTLSKG0J/nZXSTubgXu4nNvJo8zs0Jhu/zkNYadRgdLSe3iVaOA0A/hPPUmK72hxD31kyYYcmsP2HaQ7eA704eyXh5dv1QyE9q8L0EWBCIRatMGoMxDP1vjQN65623WNohrcarJZfWqtS9AQ4CoryjTFqij55sdT0wsbSAxRR23CmOhs1LP54oqlCVb5OsMl1vkal4zxlHl2zRY3t3f3D49PRc6EHzRSrPHI5iZCxstxgsuVl41OSHVenZigNT9n42ycfgE)

#### Explanations

I'm basically constructing the following `String` 17 times (`N` is a variable, not an actual value):

```java
"1%1$Ns2%1$Ns3%1$Ns4%1$Ns5%1$Ns6%1$Ns7%1$Ns8%1$Ns9%1$Ns0%n"
```

It's all the expected digits, joined by `%1$Ns` where `N` is the number of spaces between each digit.

`%1$Ns` basically means "take the first argument and pad it until length is at least `N`". Also, `%1$0s` is not supported so a special case `%1$s` is made for `0`.

Finally, I format-print that string using a single argument: `""`, so the formatter reuses always the same empty string, padding it with spaces as needed.

#### Saves

- 1 byte thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

Comment: Nice answer! Btw, I explicitly mentioned in the challenge an unused empty parameter is allowed, so you can replace `()->` with `o->` to save a byte. :)

Comment: Can you make `o` an `int` and use it in your for loop ? `for(o=-9;++o<9;)`

Comment: @Winter No, because the challenge says "**unused**", and that would use the parameter variable, even if the value wouldn't be used.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire It links to this post https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12681/are-we-allowed-to-use-empty-input-we-wont-use-when-no-input-is-asked-regarding and this posts only says it should be empty (0 for ints).

Comment: @Indeed Indeed, but the challenge itself says "unused". Specific rulings in a challenge overrule defaults.

Comment: Just came across this answer again. In Java 11 this can become [98 bytes](https://tinyurl.com/y7e5dhap) with the use of `" ".repeat` :D I liked your original answer with `printf` more though, but figured it's worth mentioning. EDIT: Just noticed you are asking about updating the JDK in the talk.tio chat. XD Was about to do that myself.

Answer (score 9):

## Clojure, <s>126</s> 99 bytes

-27 by fixing a couple of dumb mistakes. The outer use of `a` wasn't necessary, so I was able to get rid of `a` altogether and just write `apply str` once. That also allowed me to use a function macro for the main function, which saved some bytes. I also inlined the call to `Math/abs` instead of rebinding `n-spaces`.

Basically a Clojure port of @Mr.Xcoder's Python idea. In retrospect, I should have used the `abs`/`range` method for the diamond challenge originally, but I then I may not have produced the bugged output!

Pretty simple. Joins the number string with a number of spaces that depends on the current row.

```clj
#(doseq[n(range -8 9)](println(clojure.string/join(apply str(repeat (Math/abs n)\ ))"1234567890")))
```

---

```clj
(defn bugged []
  (doseq [n-spaces (range -8 9)]
    (println
        (clojure.string/join
          ; "String multiplication"
          (apply str
                 (repeat (Math/abs n-spaces) \space))
          "1234567890"))))
```

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>58</s> <s>57</s> 54 bytes

```python
i=8
while i+9:print(*'1234567890',sep=' '*abs(i));i-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9PWgqs8IzMnVSFT29KqoCgzr0RDS93QyNjE1MzcwtJAXac4tcBWXUFdKzGpWCNTU9M6U9fW8P9/AA)

(thanks to @flornquake for the last three bytes; I completely forgot using `sep` to save vs. `.join`)

Comment: 54 bytes: `while i+9:print(*'1234567890',sep=' '*abs(i));i-=1`

Answer (score 9):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
9{SUē↕∑}¹№╬«
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=OSU3QlNVJXUwMTEzJXUyMTk1JXUyMjExJTdEJUI5JXUyMTE2JXUyNTZDJUFC)
Explanation:

```
9{     }      9 times do
  SU            push "1234567890"
    ē           push e, predefined with the input, which defaults to 0, and then increase it
     ↕          get that many spaces
      ∑         join the string of digits with those spaces
        ¹     collect the results in an array
         №    reverse the array vertically
          ╬«  palindromize vertically with 1 overlap
```

Comment: Oh nice, this is even shorter than the accepted answer. Hmm, what is the policy on shorter answers a couple months after an answer has been accepted? Does this now get the check (kinda unfair to the currently accepted answer I think), or should I do something else? Great answer regardless! +1 from me.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Usually the best practice is to update the accepted answer, but as this uses a couple new features, I'd say there's reason to go either way - you choose.

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript(ES2017), <strike>83</strike> <strike>73</strike> <strike>72</strike> 68 bytes

Thanks [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy) for saving 10 bytes.
Thanks [Craig](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68610/craig-ayre) for saving 1 byte.
Thanks [arcs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70879/arcs) for saving 4 bytes.

```
for(i=-9,a="";i++<8;)a+=[...`1234567890
`].join("".padEnd(i<0?-i:i))
```

```js
for(i=-9,a="";i++<8;)a+=[...`1234567890
`].join("".padEnd(i<0?-i:i))

console.log(a);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
.as-console-row:after { display: none !important; }
```

Comment: Save 1 byte by using a polyfill for `Math.abs`. I also made the `a` list not hardcoded, but that's a preference... `a=[...Array(10).keys()];for(i=-8;i<9;i++)console.log(a.join(' '.repeat(i<0?-i:i)))`

Comment: Save some bytes with `[..."1234567890"].join("".padEnd(i<0?-i:i))`

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks. That saved 10 bytes. :)

Comment: @ThomasW I used `[...'1234567890']`, it saved 3 bytes. Thanks for the polyfill.

Comment: @ThomasW: `[...Array(10).keys]` would have `0` as the first element, not the last.

Comment: You can save a byte using your method storing the result in a string rather than logging: `for(i=-8,s="";i<9;i++)s+=[..."1234567890"].join("".padEnd(i<0?-i:i))+\`X\``, where `X` is an actual newline

Comment: This would be considered JavaScript (ES8) due to its use of `padEnd`.

Comment: @CraigAyre Thanks. And nice to see you here. :)

Comment: @darrylyeo True. I've mentioned it.

Comment: You can save even more by shorting the `for` to `for(i=-9,a="";i++<8;)` and defining the array as ` [...`1234567890
`]` (line break as last character of this), with that you can remove the last addition.

Comment: @arcs Thanks. Answer updated. :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>30</s> <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
Ị↺{∧≜;Ṣj₍g;?↔zcc}ᶠ⁹↔;XcP↔Pẉᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@Hurkdtu6ofdSx/1DnH@uHORVmPmnrTre0ftU2pSk6ufbhtwaPGnUCOdURyAJAKqHu4s738////AA)

*Saved one byte thanks to Leaky Nun*.

#### Explanation

```
Ị↺                               The string "1234567890"
  {               }ᶠ⁹            Find the first 9 outputs of:
   ∧≜                              Take an integer
       ;Ṣj₍                        Juxtapose " " that number of times
           g;?↔z                   Zip that string of spaces with "1234567890"
                cc                 Concatenate twice into one string
                    ↔            Reverse the resuling list
                     ;XcP↔P      Palindromize the list (concatenate X to it into the list P,
                                   P reversed is still P)
                           ẉᵐ    Map writeln
```

Comment: [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@Hurkdtu6ofdSx/1DnH@uHORVmPmnrTre0ftU2pSk6ufbhtwaPGnUCOdURyAJAKeLir8@HWCf///wcA)

Comment: @LeakyNun I got stuck on the big "Print this exact text" and didn't read that we could have trailing lines…

Comment: [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##ATgAx/9icmFjaHlsb2cy//9fODs44p@m4oKCe8inO@G5omrigo1nO@G7iuKGlHrihrpjY@G6iX3htZD//w)

Comment: @LeakyNun Why didn't you post your own answer?

Answer (score 7):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

1 byte thanks to Mnemonic.

```
V17j*da8NeMST
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V17j%2ada8NeMST&debug=0)

Comment: You can save a byte if you loop instead of mapping and joining. [Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V17j%2ada8NeMST&debug=0).

Answer (score 7):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 18 bytes

```
Ｆ⁹⪫⁺…Ｉ¹:⟦0¶⟧× ι‖Ｂ↑
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcaxCsIwEADQ3a84brqDFnS0ndTNSYpO6hDSiwZiIskp@PVnl8fzT1d9cckslAq0ZTjVmJWOJWbazTNNLj@EDq4pbbgDHHDxiutbxvuyc3xJIwTsIDLzuJokJPG6/6hKDelHw@XNo5n1X@tb@gM) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ⁹      Repeat 9 times (i = loop variable)
  ⪫       Join
   ⁺       Concatentate
    …Ｉ¹:    All the characters from str(1) below ":" (i.e. to "9") as a list
    ⟦0¶⟧    A list whose element is the string "0\n"
   × ι     With i spaces
‖Ｂ↑     Reflect everything upwards but without duplicating the top line
```

Note: `Cast(1)` takes the same number of bytes because `"1"` would need a separator before `":"` (which as it happens the deverbosifier fails to insert).

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://cran.r-project.org/), 108 bytes

```
for(i in abs(-8:8))cat(paste0(el(strsplit("1234567890","")),paste(rep(" ",i),collapse=""),collapse=""),"\n")
```

Just pasting and collapsing the strings.

[Try it online!](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=1qEEqjlg)

Edit: thanks for Challenger5 for pointing out a problem. Fixed it now.

Edit 2: saved a byte thanks to bouncyball.

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Comment: This doesn't look quite right - the middle line shouldn't have any spaces at all.

Comment: @Challenger5 you are right! fixed it by using `paste0` instead of `paste` so had to add a byte:(

Comment: save 2 bytes using `el`: `el(strsplit("1234567890",""))` instead of `strsplit("1234567890","")[[1]]`

Comment: You can get rid of one of the `paste` statements by using the `sep` argument to `cat` and doing a bit more to get it to [70 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcHBCoAgDADQe18hO22woG4m9DFLFgiSw/n/670Z8Y6JLbUvyeO455KJqiyseJaLD2LYgF3tNvGlONUQEnAjrqN3MdcbgCjiBw)

Comment: @Giuseppe I think you can post this as a separate answer (and also golf it down to 51 bytes...)

Comment: @JayCe if you have to big of a golf, you should post it yourself!

Comment: @Giuseppe nah... you should post the 70 bytes answer which is the big improvement :)

Answer (score 6):

### Java 8, <strike>235</strike> <strike>234</strike> <strike>206</strike> 163 bytes

```
interface A{static void main(String[]a){for(int i=-8;i<9;i++){String s="";for(int j=1,k;j<10;j++){s+=j;for(k=0;k<(i>0?i:-i);k++)s+=" ";}System.out.println(s+0);}}}
```

**Update** : -28 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun !
**Update 2** : -43 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun again !

Ungolfed :

```
interface A {
    static void main(String[] a) {
        for (int i = -8; i < 9; i++) {
            String s = "";
            for (int j = 1, k; j < 10; j++) {
                s += j;
                for (k = 0; k < (i > 0 ? i : -i); k++)
                    s += " ";
            }
            System.out.println(s + 0);
        }
    }
}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##XY5BCsMgEEWvIq6UNCHZFSYWeoYsSxeSaBltTIg2UMSzpzali3Y5b/7M@0auspxm5cxgtw1dUIuWvSLn6IMM2JN1woGMEh3rwoLudrl6HjU7ckg/CZZvCfL4SREvKAU9LTs2ojlYMG1TgykKHn0hzL60ogbbIthMM6SEQuqePqixmh6hmvOrcHfMF/WfTn912csB83iq37WwbDjsLKW0bS8)

**EDIT :** The code earlier was wrong ! Made a mistake while golfing the code, it should work as intended now !

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! [Tips for golfing in Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java) and [Tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) might be interesting to read through. :) Some things you can golf is removing the `public`, and get rid of some unnecessary spaces. And there are some more things to improve, but I suggest to read through the tips, and see where you can improve yourself. Again welcome, and enjoy your stay! :)

Comment: Hmm, also, are you sure you've posted the correct code? When I copy-paste your code into [TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##XY6xjsIwEER/ZbvsKkeUdEgmn4AoKIHChA23JjiWY0DIyrcHE3TF0T2NRm/G6Lte9I6tOV2myd2OnTQgNrBvdcOw1mIhDkGHFN97OcE1JbgNXux5d4CBILa4JDX@62AygFBsez@jqStlVlWpTJ5TdGhyyw/4WPCNza/2OzlQ4dl1aRizfZn9QAYZJbfD8mvB4eZouAmgKW6fQ@Br0d9C4ZIwdBb1V739OySJ6rqk9JAUdwPHmRzKoiI18ziO0/QC) it doesn't give the correct output.

Comment: Aww damn, i did something wrong while golfing the code ! I'll fix this !

Comment: [206 bytes: some preliminary golfing](https://tio.run/##XY5BCsMgEEWvIq6UNCHZFSYWeoYsSxeSaBltTIg2UMSzpzali3Y5b/7M@0auspxm5cxgtw1dUIuWvSLn6IMM2JN1woGMEh3rwoLudrl6HjU7ckg/CZZvCfL4SREvKAU9LTs2ojlYMG1TgykKHn0hzL60ogbbIthMM6SEQuqePqixmh6hmvOrcHfMF/WfTn912csB83iq37WwbDjsLKW0bS8)

Comment: [186 bytes: remove `f` and merge into `main` with a loop](https://tio.run/##VY1BDsIgFESvQrqCYBu6U3/ReIYujQvSovlgaVOwiSE9OxIbF25n3rwxalHlOGlnepsSuqDnu@o0uUQfVMCOLCP2ZFDoaBtmdI/rzbN4H2eaWYKy3AM2B0DO2UDxJM54LJHB@rfeWBY3A/GyKOCnMLLeWTBNLcBkSfRcmm9ppQDbINic5rAgBazt2wc9VOMrVFNWhaejnot8t6b0AQ)

Comment: [163 bytes: remove `m` also and merge into `main`](https://tio.run/##NczRDoIgFIDhV2FcwUiHd9WRWs/gZeuCKbYDiU7IrTmfnajW9f/tt3rRxTgZbzuXEvpo5l63hlzWEHXEliwjdmTQ6FkTZ/T3603ztR9nli1BVewB6wOgEHz9ARIUpfAXVlU7B7auJNiPCULZb3RKgqsZnuQZjwVycDnnSgmFrXmFaIZyfMZyys/48CwIyWHbtpTe)

Comment: [171 bytes: combine two loops into one](https://tio.run/##JY1LCsMgGISvIkJBSU111RBrSs@QZduF5FH@SDREGyghZ7eGLIYZZviYQS@auamzQ2tiBBu6uddNhx6rDzpAgxYHLRo1WFKHGezn@dZ0PSLyCmPZu5kkDoESZyPhJq5CQpbR1WcKToJX/L5bifnLYgk9OUq6c0ZBVaT9IjgryoLtQZoqiTGaeIyw3OqfD92Yu2/Ip3QbiKdy22L8Aw)

Comment: [148 bytes: one loop](https://tio.run/##PYrLCoJAFEB/ZRgQZhBfGZivpA9o5bJaTDrWNZwRvQkh9uuTblqdA@e0YhKO7qVq65cxoFAOjagkOc0jCoSKTBpq0glQrMQB1ONyE3xu9MDWl0Dup5AFu32Qgm3z8jOi7Fz9RrdfX2TOF6woPPrFBiv@S5afBT5dcR8ZeFHoHHhBCU0oTbbuxXaQUP@qKE@XxZgf)

Comment: Nice one, @LeakyNun, that last one is one byte shorter than my Java answer (if used in the same format). Also, you can extract `i%79` in a variable to gain a few bytes.

Comment: [144 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYvRCoIwGEZfZQyCLdPmnU6X9AxeVhdDV/wON9E/IcRnX4tuDh@c7wx61amfjBt6GwI4NPNTd4ZctwU1QkdWDz0ZNTjW4gzudXtovj39zOKXgEqLk1WigrqsrLJ1kTc2yaU4QpLw9rOgGTP/xmyKKbK/P5QX8WOtGMQFMgXeUEIlpdKey5hTcXeUV/sewhc)

Comment: Nicely fixed after your first edit. :) And golfed a lot of course by LeakyNun afterwards.

Comment: not much but saves you 5 bytes `for(int i=-8,j,k;i++<9;){String s="";for(j=1;j<10;){s+=j++;for(k=0;k++<(i>0?i:-i);)s+=" ";}System.out.println(s+0);}`

Answer (score 6):

### [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 21 bytes

```
mΣṪ`:§+↔tḣR8' ṁs`:0ḣ9
```

This is a full program that prints to STDOUT.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/fc4oc7VyVYHVqu/ahtSsnDHYuDLNQVHu5sLE6wMgDyLP//BwA)
There are lots of trailing spaces.

### Explanation

Husk is still missing lots of essential stuff like a two-argument range function, so parts of this solution are a little hacky.

```
mΣṪ`:§+↔tḣR8' ṁs`:0ḣ9
              ṁs`:0ḣ9  This part evaluates to the string "1234567890".
                   ḣ9   Range from 1 to 9.
                `:0     Append 0.
              ṁs        Convert each number to string and concatenate.
     §+↔tḣR8'          This part evaluates to a list like ["  "," ",""," ","  "]
                       but with 17 elements instead of 5.
          R8'           A string of 8 spaces.
         ḣ              Take prefixes.
     §+                 Concatenate
       ↔                the reversal and
        t               tail of the prefix list, palindromizing it.
  Ṫ                    Take outer product of the two lists
   `:                  with respect to flipped prepeding.
                       This prepends each digit to each string of spaces.
mΣ                     Map concatenation over the results, computing the rows.
                       Implicitly join with newlines and print.
```

Comment: You could replace `ṁs\`:0ḣ9` with `uṁsḣ10` to generate the string "1234567890" with one fewer byte!

Answer (score 6):

## [T-SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) 145 <strike>152</strike> bytes

```
DECLARE @ VARCHAR(MAX)=''SELECT TOP 17@+=REPLACE('1x2x3x4x5x6x7x8x9x0','x',SPACE(ABS(number-8)))+'
'FROM master..spt_values WHERE type='P'PRINT @
```

**Updated** to use:

- `master..spt_values` to generate numbers (`WHERE type = 'P'`, these are always consecutive, starting at 0)
- @ZLK's `TOP 17` idea
- PRINT (to obey the rules - no stringlists)
- @JanDrozen's great idea of including the carriage return in the string (I counted that as just one byte - Windows CRLF what?)
- Idea of @Bridge to use just @ for variable name - all these tricks!!

Results:

```
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0
1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
1234567890
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0
1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0
```

(Thanks @JanDrozen for the REPLACE idea)

Comment: This is a nice answer! Welcome to the site :)

Comment: Thanks. I see some of us have invented our own languages here :)

Comment: A mix between this answer and the other is optimal: e.g. `SELECT TOP 17REPLACE('1x2x3x4x5x6x7x8x9x0','x',SPACE(ABS(9-RANK()OVER(ORDER BY object_id))))FROM sys.objects` (assuming you don't need to print).

Comment: Aha @ZLK - a few nice tricks - TOP 17, RANK OVER, and sys.objects - thank you!

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 92 bytes

```
Column@Join[Reverse@(s=Row/@Table[Riffle[Range@10~Mod~10,""<>Table[" ",i]],{i,0,8}]),Rest@s]
```

[Try it online](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/)

copy/paste code with ctrl-v
press shift+enter to run

Comment: Could you perhaps add a [TryItOnline](https://tio.run/#) link?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Mathematica is not a free language, and [Mathics doesn't seem to work](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv7/P6AoM6/EwTk/pzQ3z8ErPzMvOii1LLWoONVBo9g2KL9c3yEkMSknNTooMy0NRCXmpac6GBrU@ean1Bka6Cgp2dhBFCgpKOlkxsbqVGfqGOhY1MZq6gSlFpc4FMf@/w8A).

Comment: @LeakyNun Ah ok, thanks. I see MartinEnder post TIO-links sometimes, but those were indeed Mathics links.

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen yes of course, I added link with instructions

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
8ŒRA⁶ẋØDṙ1¤jÐ€Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9qZWxsef//OMWSUkHigbbhuovDmEThuZkxwqRqw5DigqxZ//8)

Answer (score 5):

## C, 97 bytes

```c
i=-9;main(j){for(;++i<9;putchar(10))for(j=0;++j<11;printf("        "+8-abs(i)))putchar(48+j%10);}
```

Your compiler will probably complain a *lot* about this code; mine threw 7 warnings of 4 different types. Might improve the code later.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtBCoAgEAC/EkGwiwgKHZStx5hQrZSF1Sl6uxXUHGcYL/3k4pAzt9LS7DhCwLNfEpAQ3Fhaj92PLoFWiK8OrXpKaLSmNXHceyiLj1IY6boNGBH/rTYiVM9LV843)

Answer (score 5):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
ā9{SUčf@*∑Κ}╬Æ
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUwMTAxOSU3QlNVJXUwMTBEZkAqJXUyMjExJXUwMzlBJTdEJXUyNTZDJUM2)

Explanation:

```
ā               push an empty array
 9{        }    9 times do
   SU             push "1234567890"
     č            chop into characters
      f@*         get current iteration (0-based) amount of spaces
         ∑        join with that
          Κ       prepend this to the array
            ╬Æ  palindromize vertically with 1 overlap
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <strike>21 20 19</strike> 18 bytes

```
Ｆ⁹«Ｆ…¹χ⁺κ… ι0⸿»‖Ｂ↑
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nmWPGnceWg2iG5Yd2nm@/VHjrnO7gGyFczsNHu3Yf2j3o4Zp7/csetQ28f9/AA)

Link to [the verbose version](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBw1KTq5pLQQHMDkrMS0/VMNQxNNDUBIopKAQUZeaVaDimpGhk6yhAZJUUlHQUMjU1Na25YPJKBjFFSkB@LVdQalpOanKJU2lJSWpRWk6lhlVogab1////dcv@6xbnAAA). Basically I create the lower part of the drawing and then reflect the text up.

Comment: When I saw the question I though I'd try this myself in Charcoal before looking at the answer. I started with a 21-byte answer but golfed it to 20 bytes... spooky!

Comment: @Neil :-D Well, it's 19 bytes now!

Comment: Yup, just found that golf myself. I was also looking into `Ｅ…⁹⪫Ｅ…·¹χＩ﹪κχ× ι‖Ｂ↑` (also for 19 bytes) but the interpreter doesn't seem to like it (I can't see what's wrong with it myself).

Comment: Oh, Range takes two arguments, silly me.

Comment: @Neil I've never managed to write an answer in Charcoal using the `map` (`Ｅ`) operator...

Comment: My best Map attempt is still 20 bytes: `Ｆ⁹⪫⁺Ｅ…¹χＩκ⟦0¶⟧× ι‖Ｂ↑`. (Edit: typo fix)

Comment: Turns out `Map` was a red herring, so I've now posted my 18-byte answer.

Answer (score 4):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 21 bytes

```
A,(+aH*ee{:\8-zS**n}/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/31FHQzvRQys1tdoqxkK3KlhLK69W//9/AA)

#### Explanation

```
A,     e# Get [0 1 2 ... 9].
(+     e# Rotate the 0 to the end.
aH*    e# Wrap in an array and repeat 17 times.
ee     e# Enumerate. This pairs each copy of the array with its index in
       e# the list.
{      e# For each [index array] pair...
  :\   e#   Unwrap the pair and swap its order.
  8-z  e#   Get the absolute difference of the index from 8.
  S*   e#   Get a string of that many spaces.
  *    e#   Riffle the list of digits with the string of spaces.
  n    e#   Print it with a trailing linefeed.
}/
```

Comment: Alternative solution (also 21 bytes): `9{S*A,(+\*}%_W%);\+N*`

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 69 bytes

```php
for(;$i<17;)echo join(str_pad("",abs($i++-8)),range(1,9)+[9=>0]),"
";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVMm0Mza01U5Mz8hWy8jPzNIpLiuILElM0lJR0EpOKNVQytbV1LTQ1dYoS89JTNQx1LDW1oy1t7QxiNXWUuJSs//8HAA)

Answer (score 4):

### Batch, 163 bytes

```
@set s=1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
@set t=         
@for %%l in (9 7)do @for /l %%i in (1,1,%%l)do @call:%%l
:7
@set t=  %t%
:9
@set t=%t:~1%
@call echo %%s: =%t%%%
```

Note: First line ends in 9 spaces. Explanation: Uses creative line numbering! The first loop needs to run 9 times and delete a space each time, while the second loop needs to run 8 times and add a space each time. The former is achieved by running it 7 times and falling through for the 8th time, while the latter is achieved by adding two spaces and falling through to delete one of them again.

Answer (score 4):

## bash (and shell utils), 69 bytes

```
for i in `seq 9 -1 1;seq 2 9`;do seq -f%-$i.f 9|tr -d \\n;echo 0;done
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 76 bytes

```c
f(x,y){for(y=-9;++y<9;puts(""))for(x=10;x++;printf("%-*d",abs(y)+1,x%=10));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCoAgEADAvwjCbquQR9l8TBlGlxI1UKK3W12H8XrzvvcAVTW8w5mgOW2ZqE2W41UyCIH4e3Vm5ErEMe1HCSCkHlah5iVDQzKqyi8g8tP7Cw)

It outputs some trailing spaces, which is supposed to be OK.

It prints the numbers using left-justified fields of dynamic length - that's what the format string `%-*d` is for.

The inner loop has some funny initialization (starts from 10; any multiple of 10 would be fine) to "simplify" its termination condition.

Comment: [75 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcpNCoAgEEDhdR5DCGZSIZcydBgzDBeV2A9KdHar7fueU7NztXrIsuDttwRlMKRUEYbieezAOeKf86B7ykJQTGE9PPBWdROXdtyhoNAyt9@ASE/9mC02rHBtYUJ2s8YDEnvqCw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```perl
$,=$"x abs,say 1..9,0for-8..8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19Fx1ZFqUIhMalYpzixUsFQT89SxyAtv0jXQk/P4v//f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA)

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 30 bytes

```powershell
8..0+1..8|%{1..9+0-join' '*$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30JPz0DbUE/Poka1GkhZahvoZuVn5qkrqGupxNf@//8fAA)

Constructs a range of `8,7,6...2,1,0,1,2...8` then loops through each number. Inside the loop we construct a range of `1..9` concatenated with `0` then `-join` the numbers in the range together with the appropriate number of spaces. Each string is left on the pipeline, and output is implicit at program completion.

Comment: Nice answer! Powershell suddenly feels more golfy :)

Answer (score 4):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) `-nr`, <s>50</s> <s>46</s> 45 bytes

```
[range(9)+1,0|@sh]|join(range(17)-8|" "*fabs)
```

[Try it on jqplay!](https://jqplay.org/s/YprXW9RX0z)

`[range(9)+1,0|@sh]` generates the array `["1", "2", ..., "9", "0"]`. This list is then joined by each of the results from:

`range(17)-8`: -8, -7, ..., 7, 8
`" "*fabs` a string of absolute value spaces

Comment: [Sorry...](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222498/100664)

Comment: @emanresuA Yeah I've seen that before writing the answer. I will let you know when I posted an answer to a challenge you haven't

Answer (score 3):

## perl 5: <strike>43</strike>, <strike>39</strike>, 31 bytes

Needs `-E` flag (which is free per our [consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/274/55508)).

```
map{$,=$"x abs;say 1..9,0}-8..8
```

**Usage:**

```
perl -E 'map{$,=$"x abs;say 1..9,0}-8..8'
```

Thanks to Dada

Comment: That's nice! `-E` flag is free per our [consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/273/55508). Also, you probably wanted `-8..8` instead of `-8..9`. And you can save a few bytes by playing with `$,` instead of `$"`: `map{$,=$"x abs;say 1..9,0}-8..8` ([31 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqlBmqmdoYP0/N7GgWkXHVkWpQiExqdi6OLFSwVBPz1LHoFbXQk/P4v9/AA)).

Comment: @Dada:You're right, thank you, 4 bytes saved!

Comment: You don't even need to declare `@l`: just use `say 1..9,0` :)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript, 67 Bytes

```
f=(i=8)=>i+9?[...`1234567890
`].join(''.padEnd(i<0?-i:i))+f(i-1):''
```

```js
f=(i=8)=>i+9?[...`1234567890
`].join(''.padEnd(i<0?-i:i))+f(i-1):''

console.log(f())
```

Answer (score 3):

### [LOGO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fmslogo/), <s>58</s> 57 bytes

```
for[j 8 -8][repeat 9[type # repeat abs :j[type "\ ]]pr 0]
```

This should be run on new versions of FMSLogo (link above), where `#` is `repcount` in `repeat` loops. That is a new feature in FMSLogo, which seems to be undocumented.

Answer (score 3):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), <s>36</s> 32 bytes

```
[-8,8|?[|?!b%z$';space$(abs(a));
```

### Explanation

```
[-8,8|     FOR a = -8; a <= 8; a++      Sets upthe number of lines
?          Kick off each line with a \n
[|         FOR b = 1; b <= 10; b++      Loop over each digit: default behaviour for a no-arg FOR declaration
?          PRINT    
 !   $     a strng cast (suppresses QBasic's tendency to space out numbers)
  b%z      of b modulo 10 (z is 10 in QBIC)
 '         Then take the next bit of code as literal QBasic
 ;         Suppress newlines and tabs
 space$    Add x spaces to the output, where X is
 (abs(a))  The absolute line number
 ;         And suppress all newlines and tabs after this too
           A closing ` to this code literal is auto added by QBIC at EOF
           Two closing NEXT statements are also auto-added.
```

### Sample output

Just because I really like the pattern. Note that this took some fiddling in QBasic because the usual terminal output is limited to 80 chars and it wraps.

```
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0        
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0       
1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0      
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0     
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0    
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 
1234567890
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0    
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0     
1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0      
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0       
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/index.htm), 85 bytes

```
(dotimes(i 17)(format t(format()"~~{~~,,~aa~~}
"(abs(- i 8)))'(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LchLCoAwDAXAqzwEMQEF6696nPiDgqLY7sRcvbpwN8y0OX/GSPMR3L54cjCWaT2uXQLCD@JE9VbNcxVRfTRNSEZPBRx6Zs7IoEKNBi06WPQYUH4f4ws)

`format` “magic” of Common Lisp:

```
(dotimes (i 17)                     ; for i from 0 to 16
  (format t                         ; print with a format string generated from the next call
          (format ()                ; with nil as parameter generates a string instead of printing
                  "~~{~~,,~aa~~}
"                                   ; generate the format string "~{~,,na~}~%" with n given
                  (abs(- i 8)))     ;     by the value of abs(i-8) (number of spaces)
          '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0)))  ; the data to be printed for each line
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 21 bytes

```
-9Zv"l4Y29YS10:q@*Q(c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X9cyqkwpxyTSyDIy2NDAqtBBK1Aj@f9/AA)

Explanation:

```
-9Zv                  % Generates [9 ... 2, 1, 2, ... 9]. 
    "                 % Iterate over this vector.
                   (  % Assignment indexing. Places elements B at positions C in existing vector A.
     l                %   A: Dummy vector with numeric [1] in it. Is always overwritten by char '1'.
      4Y29YS          %   B:  '0':'9', circularly shifted 9 positions to get '1':'9','0'
            10:q@*Q   %   C: Equally spaced indexing vector, spacing based on loop variable @.
                    c % Convert to char, because A was numeric.
```

Golfing done:

```
-9Zv     -->  built-in, instead of -8:8|Q or even 8:PQ9:h| 
10:q@*Q  -->  2 bytes shorter than l@@10*3$:
l ... c  -->  1 byte shorter than 'x' (char dummy vector A)
```

I have attempted to get rid of the `9YS` by doing the circular shift in the indexing, but this increased the byte count (`10t:qwX\q@*Q` instead of `9YS10:q@*Q`). However, some interesting patterns were obtained in the process: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38IqINDSKqNGKcck0sjQoMQq0EGrPEYj@f9/AA), [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38IqINDSKqNGKcck0sjQoMQq0EErRiP5/38A).

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>25</s> 22 bytes

```
(1 j.|i:8)#"{1|.Num_j_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I1/DUCFLrybTykJTWanasEbPrzQ3Piv@/38A)

Answer (score 3):

### PHP, 76 Bytes

Update: Thanks to [Soaku](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72792/soaku) for the addition.

```
for($i=-9;$i++<8;)echo join(str_repeat(' ',abs($i)),range(1,9)+[9=>0])."
";
```

[Try it online !](https://3v4l.org/jrIcR)

### PHP, <s>88, 86, 80</s>

Thanks to [Caird](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing) for suggesting the golfing tips.

```
for($i=-9;$i++<8;)echo join(str_repeat(' ',abs($i)),[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0])."\r";
```

[You can try it here!](https://3v4l.org/fDBQp)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and be sure to check [these](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2913/66833) tips for golfing in PHP!

Comment: Sorry so late, but I golfed it down to [76 bytes](https://3v4l.org/jrIcR)

Comment: `str_pad("",abs($i))` is four bytes shorter than `str_repeat(' ',abs($i))`.

Answer (score 3):

### [Perl 6](https://perl6.org/), <strike>43 37</strike> 35 bytes

Originally, I came to:

```
map({say join " "x abs($_-8),1..9,0},0..16)
```

The say function in perl 6 automatically adds a newline, and it's map works a bit different from perl 5, requiring less parens due to it's more list based approach.
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/z83sUCjujixUiErPzNPQUlBqUIhMalYQyVe10JTx1BPz1LHoFbHQE/P0Ezz/38A)

Fortunately, [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king) showed how to whittle it down further to 35 bytes:

```
{say join " "x.abs,1..9,0}for ^17-8
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/7@6OLFSISs/M09BSUGpQi8xqVjHUE/PUsegNi2/SCHO0FzX4v9/AA)

Comment: `0..16` => `^17`

Comment: Or you can change to a list and use the list repetition operator for [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVIjKz8zT0FJQalCITGpWENFW1vXQlPHUE/PUsdAs6JCwdD8/38A "Perl 6 – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks, there's always more to learn :)
Interestingly, the code that runs on TIO perl6 does not run with rakudo, unless I change $++ to $_++

Comment: Huh. Well, here's [35 byter](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/7@6OLFSISs/M09BSUGpQi8xqVjHUE/PUsegNi2/SCHO0FzX4v9/AA) that uses a for loop

Comment: Too good! Thank you for sharing, I'm just starting to dabble with perl 6

Comment: Ah, I found the problem with $++ vs $_++, perl6 version 2013.12 built on parrot 5.9.0 revision 0, vs perl6 version 2015.11 built on MoarVM version 2015.11, where it behaves as on TIO.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 51 bytes

```r
for(i in abs(-8:8))cat(1:9,0,"
",sep=strrep(" ",i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPITGpWEPXwspCUzM5sUTD0MpSx0BHiUtJpzi1wLa4pKgotUBDSUFJJ1NT8/9/AA)

Managed to find some more bytes thanks to JayCe's suggestion in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

## C, <strike>135</strike> 128 characters

#### -7 characters thanks to [kevin cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

```c
#define p printf
i=1,j,h=9,k;main(){for(;++i<22;i<10?h--:h++,p("\n"))for(j=0;++j<11;)for(p(j==10?"0":"%d",j),k=1;k++<h;)p(" ");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpBDsIgEEDRvacgGJOSgQS6swPxIm4MLTIQKWncmZ4dsS7/y/fq6X1r53kJVBZWWd2ovMOJnJFJRneVGV8PKoP4hHUbCAHIjiP@MzndIVljOtSezugb13zil5nLJPA3ZWcwA9h4PJxxgftOtp9RqSkCYNd7Obi1Lw)

---

#### Fun bonus:

On my first compile I got the logic backwards and ended up with the output in reverse

```c
i=1,j,k,h=9;main(){for(;i++<20;){for(j=0;j++<10;){printf(j==10?"0":"%d",j);for(k=1;k++<10-h;){printf(" ");}}i<11?h--:h++;printf("\n");}}
```

Edit: removed missed whitespace

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Great first answer.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This is indeed a great first answer, +1 from me. 7 bytes can be saved by removing all the brackets and putting everything inside the loop declarations: [`i=1,j,h=9,k;main(){for(;++i<22;i<10?h--:h++,p("\n"))for(j=0;++j<11;)for(p(j==10?"0":"%d",j),k=1;k++<h;)p(" ");}` **128 bytes**](https://tio.run/##HcvBCgIhFIXhfU8x3AiUq6Cza67Si7QJZ8yrZDK0i57drOX5@U7Q9xB6P65b5LpNbWo711c8sLcqq@TPqtDjxlXId3zughDZzTOxs@aStF4SomoCrhWk/IHszTDZWUv/3Ubxw4KBBU4rqCxV8ZYKokskx3UCSZ/evw) Enjoy your stay!

Comment: [84 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzOi2/SCPT1sA6U1vbxtDcwLqgKDOvJE1DSTVFtVhJJ1PV0ABM2KspKUCBUnSmjaWBfaa@oYGVoZkuiI61UorJU9LUtK79n5uYmaehqVDNxZmmoWnNVfv/X3JaTmJ68X/dcgA) by utilizing a single loop, print, and iteration variable, and switching to `f()` instead of main.

Comment: [69 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzOi2/SCPT1sA6U1vbxtDcwLqgKDOvJE1DSTVFVatYSSdT1dBAJzGpWCNT39BA10ITLGCvpGSlFJOnpKlpXfs/NzEzTwNojoamNQjX/gcA "C (gcc) – Try It Online") building on @Rogem

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 15 bytes

```
8N8ṡȧƛð$ẋ9ʀ1Ǔ$j
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=8N8%E1%B9%A1%C8%A7%C6%9B%C3%B0%24%E1%BA%8B9%CA%801%C7%93%24j&inputs=&header=&footer=)

-1 byte thanks to Aaron Miller

```
8N                 -8
  8                 8
   ṡ                inclusive range; -8, -7, ..., 7, 8
    ȧ               abs; 8, 7, ..., 1, 0, 1, ..., 7, 8
     ƛ---------     for each
      ð$            push space and swap it underneath
        ẋ           repeat the space N times
         9ʀ         [0, 1, ..., 8, 9]
           1Ǔ       rotate left once
             $j     swap and join

j (flag)            join on newlines
```

Comment: [15 bytes because structures auto-complete](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=8N8%E1%B9%A1%C8%A7%C6%9B%C3%B0%24%E1%BA%8B9%CA%801%C7%93%24j&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: @AaronMiller oh right, that's why i was using the `j` flag

Comment: [13 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=jr&code=8N8%E1%B9%A1%C8%A7%C6%9B%C3%B0*!9%CA%80%C7%93j&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 3):

## [Dash](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell)*, 69 bytes

```sh
seq -- -8 8|xargs -I: sh -c 'seq -s"`printf "%:s_"`" 10'|sed s/_1*//g
```

Hopefully this iteration is fairly self explanatory -- pretty much a straight swap of `for` to `xargs`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0kszvj/vzi1UEFXV0HXQsGipiKxKL1YQdfTSqE4Q0E3WUEdLFmslFBQlJlXkqagpGpVHK@UoKRgaKBeU5yaolCsH2@opa@f/v8/AA)

## [Dash](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell)*, <s>87</s>, <s>86</s>, 73 bytes

```sh
for p in `seq -- -8 8`;do seq -s"`printf "%${p}s_"`" 10;done|sed s/_1*//g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpBCoAgEAXQq3ykNoGYO6HDOIFabtScdtXZp2j54IWVd5FUOxpyAXE8oDW0g6MlVPxmRa3nciaocbjaw16Rgp2/UOLNMYCNt5Mxm8gL)

#### Explanation (`for` method)

```sh
for p in `seq -- -8 8`
```

Produce -8 to 8, used to create separator in next `seq`.
*NB BusyBox’s* `seq` barfs on the `-8` without the `--` but TIO’s Dash env does not.*

```sh
;do seq -s"`printf "%${p}s_"`" 10
```

Print 1-10, separated with `p` × spaces, with an extra `_` appended (because `seq` won't accept an empty separator).

```sh
;done|sed s/_1*//g
```

Remove the `_` as well as the `1` from trailing `10`.

*EDIT: removed a silly space (thanks Kevin Cruijssen)*

*EDIT: saved many bytes because negative padding printf doesn't matter*

*EDIT: scraped off another few bytes by ditching the `for` in favour of `xargs`.*

**<sub>*Actually this is aimed at Busybox 1.31.1 `ash`, `sed`, `seq` and `printf`, but TIO didn't have that environment.  NB available `seq` options are limited to `-w` and `-s`.</sub>**

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Bash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15279/tips-for-golfing-in-bash) page for ways you can golf your program (they're likely to be applicable to Dash as well)

Comment: Nice first answer, welcome to CGCC! I think you can remove the space between `10 ;`?

Comment: Not sure how that sneaked in there, thanks @KevinCruijssen

Answer (score 2):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 18 bytes

```
¬19á08ñÄÓä/& 
YGpH
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v92///CrDE5w6EwOMOxw4TDk8OkLyYgCllHcEj//w)

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3.1, <s>186</s> 182 bytes**

```
func f(_ n:Int=0,_ u:Bool=true){let p={if n<8{f(n+1,u)}};let q={print((1...9).map{String($0)+String(repeating:" ",count:n)}.joined()+"0")};if u{q();p()}else{p();q()}};f(1,false);f()
```

Explanation

```
func f(_ n:Int=0,_ u:Bool=true){          function (recursive) that does
                                          all the heavy-lifting =) 
                                          n - number of spaces,
                                          u - go "up" or "down
let p={if n<8 {f(n+1,u)}}                 closure that runs f on higher step if can
let q={                                   closure which does the printing
print((1...9).map{                        print closed range of number mapped...
String($0)+String(repeating:" ",count:n)  ...making String from each number in range
                                          and appending n spaces to it
.joined()+"0")                            join all "1    "-like strings and append "0"
if u{q();p()}                             if go "up" - then call f before printing
else{p();q()}                             if go "down - the other way
f(1,false);f()                            run "up" then "down"
```

Removed some silly spaces. Thanx to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

Comment: I feel there is a room for an improvement, though

Comment: I've never programmed in Swift, so perhaps I'm saying something stupid here, but is it possible to remove some of those spaces? Like the one here: `n<8 {f(n+1`; here: `count:n) }`; here: `p()} else{p()`; and/or here `q()}}; f(1,false`?

Comment: [171 bytes](http://rextester.com/HTUP77668)

Answer (score 2):

## q/kdb+, 37 bytes

**Solution:**

```
-1" "{raze(1_11#.Q.n),\:y#x}'8-(!)17;
```

**Example:**

```
q)-1" "{raze(1_11#.Q.n),\:y#x}'8-(!)17;
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0        
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0       
1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0      
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0     
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0    
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 
1234567890
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0    
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0     
1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0      
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0       
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0
```

**Explanation:**

q is evaluation right-to-left. Here we are taking the range of -8..0..8, and joining that many spaces with the list "1234567890". We then use `-1` to print out to stdout (rather than returning the list of strings).

```
-1 " "{raze (1_11#.Q.n),\:y#x}'8 - til 17; / ungolfed solution
                                   til 17  / range of 0..16
                               8 -         / take 8 from each value, gives -8..0..8
   " "{                      }'            / each left/right, passes in " " and then -8, -7, etc..
                          y#x              / take from list " ", note: negatives take from 'back' of list
                       ,\:                 / \: is 'each left', , means concatenate with, so take each left and concatenate with the right
            (1_11#.Q.n)                    / 'the left'. .Q.n is range 0-9 as a string, take 11 to get 0123..90, then drop the first
       raze                                / reduce down output list into a single string
-1                                       ; / print to stdout and swallow return value (-1)
```

**Notes:**

Doing `(1_11#.Q.n)` is 1 byte shorter than the much more straightforward `"1234567890"`... but as `.Q.n` returns `"0123456789"` some manipulation is required.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby 2.4, 40 bytes

```
-8.upto 8{|i|puts [*1..9,0]*(' '*i.abs)}
```

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) (lower than 2.4), 41 bytes

```ruby
-8.upto(8){|i|puts [*1..9,0]*(' '*i.abs)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X9dCr7SgJF/DQrO6JrOmoLSkWCFay1BPz1LHIFZLQ11BXStTLzGpWLP2/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 71 bytes

```php
while($y<17)echo chunk_split(1234567890,1,str_pad("",abs($y++-8))),"
";
```

Run with `-nr` or [test it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/42f1ae4e3f96340c988e057805c7823a235b0b66).

Comment: Inspired by your solution, I got my solution down to 66: `while($i<17)echo implode(str_pad('',abs($i++-8)),range(1,9))."\n";`

Comment: Oops! Looks like I made an incorrect assumption about the output. I thought it was 123456789

Answer (score 2):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 140 bytes

:P

```
0000000: ad92 510e c230 0c43 ff39 0547 802c f3bc  ..Q..0.C.9.G.,..
0000010: fb5f 8c10 c5d1 5a09 10b0 7d59 b1fd b4b6  ._....Z...}Y....
0000020: b95f eb33 8945 c225 5609 486c 1294 d825  ._.3.E.%V.Hl...%
0000030: 6e17 216d 02fa 84c3 04a3 5033 c906 8e0f  n.!m......P3....
0000040: 140c 0c8a 3000 ec50 f743 1987 2abb d83d  ....0..P.C..*..=
0000050: eb96 7707 dda0 f215 b70a 7b45 5141 66ac  ..w.......{EQAf.
0000060: 5296 19cf 04d2 67ba 4fd3 c2f2 3010 63c6  R.....g.O...0.c.
0000070: 3066 b6f8 8a8d fb0b fb0d eff3 2f7d 77ce  0f........../}w.
0000080: 1faf f3df 773c 7fa5 cedf f707            ....w<......
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZG9blUxEIR7nmIo0iC0rP/tKBQIRdCRUCBBg7y2N01CF90C5dkve865AkayZVveT7Oz8izyuB6en85nPnSNPptHcrwwfGDwiAGqoYFTLKjsBzTIAIjuiZg@UqNP9Jbo1Q5whlBJijocY6TpkDo3OBZGmalBnE5IlGyIn2T6Yevl@3Y6EN4Q0gyxJATUFpNZ8QkpGyfWPOB8i5jV3jZEoFu6@kafH41wdSCCIfJyBd7lCfbaUeMI4NgDEht2NM6oixX4Ra@faNdd@OciGsJFHpZA7Qj2gjUSQ4sF4lo1dhcxF2FuWWxR0J2lQW@I3h@IZIglLaMULpizW7V3CVK4o4j1lVx0yLnvcZ4OE/T79v6DXlxkQyRvCNeGmv3pkYt0RJ3Wg1dvziznHIbF@XUvf6Avu5txQRRDBM4ZkrWi9jptQCzbNrFstPBapnkcC2Clv3r3crog6paFdrXJT7WfYaBot7Esu@rW3H/aSk83B@J8/gM)

Do I get brownie points for having `._.` two times in the dump?

Comment: [131 bytes](https://tio.run/##hZBLaxUwEIX3/oqzENwNk2TyEqS4sbcg2IWL4qrJJGnRFkVowYW//Trh3oo7Z5EHzHxzzulPvT/Mu6fH45HP9RbBR0Fh9rDvQgrZXiIOrBzQ3FqQ1APgP5OV/qT3@/5Ar04EZ4wUZ4dqWOhuOYy4FL15QeJUIMoDI2QGJtHFnqbXt/cfiX6cGd4YZQyGlGKt3obK2IuXVoirDDdDRWoqANGB6J7o0xZSv77oCFtHqQ7NB8EsNtSc8wgiBZEjmxh7ac4JsHHZMuRwfX17oOczQ4zRa7PtsRSE3NlS8BmBZ8PykzGDMmpecesgykRvmE51ZkRjSJ7JWmPDkGg71eJcyoxcx0QedefcB3BJ9IVutpFf9Jv0hZG2Fw0DyVc7urNQchqW5ArQYmLSMm4TrsDDu07fiB4tT/p@81dHNkYtkjGKVGtdFTWoYnITC8VNtGo6mphd0CVdnVzIv17KZiyTzA7/LRs7Hv8A)

Comment: How did I get out-golfed in Bubblegum? o0 What compression method did you use?

Comment: I used zopfli to generate a DEFLATE stream. I got to [130 bytes](https://tio.run/##jdJNS10xEAbgvb/iXYiblpBkJl9dVLRXoUK7ENtF6SaZJEKpLvyAVvvfbyd4L24dODkETp4z553THlv7Pa4fb7Zbu6sPIB8Y2VoP3XZMigNC1sKKJZBrDJnEgL8yq27X4ozhgxfBqZHdFPSZJppzAidtYgxvUZwXVHIFvbsMmH3BvF@3neHVkKgvKbE55B4JSWii@FyRfapIPlZEH6oarAfl37GuT3e/2o@dQWoEzxXsuYMjBzAzra1DtSOjK4JELgGXF6dfzs82n05PVDm63/fBahSSDN9ChGcZiIpArE1IMzFSG4KUB69veff90PSNCg/P5s/eCGqk2gXsQkDJuSGLbagyG2jMiZhGQA@TgCdz8u0lkI/m@jWPuPrIVDCmxpmoNvQoCWEZU3IEh6LJ2FS0j2LMvZ79qdeZMX93Rlpz4aJRsD5KU4pOlAe4DtK5TA2qaLqzjmWYjdFAv16o8fm1j6yG6/ovvKWM2W7/Aw) with 222 iterations.

Comment: For some reason the byte count went up with more then 314 iterations. [zopfli link](https://tio.run/##jdJNS10xEAbgvb/iXYiblpBkJl9dVLRXoUK7ENtF6SaZJEKpLvyAVvvfbyd4L24dODkETp4z553THlv7Pa4fb7Zbu6sPIB8Y2VoP3XZMigNC1sKKJZBrDJnEgL8yq27X4ozhgxfBqZHdFPSZJppzAidtYgxvUZwXVHIFvbsMmH3BvF@3neHVkKgvKbE55B4JSWii@FyRfapIPlZEH6oarAfl37GuT3e/2o@dQWoEzxXsuYMjBzAzra1DtSOjK4JELgGXF6dfzs82n05PVDm63/fBahSSDN9ChGcZiIpArE1IMzFSG4KUB69veff90PSNCg/P5s/eCGqk2gXsQkDJuSGLbagyG2jMiZhGQA@TgCdz8u0lkI/m@jWPuPrIVDCmxpmoNvQoCWEZU3IEh6LJ2FS0j2LMvZ79qdeZMX93Rlpz4aJRsD5KU4pOlAe4DtK5TA2qaLqzjmWYjdFAv16o8fm1j6yG6/ovvKWM2W7/Aw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Cubically](//git.io/cubically), 2622 bytes

```
U3D1R3L1F3B1U1D3+3111111@6-2111@66666666+21111@6-21111@66666666+211111@6-211111@66666666+0@6-0@66666666+01@6-01@66666666+011@6-011@66666666+0111@6-0111@66666666+4@6-4@66666666+41@6-41@66666666+211@6-511111@6+5111111@6-2111@6666666+21111@6-21111@6666666+211111@6-211111@6666666+0@6-0@6666666+01@6-01@6666666+011@6-011@6666666+0111@6-0111@6666666+4@6-4@6666666+41@6-41@6666666+211@6-511111@6+5111111@6-2111@666666+21111@6-21111@666666+211111@6-211111@666666+0@6-0@666666+01@6-01@666666+011@6-011@666666+0111@6-0111@666666+4@6-4@666666+41@6-41@666666+211@6-511111@6+5111111@6-2111@66666+21111@6-21111@66666+211111@6-211111@66666+0@6-0@66666+01@6-01@66666+011@6-011@66666+0111@6-0111@66666+4@6-4@66666+41@6-41@66666+211@6-511111@6+5111111@6-2111@6666+21111@6-21111@6666+211111@6-211111@6666+0@6-0@6666+01@6-01@6666+011@6-011@6666+0111@6-0111@6666+4@6-4@6666+41@6-41@6666+211@6-511111@6+5111111@6-2111@666+21111@6-21111@666+211111@6-211111@666+0@6-0@666+01@6-01@666+011@6-011@666+0111@6-0111@666+4@6-4@666+41@6-41@666+211@6-511111@6+5111111@6-2111@66+21111@6-21111@66+211111@6-211111@66+0@6-0@66+01@6-01@66+011@6-011@66+0111@6-0111@66+4@6-4@66+41@6-41@66+211@6-511111@6+5111111@6-2111@6+21111@6-21111@6+211111@6-211111@6+0@6-0@6+01@6-01@6+011@6-011@6+0111@6-0111@6+4@6-4@6+41@6-41@6+211@6-511111@6+5111111@6+1@6+1@6+1@6+1@6+1@6+1@6+1@6+1@6-111111111@6-511111@6+5111111@6-2111@6+21111@6-21111@6+211111@6-211111@6+0@6-0@6+01@6-01@6+011@6-011@6+0111@6-0111@6+4@6-4@6+41@6-41@6+211@6-511111@6+5111111@6-2111@66+21111@6-21111@66+211111@6-211111@66+0@6-0@66+01@6-01@66+011@6-011@66+0111@6-0111@66+4@6-4@66+41@6-41@66+211@6-511111@6+5111111@6-2111@666+21111@6-21111@666+211111@6-211111@666+0@6-0@666+01@6-01@666+011@6-011@666+0111@6-0111@666+4@6-4@666+41@6-41@666+211@6-511111@6+5111111@6-2111@6666+21111@6-21111@6666+211111@6-211111@6666+0@6-0@6666+01@6-01@6666+011@6-011@6666+0111@6-0111@6666+4@6-4@6666+41@6-41@6666+211@6-511111@6+5111111@6-2111@66666+21111@6-21111@66666+211111@6-211111@66666+0@6-0@66666+01@6-01@66666+011@6-011@66666+0111@6-0111@66666+4@6-4@66666+41@6-41@66666+211@6-511111@6+5111111@6-2111@666666+21111@6-21111@666666+211111@6-211111@666666+0@6-0@666666+01@6-01@666666+011@6-011@666666+0111@6-0111@666666+4@6-4@666666+41@6-41@666666+211@6-511111@6+5111111@6-2111@6666666+21111@6-21111@6666666+211111@6-211111@6666666+0@6-0@6666666+01@6-01@6666666+011@6-011@6666666+0111@6-0111@6666666+4@6-4@6666666+41@6-41@6666666+211@6-511111@6+5111111@6-2111@66666666+21111@6-21111@66666666+211111@6-211111@66666666+0@6-0@66666666+01@6-01@66666666+011@6-011@66666666+0111@6-0111@66666666+4@6-4@66666666+41@6-41@66666666+211@6
```

Pretty simple, turns the cube to get it into this:

```
   242
   202
   242
000131555313
010121535343
000131555313
   424
   454
   424
```

Now the LEFT face sums up to 1. So we use the other faces to get as close to the desired ASCII values as possible, then just increment/decrement by 1.

This also works:

## Cubically, 2938 bytes

```
:4/1+5@6/1+3@66666666+2@6-2@66666666:5+1/1+5@6/1+3@66666666:5+2/1+5@6/1+3@66666666:5+3/1+5@6/1+3@66666666:5+1@6:5/1+3@66666666:1/1+51@6:5/1+3@66666666:2/1+51@6:5/1+3@66666666/1+51@6:5/1+3@66666666/1+5@6:1/1+1@6:4/1+5@6/1+3@6666666+2@6-2@6666666:5+1/1+5@6/1+3@6666666:5+2/1+5@6/1+3@6666666:5+3/1+5@6/1+3@6666666:5+1@6:5/1+3@6666666:1/1+51@6:5/1+3@6666666:2/1+51@6:5/1+3@6666666/1+51@6:5/1+3@6666666/1+5@6:1/1+1@6:4/1+5@6/1+3@666666+2@6-2@666666:5+1/1+5@6/1+3@666666:5+2/1+5@6/1+3@666666:5+3/1+5@6/1+3@666666:5+1@6:5/1+3@666666:1/1+51@6:5/1+3@666666:2/1+51@6:5/1+3@666666/1+51@6:5/1+3@666666/1+5@6:1/1+1@6:4/1+5@6/1+3@66666+2@6-2@66666:5+1/1+5@6/1+3@66666:5+2/1+5@6/1+3@66666:5+3/1+5@6/1+3@66666:5+1@6:5/1+3@66666:1/1+51@6:5/1+3@66666:2/1+51@6:5/1+3@66666/1+51@6:5/1+3@66666/1+5@6:1/1+1@6:4/1+5@6/1+3@6666+2@6-2@6666:5+1/1+5@6/1+3@6666:5+2/1+5@6/1+3@6666:5+3/1+5@6/1+3@6666:5+1@6:5/1+3@6666:1/1+51@6:5/1+3@6666:2/1+51@6:5/1+3@6666/1+51@6:5/1+3@6666/1+5@6:1/1+1@6:4/1+5@6/1+3@666+2@6-2@666:5+1/1+5@6/1+3@666:5+2/1+5@6/1+3@666:5+3/1+5@6/1+3@666:5+1@6:5/1+3@666:1/1+51@6:5/1+3@666:2/1+51@6:5/1+3@666/1+51@6:5/1+3@666/1+5@6:1/1+1@6:4/1+5@6/1+3@66+2@6-2@66:5+1/1+5@6/1+3@66:5+2/1+5@6/1+3@66:5+3/1+5@6/1+3@66:5+1@6:5/1+3@66:1/1+51@6:5/1+3@66:2/1+51@6:5/1+3@66/1+51@6:5/1+3@66/1+5@6:1/1+1@6:4/1+5@6/1+3@6+2@6-2@6:5+1/1+5@6/1+3@6:5+2/1+5@6/1+3@6:5+3/1+5@6/1+3@6:5+1@6:5/1+3@6:1/1+51@6:5/1+3@6:2/1+51@6:5/1+3@6/1+51@6:5/1+3@6/1+5@6:1/1+1@6:4/1+5@6/1+5@6:5+1/1+5@6:5+2/1+5@6:5+3/1+5@6:5+1@6:1/1+51@6:2/1+51@6:3/1+51@6-1@6:1/1+1@6:4/1+5@6/1+3@6+2@6-2@6:5+1/1+5@6/1+3@6:5+2/1+5@6/1+3@6:5+3/1+5@6/1+3@6:5+1@6:5/1+3@6:1/1+51@6:5/1+3@6:2/1+51@6:5/1+3@6/1+51@6:5/1+3@6/1+5@6:1/1+1@6:4/1+5@6/1+3@66+2@6-2@66:5+1/1+5@6/1+3@66:5+2/1+5@6/1+3@66:5+3/1+5@6/1+3@66:5+1@6:5/1+3@66:1/1+51@6:5/1+3@66:2/1+51@6:5/1+3@66/1+51@6:5/1+3@66/1+5@6:1/1+1@6:4/1+5@6/1+3@666+2@6-2@666:5+1/1+5@6/1+3@666:5+2/1+5@6/1+3@666:5+3/1+5@6/1+3@666:5+1@6:5/1+3@666:1/1+51@6:5/1+3@666:2/1+51@6:5/1+3@666/1+51@6:5/1+3@666/1+5@6:1/1+1@6:4/1+5@6/1+3@6666+2@6-2@6666:5+1/1+5@6/1+3@6666:5+2/1+5@6/1+3@6666:5+3/1+5@6/1+3@6666:5+1@6:5/1+3@6666:1/1+51@6:5/1+3@6666:2/1+51@6:5/1+3@6666/1+51@6:5/1+3@6666/1+5@6:1/1+1@6:4/1+5@6/1+3@66666+2@6-2@66666:5+1/1+5@6/1+3@66666:5+2/1+5@6/1+3@66666:5+3/1+5@6/1+3@66666:5+1@6:5/1+3@66666:1/1+51@6:5/1+3@66666:2/1+51@6:5/1+3@66666/1+51@6:5/1+3@66666/1+5@6:1/1+1@6:4/1+5@6/1+3@666666+2@6-2@666666:5+1/1+5@6/1+3@666666:5+2/1+5@6/1+3@666666:5+3/1+5@6/1+3@666666:5+1@6:5/1+3@666666:1/1+51@6:5/1+3@666666:2/1+51@6:5/1+3@666666/1+51@6:5/1+3@666666/1+5@6:1/1+1@6:4/1+5@6/1+3@6666666+2@6-2@6666666:5+1/1+5@6/1+3@6666666:5+2/1+5@6/1+3@6666666:5+3/1+5@6/1+3@6666666:5+1@6:5/1+3@6666666:1/1+51@6:5/1+3@6666666:2/1+51@6:5/1+3@6666666/1+51@6:5/1+3@6666666/1+5@6:1/1+1@6:4/1+5@6/1+3@66666666+2@6-2@66666666:5+1/1+5@6/1+3@66666666:5+2/1+5@6/1+3@66666666:5+3/1+5@6/1+3@66666666:5+1@6:5/1+3@66666666:1/1+51@6:5/1+3@66666666:2/1+51@6:5/1+3@66666666/1+51@6:5/1+3@66666666/1+5@6
```

Uses the existing cube and division to get the required ASCII values.

Found using [these answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/133793/61563).

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 48 bytes

```zsh
for 1 ({9..1} {2..9})printf %-$1s {1..9} 0&&echo
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IwVBBo9pST8@wVqHaSE/PslazoCgzryRNQVVXxbBYodoQJKZgoKaWmpyR//8/AA)
<sub><s>[49b](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IwVBBo9pST8@wVqHaSE/PslazuqAoM68kTUFVV8WwWKHaECSoYGCdmpyRX/v/PwA)</s> <s>[61b](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIVNBo9pST8@wVqHaSE/PslazGiRaARQ1BHEVDDQLijLzStIUVHVVqjNrixVUKqxTkzPya///BwA)</s> <s>[57b](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IwVBBo9pST8@wtlih2khPz7K2WLMaJG4EFDcE8RUMNAuKMvNK0hRUdVUcrFOTM/Jr//8HAA)</s></sub>

Similar to [Spaceship Maw!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216255/15940). -4, -8 bytes thanks to @pxeger.

Comment: 57: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IwVBBo9pST8@wtlih2khPz7K2WLMaJG4EFDcE8RUMNAuKMvNK0hRUdVUcrFOTM/Jr//8HAA "Zsh – Try It Online")

Comment: 49: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IwVBBo9pST8@wVqHaSE/PslazuqAoM68kTUFVV8WwWKHaECSoYGCdmpyRX/v/PwA "Zsh – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Deadfish~, 2959 bytes

```
{iiiii}dc{dd}iiicccccccc{ii}ddc{dd}iicccccccc{ii}dc{dd}icccccccc{ii}c{dd}cccccccc{ii}ic{dd}dcccccccc{ii}iic{dd}ddcccccccc{ii}iiic{dd}dddcccccccc{ii}iiiic{dd}ddddcccccccc{ii}iiiiic{dd}dddddcccccccc{i}iiiiiic{dddd}iic{iiii}dc{dd}iiiccccccc{ii}ddc{dd}iiccccccc{ii}dc{dd}iccccccc{ii}c{dd}ccccccc{ii}ic{dd}dccccccc{ii}iic{dd}ddccccccc{ii}iiic{dd}dddccccccc{ii}iiiic{dd}ddddccccccc{ii}iiiiic{dd}dddddccccccc{i}iiiiiic{dddd}iic{iiii}dc{dd}iiicccccc{ii}ddc{dd}iicccccc{ii}dc{dd}icccccc{ii}c{dd}cccccc{ii}ic{dd}dcccccc{ii}iic{dd}ddcccccc{ii}iiic{dd}dddcccccc{ii}iiiic{dd}ddddcccccc{ii}iiiiic{dd}dddddcccccc{i}iiiiiic{dddd}iic{iiii}dc{dd}iiiccccc{ii}ddc{dd}iiccccc{ii}dc{dd}iccccc{ii}c{dd}ccccc{ii}ic{dd}dccccc{ii}iic{dd}ddccccc{ii}iiic{dd}dddccccc{ii}iiiic{dd}ddddccccc{ii}iiiiic{dd}dddddccccc{i}iiiiiic{dddd}iic{iiii}dc{dd}iiicccc{ii}ddc{dd}iicccc{ii}dc{dd}icccc{ii}c{dd}cccc{ii}ic{dd}dcccc{ii}iic{dd}ddcccc{ii}iiic{dd}dddcccc{ii}iiiic{dd}ddddcccc{ii}iiiiic{dd}dddddcccc{i}iiiiiic{dddd}iic{iiii}dc{dd}iiiccc{ii}ddc{dd}iiccc{ii}dc{dd}iccc{ii}c{dd}ccc{ii}ic{dd}dccc{ii}iic{dd}ddccc{ii}iiic{dd}dddccc{ii}iiiic{dd}ddddccc{ii}iiiiic{dd}dddddccc{i}iiiiiic{dddd}iic{iiii}dc{dd}iiicc{ii}ddc{dd}iicc{ii}dc{dd}icc{ii}c{dd}cc{ii}ic{dd}dcc{ii}iic{dd}ddcc{ii}iiic{dd}dddcc{ii}iiiic{dd}ddddcc{ii}iiiiic{dd}dddddcc{i}iiiiiic{dddd}iic{iiii}dc{dd}iiic{ii}ddc{dd}iic{ii}dc{dd}ic{ii}c{dd}c{ii}ic{dd}dc{ii}iic{dd}ddc{ii}iiic{dd}dddc{ii}iiiic{dd}ddddc{ii}iiiiic{dd}dddddc{i}iiiiiic{dddd}iic{iiii}dcicicicicicicicic{d}ic{dddd}iic{iiii}dc{dd}iiic{ii}ddc{dd}iic{ii}dc{dd}ic{ii}c{dd}c{ii}ic{dd}dc{ii}iic{dd}ddc{ii}iiic{dd}dddc{ii}iiiic{dd}ddddc{ii}iiiiic{dd}dddddc{i}iiiiiic{dddd}iic{iiii}dc{dd}iiicc{ii}ddc{dd}iicc{ii}dc{dd}icc{ii}c{dd}cc{ii}ic{dd}dcc{ii}iic{dd}ddcc{ii}iiic{dd}dddcc{ii}iiiic{dd}ddddcc{ii}iiiiic{dd}dddddcc{i}iiiiiic{dddd}iic{iiii}dc{dd}iiiccc{ii}ddc{dd}iiccc{ii}dc{dd}iccc{ii}c{dd}ccc{ii}ic{dd}dccc{ii}iic{dd}ddccc{ii}iiic{dd}dddccc{ii}iiiic{dd}ddddccc{ii}iiiiic{dd}dddddccc{i}iiiiiic{dddd}iic{iiii}dc{dd}iiicccc{ii}ddc{dd}iicccc{ii}dc{dd}icccc{ii}c{dd}cccc{ii}ic{dd}dcccc{ii}iic{dd}ddcccc{ii}iiic{dd}dddcccc{ii}iiiic{dd}ddddcccc{ii}iiiiic{dd}dddddcccc{i}iiiiiic{dddd}iic{iiii}dc{dd}iiiccccc{ii}ddc{dd}iiccccc{ii}dc{dd}iccccc{ii}c{dd}ccccc{ii}ic{dd}dccccc{ii}iic{dd}ddccccc{ii}iiic{dd}dddccccc{ii}iiiic{dd}ddddccccc{ii}iiiiic{dd}dddddccccc{i}iiiiiic{dddd}iic{iiii}dc{dd}iiicccccc{ii}ddc{dd}iicccccc{ii}dc{dd}icccccc{ii}c{dd}cccccc{ii}ic{dd}dcccccc{ii}iic{dd}ddcccccc{ii}iiic{dd}dddcccccc{ii}iiiic{dd}ddddcccccc{ii}iiiiic{dd}dddddcccccc{i}iiiiiic{dddd}iic{iiii}dc{dd}iiiccccccc{ii}ddc{dd}iiccccccc{ii}dc{dd}iccccccc{ii}c{dd}ccccccc{ii}ic{dd}dccccccc{ii}iic{dd}ddccccccc{ii}iiic{dd}dddccccccc{ii}iiiic{dd}ddddccccccc{ii}iiiiic{dd}dddddccccccc{i}iiiiiic{dddd}iic{iiii}dc{dd}iiicccccccc{ii}ddc{dd}iicccccccc{ii}dc{dd}icccccccc{ii}c{dd}cccccccc{ii}ic{dd}dcccccccc{ii}iic{dd}ddcccccccc{ii}iiic{dd}dddcccccccc{ii}iiiic{dd}ddddcccccccc{ii}iiiiic{dd}dddddcccccccc{i}iiiiiic{dddd}iic
```

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 74 bytes

```
=LET(x,MOD(COLUMN(A:J),10),CONCAT(x&IF(x,REPT(" ",ABS(ROW(1:17)-9)),"
")))
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnG55rU09NesO-uLY?e=3doX6i)

The version without LET that would have been valid when the question was asked is only 2 bytes longer.

### Without LET, 76 bytes

```
=CONCAT(RIGHT(COLUMN(A:J))&IF(COLUMN(A:J)>9,"
",REPT(" ",ABS(ROW(1:17)-9))))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 11 bytes

```
8ʀṘ∞ƛ9ʀǓ$Ij
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwiOMqA4bmY4oiexps5yoDHkyRJaiIsIiIsIiJd)

```
8ʀṘ∞ƛ9ʀǓ$Ij
8ʀ          # Range [0, 8]
  Ṙ         # Reverse
   ∞        # Palindromise, append reverse without first element.
            # Produces [8, 7, 6, ..., 1, 0, 1, 2, ..., 7, 8]
    ƛ       # For each:
     9ʀ     # Range [0, 9]
       Ǔ    # Rotate it left to make [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
        $   # Swap so the current element is at the top
         I  # Push that many spaces
          j # Join the number list by these spaces
            # j flag joins on newlines
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `N`, 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
9LrⱮıṣkDỤsj
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPTlMciVFMiVCMSVBRSVDNCVCMSVFMSVCOSVBM2tEJUUxJUJCJUE0c2omZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0mZmxhZ3M9Tg==)

##### Explanation

```python
9LrⱮıṣkDỤsj  # Implicit input
9L           # Push [0..9)
  r          # Reverse it
   Ɱ         # And palindromise that
    ı        # Map over this list:
     ṣ       #  Push that many spaces
      kDỤ    #  Push "1234567890"
         sj  #  Join it by the spaces
             # Join on newlines
             # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 5.9, 106 bytes

```swift
for i in(1..<9)+(1...9).reversed(){(1...10).map{print($0%10,terminator:{String.init}()(" ",9-i))};print()}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Cheddar](http://cheddar.vihan.org/), 42 bytes

```
-8|>8=>n->print(1|>9+[0]).join(abs(n)*' ')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ITUlJLPr/X9eixs7C1i5P166gKDOvRMOwxs5SO9ogVlMvKz8zTyMxqVgjT1NLXUFd8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 33 bytes

```
9:>' '*[9~>\#`]"!:8~>#rev\,$out"!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTfn/39LKTl1BXSvass4uRjkhVknRyqLOTrkotSxGRyW/tERJ8f9/AA)

### Explanation

```
9:>' '*[9~>\#`]"!:8~>#rev\,$out"!
9:>                                 range from 0 to 9 (right-exclusive)
   ' '*                             vectorized repetition of the space
       [      ]"!                   on each repetition:
        9~>                           generate a range from 1 to 9
           \#`                        and join it by that repetition
                 :8~>#              copy all but the first element
                      rev           reverse it
                         \,         swap then concatenate
                           $out"!   output each
```

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 251 bytes

```
/B/' //A/!!//@/" //?/\/\///>/  ?=/0
1?</ 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ?;/!2!3!4!5!6!7!8!9!?:/'2'3'4'5'6'7'8'9'?-/="2"3"4"5"6"7"8"9"=?,/@2@3@4@5@6@7@8@9@?'/!"?&/=>2>3>4>5>6>7>8>9>=?%/=A2A3A4A5A6A7A8A9A=?#/1B2B3B4B5B6B7B8B9B0?"/! ?!/> /#
1:%,-;&<=23456789=<&;-,%:0
#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcY9boQwEAbQnlPMGC1uQB/rfwP22D5HmhSRUqTj/iKr17z77/v@/bmfBwOagA5moEF9Lvj6ACqIpGCf3nKBDFly5ClQpESZ5AQbtuzYc@DIiTPLAW201U57HXTUSWctG4oyyiqnvAoqqqSyKrKimWaba76FFltquYkGK1lQqqm2uuprqLGmmmuRF0o33XbXfQ899tRzLzLjPcywww0/wogjjTx2UWASRiXM0/t4rdu5XMVY50NMuVzLua2vY5/m5/kH) Or [here, interactively!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/slashes.html?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)

Considerably long, but /// has no real way of modifying data elegantly.

Answer (score 1):

## Delphi / Pascal  137 Bytes*

```
program x;{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}var i,j: Integer;begin for i:=-8 to 8do begin write(#10,1); for j:=2 to 10do Write(j mod 10:Abs(i)+1);end;end.
```

*The `{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}` is a compiler directive that can be removed for pure Pascal. or if compiled with the Delphi command line compiler using the -cc switch to give **119 bytes**. Without it you get a runtime error as it tries to print to a non existent console.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java 7],  <s>137</s> 132 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanx to Kevin Cruijssen and 2 more thanx to  TheLethalCoder

```java
void a(){int i,j,k;for(i=-8;i<9;i++){String a="";for(j=1;j<11;j++){a+=j%10;for(k=0;k<(i<0?-i:i);k++)a+=" ";}System.out.println(a);}}
```

```java
 void a(){for(int i=-8;i<9;i++){String a="";for(int j=1;j<11;j++){a+=j%10;for(int k=0;k<Math.abs(i);k++){a+=" ";}}System.out.println(a);}}
```

Ungolfed:

```java
  void a(){
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=-8;i<9;i++){
        String a="";
        for(j=1;j<11;j++){
            a+=j%10;
            for(k=0;k<(i<0?-i:i);k++)a+=" ";
        }
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare `i`, `j`, and `k` in one place to save bytes (I'm sure you go do this in Java). Use Java 8 and compile to an anonymous method. I think `int i=-9;++i<9;i` should work and similar for `j` and `k`. I'm not sure if `Math` needs qualifying but I don't know Java well enough to say for sure. I think you can remove the braces from the `k` loop as well.

Comment: Also it might be cheaper, especially when compiling to a lambda, to return the results as a string.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! There is already a shorter Java answer posted, but that doesn't matter because it uses a different approach. But, you can still shorten your code a bit like this: `void a(){for(int i=-8,j,k;i<9;i++){String a="";for(j=1;j<11;)for(a+=j++%10,k=0;k++<(i<0?-i:i);)a+=" ";System.out.println(a);}}`. (I've put some things inside the for-loop to get rid of the brackets; I've removed the two `int` by adding `,j,k` in the first loop; and I've changed `Math.abs(i)` to `(i<0?-i:i)`. It might also be useful to read [Tips for golfing in Java](https://tinyurl.com/yb2z65sp). :) Enjoy your stay.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 131 bytes

My first participation

```
for(int i=8;i>-9;i--){for(int n=1;n<=10;n++){Console.Write((n==10?"0":n.ToString())+new String(' ',Math.Abs(i))+(n==10?"\n":""));}}
```

More easy reading version

```
for (int i = 8; i > -9; i--)
{
    for (int n = 1; n <= 10; n++)
    {
        Console.Write((n==10 ? "0" : n.ToString()) + new String(' ', Math.Abs(i)) + (n == 10 ? "\n" : ""));
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG.SE! A nice first post though by default, you should supply a full program or function, not just a snippet like you have here. See [this meta post for more](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422). I would also recommend you have a look at [Try it Online](https://tio.run/nexus) which lets you run your code online and share it with others. It can also format your answers for you to post here.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! In addition to what @Notts90 said, I can also recommend reading [Tips for golfing in C#](https://tinyurl.com/y8fnu9y9) and [Tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://tinyurl.com/y8kzo4vm). Some things you can golf is removing the brackets and int; change the condition to remove the `=`; and change the `Math.abs`, like this: `o=>{for(int i=8,n;i>-9;i--)for(n=1;n<11;n++)Console.Write((n>9?0:n)+new String(' ',i<0?-i:i)+(n>9?"\n":""));}` (where `o=>` is an unused parameter). [Try it here.](https://tinyurl.com/yace47e2) Again welcome, and enjoy your stay. :)

Comment: Oh, and one more thing after my previous golfed version: `o=>{for(int i=8,n;i>-9;i--)for(n=1;n<11;)Console.Write((n>9?0:n)+new String(' ',i<0?-i:i)+(n++>9?"\n":""));}` (the `n++` is removed and `++` is added to the last `n`. [Try it here.](https://tinyurl.com/y7ud7prz) So **108 bytes** in total.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Notts90 and Kevin, I will look at your code this evening :)

Answer (score 1):

## tcl, 112

Very naïve:

```
proc x n\ s {time {puts [join {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0} [format %[incr n $s]s \ ]]} 9}
x 10 -1
puts 1234567890
x 0 1
```

## [demo](http://rextester.com/TKMM49184)

Comment: Different approach with same size http://rextester.com/RGO50353

Answer (score 1):

## /// (Slashes), <s>377</s> 374 bytes

```
/a/1_//b/2_//c/3_//d/4_//e/5_//f/6_//g/7_//h/8_//i/9_//z/0
//./  //-/. //_/../a_b_c_d_e_f_g_h_i_za-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-za.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i.za b c d e f g h i zabcdefghiz1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-z1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.z1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 z123456789z1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 z1.2.3.4.5.6.7.h.9.z1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-zabcdefghiza b c d e f g h i za.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i.za-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-za_b_c_d_e_f_g_h_i_0
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##bdA7bsQwDATQPqfgBTiz/tunIfSXgHTb6fKOkCYI1s1rCAyHfH@7d03v@6bjZKTnPAxchpHrMHEbZu7DwmNYeQ4br2Hn64sERUglhkaAzrwFi5YsW7FqzbpTr0GjJs1atGrT7uAREJGQUVDR0J14CRIlSZYiVZp050NMudTWJ5110VU33fXQUy/tE2YsWLFhx4ETF/oksyyyyia7HHLKJX2al3Xbj/N6HP6LqL8Rn4v@WjxVfDjk4dyPp7zu@wc)

### Explanation

The original output was initially compressed by doing the following replacements:

- *(4 spaces)* → `_`
- *(3 spaces)* → `-`
- *(2 spaces)* → `.`

In a second step, `1_` was replaced by `a`, `2_` by `b` and so on. Finally, those mappings were inverted and prepended to the code.

Additional step (thx to [CalculatorFeline](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51443/calculatorfeline)):

`/./  //-/   //_/    /` → `/_/..//-/. //./  /`

Comment: `/./  //-/   //_/    /` can be `/_/..//-/. //./  /`. Imagine the spaces being correct because Markdown doesn't like multiple spaces in inline code blocks >:(

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Thanks, missed that one. Btw, you can fake the spaces with "figure space" (U+2007), markdown doesn't seem to collapse those (it's what I did in the post as well).

Answer (score 1):

## [Sink](https://github.com/voidqk/sink/), <s>102</s> 100 bytes

```
var v=range 0,17
var p=list.push(range 0,10),0
for var s:v
say list.join p,str.pad"",num.abs s-8
end
```

[Try it online! (sort of, it's just a repl so you'll need to type it in)](https://rawgit.com/voidqk/sink/master/src/repl.html)

-2 bytes thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first answer, +1 from me. I've never even heard of Sink before, so it's always great to see a new programming language. Btw, I tried some things in the REPL, and if I'm not mistaken you can golf two spaces on this line: `say list.join p,str.pad"",num.abs s-8`. Again welcome, and enjoy your stay. :)

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, <strike>106</strike> 85 bytes

-21 bytes thanks to user202729

```
n="1L2L3L4L5L6L7L8L9L0"for i=-8,8,1 do print((n:gsub("L",(" "):rep(math.abs(i)))))end
```

Output has a trailing newline

Ungolfed

```
n="1L2L3L4L5L6L7L8L9L0"
for i=-8,8,1 do 
    print((n:gsub("L",(" "):rep(math.abs(i)))))
end
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##FcFbCoAgEAXQrch8TWDROwvawd2E0UsoDdP1G51zRZ2SnalCjQYtOvQYoDCipN15YeZcSSUrsTrxeGMDs52ONy5MIMkkKJv89vCtw1no5WWT/Ta7pvQB)

Comment: Hi there. Would you mind adding a [TIO-link](https://tio.run/#) with test code? Lua should be available on TIO as well.

Comment: You can save 5 bytes by using `(" "):rep`.

Comment: You can also get it down to 82 bytes with pattern. Hint: `%1`.

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 209 bytes

```
++++++++[->+>+>+>++++>++++++>+>>+<<<<<<<<]>++>+>+>>>>>+<<<<<<-[->>>>>>[-<<<+.>[-<<.>>>+<]>[-<+>]>>+<]>[-<+<<<->>>>]<<<-<.<<<<.>]>[->>>>>[-<<<+.>>>>>[->+<<<<<<<.>>>>>>]>[-<+>]<<+<]>[-<+<<<->>>>]>+<<<<<.<<<<.>>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU1BCoBACHyQrC9Y5iOLhwqCCDoE@37T1YoaD47jOM7ntB1rX3ZVSrQCijIgNJtANSGgMDhSLXY10IpNxKPz2Itzgrzc/e4VJ5X9nuGrT0Lw520IuNPM8k9La@ZBVC8)

I noticed there wasn’t a brainfuck submission yet, so I gave it my best shot. Definitely not the most golfed solution possible, but I’m not upset with the result.

Answer (score 1):

### [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>20</s> 15 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
９｛９∔ ×９Ｒ0∔∑；＊］─
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjE5JXVGRjVCJXVGRjE5JXUyMjE0JTIwJUQ3JXVGRjE5JXVGRjMyMCV1MjIxNCV1MjIxMSV1RkYxQiV1RkYwQSV1RkYzRCV1MjUwMA__)

Explanation:

```
９｛９∔ ×９Ｒ0∔∑；＊］─  | (Full code)
                        | Print (implicit)
    ９∔ ×               | 9-i spaces
         ９Ｒ0∔∑；＊    | Inserted between the characters of the string "1234567890"
９｛                    | For each i in [1-9]
                   ］   | Separated by newlines
                     ─  | Palindromized vertically with 1 line of overlap
```

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, 58 bytes

An immediate window function that takes no input and outputs to the console.

```vb
For i=-8To 8:For j=1To 9:?j &""Spc(Abs(i));:Next:?"0":Next
```

#### Ungolfed and Commented

```vb
For i=-8To 8        ''  Iterate `i` from `-8` to `8`
For j=1To 9         ''  Iterate `j` from `1` to `9`
?j &""Spc(Abs(i));  ''  Print `j` and `i` spaces
Next                ''  Loop `j`
?"0"                ''  Print `0`, with a newline
Next                ''  Loop `i`
```

Answer (score 1):

## [QBasic](https://archive.org/details/msdos_qbasic_megapack), 66 bytes

An undeclared subroutine that takes no input and outputs to STDOUT

```vb
FOR i=-8TO 8
FOR j=49TO 57
?CHR$(j)SPC(ABS(i));
NEXT
?"0
NEXT
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 71 bytes

```
f=(i=8,q=[..."1234567890"].join(" ".repeat(i)))=>i?q+`
`+f(i-1)+`
`+q:q
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 126 bytes

```
Enum.each 8..-8,fn n->IO.puts Enum.map Enum.into(1..10,[],&(rem &1,10)),&(Integer.to_string(&1)<>String.duplicate" ",abs n)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcmxCsIwEIDhVzk6hATSo9k6SDeHTg6OIhLbswbaa0gu4NtHqdv389MaPiHVeuayIfnpDT1i29sXA7fDeMFYJMNxNx//CCy7doius7e7VTrRBspZ1xnzq5GFFkoo@yNLCrxo5cxpuB7GucQ1TF6ogcb6ZwY2xHOtXw)

```
Enum.each 8..-8,
          fn n->
            IO.puts 
              Enum.map 
                Enum.into(1..10, [], &(rem &1,10)),
                &(Integer.to_string(&1) <> String.duplicate" ",abs n)
          end
```

For each number in the range 8 to -8, do this anonymous function with the number as `n`. The function (inner to outer) sets the range 1 to 10 into a list after applying the remainder mod 10 (so we have the list 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0). Then maps that list of numbers into strings, and concatenates the absolute value of `n` spaces onto the end. After getting each string we print out the whole list of strings... and Elixir doesn't put any delimiter on that by default.

Output:

```
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0        
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0       
1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0      
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0     
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0    
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 
1234567890
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0    
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0     
1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0      
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0       
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-l`, <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
(\,t)%tJsXPZRV,9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fI0anRFO1xKs4IiAqKEzH8v///7o5AA)

#### Explanation

```
                  t is 10, s is " " (implicit)
              ,9  Range(9): [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
            RV    Reverse: [8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0]
          PZ      Palindromize: [8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
        sX        For each element of the above list, a string of that many spaces
 \,t              Inclusive-range(10): [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
(   )%t           Mod 10: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0]
       J          For each string of spaces, join the above list on that string
                  Output the list of results one per line (`-l` flag)
```

---

The `PZ` operator was added more than a year after this challenge was posted, so here's a 17-byte answer that would have worked at that time:

```
(\,t)%tJsXAB:-8,9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fI0anRFO1xKs4wtHJStdCx/L///@6OQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Sisi](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Sisi), 239 bytes

```
0set s8
1set d0-1
2set o""
3set i1
4set o o+i
5jumpif i7
6jump17
7set x s
8jump11
9set o o+" "
10set x x-1
11jumpif x9
12set c9>i
13jumpif c15
14set i0-1
15set i1+i
16jump4
17print o
18set s s+d
19jumpif s21
20set d1
21set q9>s
22jumpif q2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY/BDoMgEETv8xWEq2nioBa5@DPaJtukVUub@PcUVnpiMrvMm40SJaU23j4mjmB5l/ZCuKJWa9EVIUSvhlkbwfD4Pje5G/G4FkkPX6aHiRjVIMJ/3RoLtuf4yMFk/X0EUClzmATsqj1zABUmpQeHk5@xVFgP@u0tr5wOjtrbxGYBQw2ILrdX4JKFXrSHKcK5urC7lH4)

The basic strategy is to run a loop from 8 down to 0 and back up to 8, constructing each line accordingly and printing it. I'm not going to write a detailed explanation, but if you're trying to follow the algorithm, the following key to the variable names may be helpful:

- `s`: number of spaces to print between digits
- `d`: direction of change in `s` (-1 or 1)
- `o`: the current line of output
- `i`: the current digit
- `x`: loop counter while printing spaces
- `c`: conditional that tests whether `i` is less than 9 (if not, we set it to -1 so it gets incremented to 0 instead of 10)
- `q`: conditional that tests whether `s` is less than 9 (if so, we continue looping)

Comment: Hmm, never seen or heard about the programming language SIsi. Weird how those leading line numbering are mandatory. Nice answer though!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Not surprised that you haven't heard of it--[it's a toy language I wrote for an old popularity contest here.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/22813/16766) :)

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 244 bytes

```
/*/\/\///X/0
1*j/\/X*x/  *S/x *s/SS*-/S *_/s *(/- *)/_ *A/)2)3)4)5)6)7)8)9)*Bj_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_*Cjs2s3s4s5s6s7s8s9s*Dj(2(3(4(5(6(7(8(9(*Ej-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-*FjS2S3S4S5S6S7S8S9S*Gjx2x3x4x5x6x7x8x9x*Hj 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 /1ABCDEFGHX23456789HGFEDCBXA0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dca5igMxDADQfr9CpS0QSny7nHt6NVMETIqFYLZT47@fDa95@vfWz6/eNyO/vpgvfvw8sX9/4WAAFB6AyiJILICNFdAwAVpugBNbZ70NNtpksy22Wpx7c8230GJLLbfSasOlq1OvQaMmzVq0Kq7dOONNMNEkk00x1eDWyZGnQJESZSpUCfcuTrwEiZIkS5EqePThhh9hxJFGHmXUgWcHBx4CREiQoUAFfk7zsm77cV7Oh5hyqeexb@syX9Pjvv8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 27 bytes

Not the most elegant solution, but it does the job.

```
N9X@wL:Ocv:32;ZT:hT%#^"v;T'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/9/PMsKh3MfKP7nMytjIOirEKiNEVTlOqcw6RP3/fwA)

Explanation:

```
N                                \ Set printing delimiter to empty string
 9X                              \ Push range(9) to stack: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
   @                             \ Reverse: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
    w                            \ Mirror: [8, 7, 6... 1, 0, 1... 6, 7, 8]
     L:                          \ Length (17) times do:
       Oc                        \   Go to (cleared) auxiliary stack
         v:                      \   Pop top of main stack, and that many times:
           32;                           Push character 32 (space)
              Z                  \   Push 0
               T                 \   Ten times do:
                :hT%             \      counter = (counter + 1) mod 10
                    #            \      Print the counter
                     ^"v;        \      Print the rest of the stack (spaces)
                         T'      \   Print a newline
```

Comment: Would you mind adding an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 99 bytes

```
time {incr i;time {puts -nonewline [incr j][string repe " " [expr abs(9-$i)]]} 9;puts 0;unset j} 17
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYvBCkBAFEV/5SYLFoqVNJ8yzQK99MQzzTxR8u1DdFan09FxSUl5JVwsYwCbX/yuEZVsQsfCQrBfnZ2NGlgmBPKE7MXS6QP6IRZdlXPp3I3OfHdtdomkmG80bUoP)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>127</s> <s>126</s> 124 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Kevin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/)

```
F takes X
cut 1234567890 into L
join L with " "*X
say L

X's9
while X
let X be-1
F taking X

while X-8
let X be+1
F taking X
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Comment: Based on [your other Rockstar answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210927/52210) the space can be removed at `be-1`, right?

Comment: Thanks, @KevinCruijssen. Dunno how that snuck in there; omitting that space is one of my favourite wee byte-saving tricks in Rockstar.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü¡↑├☼Rσ┬q▄└m
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=81ad18c30f52e5c271dcc06d&i=)

can probably tie mathgolf. Port of Emigna's answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [BRASCA](https://github.com/SjoerdPennings/BRASCA), 72 bytes

```
8[a09Ir,m[oA:a[Eo{]x]xloA{]x09Ir,m[o]lo8[9$-a09Ir,m[oA:a[Eo{]x]xloA}9$-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVt7c9s2Ev9fnwK121qqJVvOo3F8lnt2kl7dNnHGdud6o1FZSIQspiTBkGBkT5p@9dwu@BBBQiIYPzPT2iaB3d8@sQCWwZWYcf/xbhB@dryAh4JEV1GXeFTMWtOQe0Q4HiPZK5exIHkcUt@GH@kL/Av@u2Ct9IEI6YSN6eSvVmvi0igiRyGNJvQF/r7XIvBvbW3tTMCALgnZhRMJFkYEqJAPNHTo2GURDJADbTYlluX4jrCsdsTcaWevJV/gv3VJQ07MyeQvcfBWJAcMyHCkPqfwrK8@GiuPFjwOQ0bmDBhQ2/EvCPvAQtAa/kojMplRkBX5/lBmHMIQy@M2A7o/UjdiBdxvnYDZPccnNhU0f@xMic@lCWA6MNtyIirEVbuzlw8p0IcBFk4H8osZiLLdGe7t9XZGyqQpD4nVJRYBpsyPPRZSwdolUiVGGmZoryh2BTJV3wyRZbfytIxDtcwWDQLm220e2u2EcKeTD2egszrJwUsWWv2JohOlxhkz5pMAjCCYTa6YKNmHuqiqKysbUbXR@cyJyNxxXRIJDj5A4TcxY2QMBv@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@oD0q4VEZVRvQHaUUdJHqjgHy6mVZC0DywRBdxuuJauuMi@dqCefuWGmmE4VbJHBqBED8I4QiyjJSM0My6qJoZwzgkkZovop2UicJaevlmFjrVbT52HM6m07II9Wc/qzsTmKwyogTOnjxHryqTe1cA9ydgUZyyM0vIBI8AVsXwK5Z8IyELY0W8EVmZL9Kajcpx47qL6dkH0Mm4NW65xDPOHmBkJ7HF90SQx5a2pvTzDUgAu1Md9MtydbODRy@ZzYfO4THosgFunwaHsSSWAO7ouQp2VJiS3Lo1AXW6kJEwBgiMLWK3WyFFteSa593h3S/vPjsOsN@eEeHb7iH0eXo0uXH8LP7MXI5bvD51/3loz8BK9Gn9OtXZL0yBFmrySdYrLzaFDkX8xtWZ4kr0EGOVr@nWTKAt68Lt6XibbwppgZwyvVxrljFEkNNWRH5QySjlE2c0u9tPJgnchVeh@S6IFa7a5IVH1NDBa0VqzE@9WkUQmEHXNyOwbkHpmTe2RA7rE5uccG5J6Yk3tiQO6pObmnBuS@Nyf3vQG5Z@bknhmQ2zUnt2tA7rk5uecG5NwGbmwSFr82oGfieaxBXJgY91WDwDAJNLtBZJiY92UDXzaJjVkDdzHx5p@a@IuJw/zSiKAJxY9re2T9JZuEDAsLU@LZIywZeyYZ@xOyOfavwWbThE2IbORydypPgnV86GIF1pe8EozJINywOLhBkcfO7XGXUECpt9ASCZ1Oq7pgSwGS1R4KrRkNawXf@HNjpWOo58Da6tmoDC9LIY/JasqZzZ1RZxUhpaLaxO1YVSOvKW6DA9wE8sLh@lLsm@gHh7Z9yw6gc9lNauCnPcR3Fo/xikLcA8ieCcjvEOTr2BVO4F7dA8jvTEBuJ4lFsAvwHtv54ES6Lentg93eNkH7jVQpt2OX3wPGb0wg/oEQX10G3F@WqG/Z6kZmj2QAvQ@vg7DKHG8ct6aw8Ut/jYBBm3Y6uiR95Ii5A3vhBlnpHwT95uT8RjH/Y6Kub2U@fPPyHuz5rQm@vxHfyek9wPvbBJ6F8H6/F3x/AD6N951pN/EV4BSBB/KQni8Ovg9XlgrFSwcgYKCesZbLkTmXsQmXQ8klu88xE0a9cDCT5kjP56gBHyN5usgnPfxfciijcMhuCWoJ7yFhO8Z7VnnYD6Lw6QoOX5p56HVGVlD/S0W9uKszBZ5d35miysbTG5hQkcZDaTz@QVU/xkdCRMsyuTn7ImNk2CQJA3yvc3wlRcuLu/Tgsx5fU50b4wtq9Ed82RQU6f3C47EvTHdw/mIH1@8mU1fs4YxtdDN2eltjpwekh9W@cE1/@EEmy6TfK@2s6Pd2Hj0z9bu8OawN@8zyuULHAMBX@Rq3uJStTdqas4z02taE5dfIMprTQBpazDlxBPMiwv1rJ/Nbz/hjA/lOpU25yBYpMQsZu1sZJ7euiMl1VKa9z6no8Qz1OOE@rpt@rkxwl4RwdPd@gjEWCRRpE39Qowi7KIux3AHSrgNks7Gx9Y47vmTndxaJLD/4wv6H5UlvgmkOkkkh9RWu9NLZ9Sd6TZSD4A3U4aTqgLJPECDiOJjy09zX7unOxxWhummKVvonFLmWiwVQkskHA/JkN22Jxb/3B@Tps@XzlBNHYDGUSPDaX04H0PVyHxflXjTRJRpob96Z3H1V7OdfLDVAbtWLfSnLXweIhHZ9yb7S7yq0fy/SNimsTRb1CpcYufzm9860JH3TMkR2/CTR3OwkHZKBbZJnfktxXizFWcwpl0lOuazklFadG6htUTctpuZM4Hj7xMDRuDxqkc0c2Dp@ePbi@DhtkazzukUrQqVveWk7QkmUasOz9jIC/8kh7clMvQbqdCGs7cHGhoGlT5aKahIE9y9tHnxNhPZVodMM@nANXDRuAzHfLBfzoRpXY9iFwJp4fsF9EXKX/Ojyeb1C9lEhv7Iogjqa3vYNCKpvnzZKXDt6SsxE1U3bjQ5QF/8B88j@97tRx8HDVcdAXum8j8Gt70ARg8GD1cTG/zZAE0dMzBnzH8LWEvWF1eUE//dwHejf6EDnLPQc3Ji1biYp4udi7NIRJrXlOgKAfGjLPmLqknexF9Qkdql11Gu/Vh/VFoRaRO8Q0c@AAqu5ORTWUZMeB7V/pp7bzzk3/J6xGbueym7TgN0Q2f0X2157sme22rRdVXdS836FRe/KDZayU@rtjGostEyqXKhio3ltM61W2lFJWliSb0vWg1sV1cSTXqzu6il9wGfWKXRuSDP55E/SbKk7l@QDFylFEDJ5IBPl37ri95RpO1S13V7fG63vsF8/x29jHAGl4ZTMZ8yHLT4HxqGMKuGATYHtFHbvdk1/dLN@K/UbmBzNCbKWPQTyXNkRLfNkXmnCSsGVOhXWX8srlOyLz/KXnkYpkF1OWCDIL@xqzCHxYK9NGMaBKH04Vc3m6cRX8gekbTRkSZz1M@6x5EvZOfMFmYfcv@jiSTCfg3EIcOIq3KSUXnt1enpyukd000t3r8mE/FvwLUjXHhUWgCsfwhdESL4DOE4dN/32odV047AYq4QA@Jhmh7HynvcaR5V0sLIK0WDE0NdjrG5Wad2ebQlxfYAuaNMqWS25VJ9VcivEbixyvbjNRV0qJv77/H8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 2606 bytes

```
ioi{iii}cccccccc{ddd}o{iii}ccccccccd{ii}ci{dd}cccccccc{ii}c{dd}cccccccci{ii}cd{dd}ccccccccii{ii}cdd{dd}ccccccccd{{{i}}}odsddddcccccccc{{{i}}}oddsddddcccccccci{ddd}soiii{ii}cccccccc{{d}}o{i}ci{d}oi{iii}ccccccc{ddd}o{iii}cccccccd{ii}ci{dd}ccccccc{ii}c{dd}ccccccci{ii}cd{dd}cccccccii{ii}cdd{dd}cccccccd{{{i}}}odsddddccccccc{{{i}}}oddsddddccccccci{ddd}soiii{ii}ccccccc{{d}}o{i}ci{d}oi{iii}cccccc{ddd}o{iii}ccccccd{ii}ci{dd}cccccc{ii}c{dd}cccccci{ii}cd{dd}ccccccii{ii}cdd{dd}ccccccd{{{i}}}odsddddcccccc{{{i}}}oddsddddcccccci{ddd}soiii{ii}cccccc{{d}}o{i}ci{d}oi{iii}ccccc{ddd}o{iii}cccccd{ii}ci{dd}ccccc{ii}c{dd}ccccci{ii}cd{dd}cccccii{ii}cdd{dd}cccccd{{{i}}}odsddddccccc{{{i}}}oddsddddccccci{ddd}soiii{ii}ccccc{{d}}o{i}ci{d}oi{iii}cccc{ddd}o{iii}ccccd{ii}ci{dd}cccc{ii}c{dd}cccci{ii}cd{dd}ccccii{ii}cdd{dd}ccccd{{{i}}}odsddddcccc{{{i}}}oddsddddcccci{ddd}soiii{ii}cccc{{d}}o{i}ci{d}oi{iii}ccc{ddd}o{iii}cccd{ii}ci{dd}ccc{ii}c{dd}ccci{ii}cd{dd}cccii{ii}cdd{dd}cccd{{{i}}}odsddddccc{{{i}}}oddsddddccci{ddd}soiii{ii}ccc{{d}}o{i}ci{d}oi{iii}cc{ddd}o{iii}ccd{ii}ci{dd}cc{ii}c{dd}cci{ii}cd{dd}ccii{ii}cdd{dd}ccd{{{i}}}odsddddcc{{{i}}}oddsddddcci{ddd}soiii{ii}cc{{d}}o{i}ci{d}oi{iii}c{ddd}o{iii}cd{ii}ci{dd}c{ii}c{dd}ci{ii}cd{dd}cii{ii}cdd{dd}cd{{{i}}}odsddddc{{{i}}}oddsddddci{ddd}soiii{ii}c{{d}}o{i}ciio{d}ioioioioioioioi{d}o{i}ci{d}oi{iii}c{ddd}o{iii}cd{ii}ci{dd}c{ii}c{dd}ci{ii}cd{dd}cii{ii}cdd{dd}cd{{{i}}}odsddddc{{{i}}}oddsddddci{ddd}soiii{ii}c{{d}}o{i}ci{d}oi{iii}cc{ddd}o{iii}ccd{ii}ci{dd}cc{ii}c{dd}cci{ii}cd{dd}ccii{ii}cdd{dd}ccd{{{i}}}odsddddcc{{{i}}}oddsddddcci{ddd}soiii{ii}cc{{d}}o{i}ci{d}oi{iii}ccc{ddd}o{iii}cccd{ii}ci{dd}ccc{ii}c{dd}ccci{ii}cd{dd}cccii{ii}cdd{dd}cccd{{{i}}}odsddddccc{{{i}}}oddsddddccci{ddd}soiii{ii}ccc{{d}}o{i}ci{d}oi{iii}cccc{ddd}o{iii}ccccd{ii}ci{dd}cccc{ii}c{dd}cccci{ii}cd{dd}ccccii{ii}cdd{dd}ccccd{{{i}}}odsddddcccc{{{i}}}oddsddddcccci{ddd}soiii{ii}cccc{{d}}o{i}ci{d}oi{iii}ccccc{ddd}o{iii}cccccd{ii}ci{dd}ccccc{ii}c{dd}ccccci{ii}cd{dd}cccccii{ii}cdd{dd}cccccd{{{i}}}odsddddccccc{{{i}}}oddsddddccccci{ddd}soiii{ii}ccccc{{d}}o{i}ci{d}oi{iii}cccccc{ddd}o{iii}ccccccd{ii}ci{dd}cccccc{ii}c{dd}cccccci{ii}cd{dd}ccccccii{ii}cdd{dd}ccccccd{{{i}}}odsddddcccccc{{{i}}}oddsddddcccccci{ddd}soiii{ii}cccccc{{d}}o{i}ci{d}oi{iii}ccccccc{ddd}o{iii}cccccccd{ii}ci{dd}ccccccc{ii}c{dd}ccccccci{ii}cd{dd}cccccccii{ii}cdd{dd}cccccccd{{{i}}}odsddddccccccc{{{i}}}oddsddddccccccci{ddd}soiii{ii}ccccccc{{d}}o{i}ci{d}oi{iii}cccccccc{ddd}o{iii}ccccccccd{ii}ci{dd}cccccccc{ii}c{dd}cccccccci{ii}cd{dd}ccccccccii{ii}cdd{dd}ccccccccd{{{i}}}odsddddcccccccc{{{i}}}oddsddddcccccccci{ddd}soiii{ii}cccccccc{{d}}o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1ZhLb@M2EIDv@hWs9yJt5Njeoj0YsIGiwaJ72CZoF9iDERiKSMfESqJAUmsZgvevp0PqxYfSprdEAQxqOEN@8@BISnmWR1b8/PQOpaykBKMDZzk6SlmK9WLxSOWxerhOWb74ws@f5G2R0YIsMEnwgYrjfPGQsYdFnghJ@CC9Ls9BQPOScYnEWQTB77efP//2583faIOaAME1o7M1ypL8ASeojtF5jcL6agWDKG7nsT8/N@eFP/@@NuaZN19yWsh9kqZVHoIoPSZ88zHJBIkMs/RFZl94ZVmdXKvW6MR4hkOTKvQUEy7IHn5JIbRmjDLGyh6stWpeatVytUZH1wgScU1qKsMouATB3e0dJKNXUOHbLe9jVO9W6/soCDA5oAMt8D5PZHqkxWO7W0iLvZA8RqwkMDrnEJCMAQsMo3W7sb70MGVVIWGXlb47MI5oG0BEC0SKKic8kaRbszNXFz20WpvNsM84OS581a@sLpIZVgPTlNncNFNGLeUGLW1tTmTFC0QD42a@CtrYOBmw0zYE4tMBnYiOIyJwjghHIYIoNAjGBcIMsYIgdlC3EJ4sYyeI9EDxHn0E5TBGpCZpJYlWExJClhMghhgqQcugHIG70QFdsFWWSBV1gbZoaS/bvGzZ1RJJmhMxpFRHVk9CYmeXmdpYuQ4JEATNolZNp23Qalyt0FtsDzGqQXeq5s6xsV5sWkGhdkkMa@UiSiDSBZN6r0jfeXtszTyrLfumFZ53a1cbToQO5KYet9J@/PfSutxVNHlSPJJwtYzs8vrfW3clqA7zzlW@glPbVSYnggz9aizFv5TYqgrJIGDgD5WqQLr6nK9UgX745dc@4d2uYah1VZNQPoWqF4NW1CZUiSPdPFTvaA@I0wEhh5XcqB4kJIbhSPaVUyjCPwiUf4y@KoOfFJuuSpKRVMIjCQzKSkK8vtOU9GggvD4p43BmWc/iyEKH42lTTTwDnse7UyZu4ETKCSmuEbohh6TKpFDCMksgNKBNHgmPA7OTQYBVb27PveRnpZ6y4juBByQME1QVNGWYaO0EXOa@k2F65JDRYU0deWicIItsj@vO26G80hz31bQcPeunf/R7wcrq8ID2ul9KG7WHNVYTULTw5FALRoODqiD6B/xY49qytzGLslfdpffhqBTZVT6Frn8jx7d9mtHQc@2GCsjGGW23kHKWlzLWJ1Z3bXQ6Qq@D0KvgQZdRyaGFKq9KwK1eYtg@6mNzOtKM6CQ6LprHmCenvV4qnG23s8gB7810EYIbOuEbhftEGW0opZe0uxqM8YVZItyoGwozo5aSmAKqJdgSdTJLiJumoZfLhWEBG@FhvV5qi6mmEYx2aw3a@KIYNdTFdsDn9/Fdeh9@in0afZp8GvxfuD1sj9qB9pgnkCeJJ4EneZ/HdWldWJvVRfVJp0CnOKcwn6V0IB1GC9Eh9AAn@CbwJuieg7PZbDSTzAZzuXwsn8qHeobJQrKIDCCLx8HxaDwYj2UaxSQxQUYOE8OmcCFcBhfBIKAMxtAOzb8Gvxq815mrV1nKr/vsv5H2@daeSW/20f@W3rme4JVxt1rPV/DN9w4@mWv1DZEn39T3BbzMwkfXt3Wgv2WI5PCNzwVlRUZzKsMPy@VS/3unf72Gd9Do6R8)

Deadfish~ has two output commands, `o` to print the accumulator as an integer and `c` to print a character. All whitespace is printed with `c`, and 84 of the 190 digits are printed with `c`, determined by an exhaustive search. If you're interested, here is the semi-golfed and fully unreadable generator: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVTbbtswDH33V/ClkBQrrZ1ua9fNxdrfCIxBle1UaSoZloO2CLJfz0j5ksbdHvYyBFHEw0PykKZTv7WPzl4eDua5dk0L/s1HVeOeodpa3Tq38dB7Ns32p1b6sYyioqygKFVRGf/IvQQlbiKAyjXwCsaCJwvAVGhmGTDDbkDFWRrQckN4lrGC0PkU9YTOMjVkUJSQz1MJi89fBPqyZHTdpkmS3DRlu23snPJ0V1CdwopbCXWQ1kAGyzwKYfb7VacP0RhhjvpmVoZTSOAojEw6xRByu5iE7M78np0p@TBLExE6xztJrZd2vsjzaKSqGHuSD3R@IKaBSKAhqFF2VfJUzn/Zi4uFOC2p4jvMcj/JYfJg38n7ISciNJslJo/vlkkO1rVhhswUTAIrDJ37HQvN9RPzZcsbEUV141aeZrXjjEnGxD6PPsjDjkla4J6rui5twStuZIcITPNj3BUuwqNYcSWhdRKqENpqrNG6@NM1Gt6h4QlhDE1H9d1oUnUdeqPk3UgIe5FPhOp@SNCkGDHu5BPt5OBxE0/rRpeeuvTgwhl6h/vIQNkiZCfFQ7Ve9Utvhu31ekrX7@h6Snf@SHdEr47sMINT9rvkeso@ze3Lo0s72xq7LY9Nqc2GLz0@Ca8l1sGvzsUxoCmp9LOx3LuYORYjxeuYabxhwFP5lm1KK74Ni4N82hpjW77iiQR8Ty8XAmLAiNk1/vJwEedrhzlX/HIh4TVwxn@Lbq0WtFbvAzsupUx6GBeLgtbHoCuZyHnab2OnIZ2KWA8i1v8oYv03EX2/zBi3K/bGnXwQcTuz/5PaVH79v1IPh98)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>105</s> 103 bytes

```java
a->{for(int j,i=-9;i++<8;){var s="";for(j=0;j++<9;)s+=j+" ".repeat(i<0?-i:i);System.out.println(s+0);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY8xb8IwEIX3/IpTJluuo7CVGsPMwMSIGK7BoDMhsWwTCaL89tS4VXnLSffefadncUBpT9fZ3b9baqBpMQTYIXUwFgUkUReNP2NjYDvmxUtDTydA59oHsBQA5Cp70@/NHyxEjGnk8C0h2T566i6HI6C/BA5v3haeoGeU6/Hc@0y0H6TlUpEQq0/FxwE9BF2W6uVbXSubjKXiQWgrSigrb5zByGhVbyR9EVf7R4jmVvX3WLn0NbYdC6LmappmVfw/fla5BZOLd4Np/gE)

Thanks to ceilingcat for -2

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>77</s> 76 bytes

```
(for(i<- -8 to 8)yield"1234567890".mkString(" "*math.abs(i)))foreach println
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##JY69DoIwHAfn8hS/MLUmEL9FIoMP4GScjMMfKFAt1JTGhBievTZxvlzuxoo0eVM@ZeVwITXgG7EPaTTGoPC8MZarU4IkgzPIxKSkruPVerPd7Q/ZcRmn/evqrBpaHiNe9OS6lMqRKyFEcCVVHd4BOz14VssGfWhwsu2Y42wtTfe//RA5boNyKMIAwFjoR2yOZv8D)

Thanks Kevin Cruijssen for 1 byte saved!

Comment: Nice answer, +1 from me. :) You can save 1 byte by removing the space at `)foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2) `Ṁjr`, 10 bytes

```
₀ƛIkdǓj;Ṙ∞
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyLhuYBqciIsIiIsIuKCgMabSWtkx5NqO+G5mOKIniIsIiIsIiJd)

port of my vyxal 3 answer

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 72 bytes

```python
for i in range(-8,9):print(('%-'+'%ds'%-~abs(i))*10)%tuple('1234567890')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1VQ9dCx1LTqqAoM69EQ0NdVVddW101pRjIqEtMKtbI1NTUMjTQVC0pLchJ1VA3NDI2MTUzt7A0UNf8/x8A)

Answer (score 0):

## Vim, 53 bytes

```
i1234567890^[^qq8a ^[lq8@qqeYpPqqqlxbequ^qw9@q@eq7@wdj
```

Where `^[` is the `ESC` Key.

```
i1234567890^[^       puts 1-9+0 in the buffer and returns the cursor to the beginning
qq8a ^[lq8@q         puts 8 spaces between each of the numbers
qeYpPq               records @e to duplicate the line twice and stay on the middle one
qqlxbequ^            records @q to delete one space between numbers and undoes it
qw9@q@eq             records @w to do @q 9 times, then @e
7@wdj                does @w 7 more times, then deletes two lines
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 84 bytes

```
for x in range(-8,9):
 z=""
 for y in range(1,11):z+=str(y%10)+" "*abs(x)
 print(z)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SKFCITNPoSgxLz1VQ9dCx1LTikuhylZJiUsBJFmJkDTUMTTUtKrSti0uKdKoVDU00NRWUlDSSkwq1qjQ5FIoKMrMK9Go0vz/HwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3) `j`, 12 bytes

```
₀ƛkdṘmð×j]Ṛṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJqIiwiIiwi4oKAxptrZOG5mG3DsMOXal3huZrhuYUiLCIiLCIiLCIzLjQuMiJd)