# It was just an input-bug

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Continuing my [*It was just a bug*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/129523/it-was-just-a-bug) challenge:

#### Input:

A string consisting of printable ASCII characters without white-spaces nor new-lines.

#### Output:

First turn the input into a palindrome by reverting the input, and adding it before itself, excluding the middle character (i.e. with an input `1234567890`, it will becomes `0987654321234567890`).

And then output this text:

```
0        9        8        7        6        5        4        3        2        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0
         0       9       8       7       6       5       4       3       2       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0
                  0      9      8      7      6      5      4      3      2      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0
                           0     9     8     7     6     5     4     3     2     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0
                                    0    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0
                                             0   9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0
                                                      0  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0
                                                               0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
                                                                        0987654321234567890
                                                               0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
                                                      0  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0
                                             0   9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0
                                    0    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0
                           0     9     8     7     6     5     4     3     2     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0
                  0      9      8      7      6      5      4      3      2      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0
         0       9       8       7       6       5       4       3       2       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0
0        9        8        7        6        5        4        3        2        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0
```

(From the middle outward in both directions, each character is separated by one more space than the previous line.)

### Challenge rules:

- You need to print twice the length of the input, minus 3 lines. So with the input `1234567890`, the output displayed above is 17 lines (length 10 * 2 - 3).
- The input will only contain printable ASCII (excluding space, tab and new-line).
- Trailing spaces are optional.
- A single trailing new-line is optional.
- (Additional) leading spaces or leading new-lines are not allowed.
- You can assume the input will always be at least four characters long.
- Unlike my *It was just a bug* challenge, both the input and output formats are flexible. So you are allowed to output the result as a String-array, String-list, etc.

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer, so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code.
- Also, please add an explanation if necessary.

### Test cases:

```
Input: 1234567890
Output:
0        9        8        7        6        5        4        3        2        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0
         0       9       8       7       6       5       4       3       2       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0
                  0      9      8      7      6      5      4      3      2      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0
                           0     9     8     7     6     5     4     3     2     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0
                                    0    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0
                                             0   9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0
                                                      0  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0
                                                               0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
                                                                        0987654321234567890
                                                               0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
                                                      0  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0
                                             0   9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0
                                    0    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0
                           0     9     8     7     6     5     4     3     2     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0
                  0      9      8      7      6      5      4      3      2      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0
         0       9       8       7       6       5       4       3       2       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0
0        9        8        7        6        5        4        3        2        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0

Input: ABCD
Output:
D  C  B  A  B  C  D 
   D C B A B C D
      DCBABCD
   D C B A B C D
D  C  B  A  B  C  D

Input: =>)}]
Output:
]   }   )   >   =   >   )   }   ]
    ]  }  )  >  =  >  )  }  ]
        ] } ) > = > ) } ]
            ]})>=>)}]
        ] } ) > = > ) } ]
    ]  }  )  >  =  >  )  }  ]
]   }   )   >   =   >   )   }   ]

Input: XXxxXX
Output:
X    X    x    x    X    X    X    x    x    X    X
     X   X   x   x   X   X   X   x   x   X   X
          X  X  x  x  X  X  X  x  x  X  X
               X X x x X X X x x X X
                    XXxxXXXxxXX
               X X x x X X X x x X X
          X  X  x  x  X  X  X  x  x  X  X
     X   X   x   x   X   X   X   x   x   X   X
X    X    x    x    X    X    X    x    x    X   X
```

Comment: Are an equal amount of leading spaces on every line OK?

Comment: @Adám Sorry but no. Any number of trailing spaces are fine, but leading spaces not. I'll specify this rule in the challenge.

Comment: "You need to print the length of the input minus 3 lines." then "(length 10 * 2 - 3)". The first sentence says "no double", the second one says "double". So which is it?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Oops, first line should have contained 2x the length minus 3. Fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `C`, 11 bytes

```
ṪẏṘ∞ƛ?Ṙ∞$Ij
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJDIiwiIiwi4bmq4bqP4bmY4oiexps/4bmY4oieJElqIiwiIiwiPT4pfV0iXQ==)

### Explanation

```
ṪẏṘ∞ƛ?Ṙ∞$Ij
Ṫ           # Remove the last element (removing the first element would be fine too)
 ẏ          # Make a range [0, length)
  Ṙ         # Reverse
   ∞        # Palindromize, a + a[::-1][1:]
    ƛ       # Map, and for each:
     ?Ṙ     #  Push the input reversed
       ∞    #  Palindromize that (call this X)
        $   #  Swap so the current item is at the top
         I  #  Push that many spaces
          j #  Join the characters of X by that
            # C flag centers and joins on newlines
```

Comment: Would you mind adding an explanation? Then I'll accept it as the new shortest answer.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Sure, added.

Answer (score 8):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
¬Å£¬qYîÃy w ê y w ê ·
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=rMWjrHFZ7sN5IHcg6iB5IHcg6iC3&input=ImFiY2RlIg==)

#### Explanation

The first 8 bytes generate the bottom-right quadrant of the pattern:

```
 ¬ Å  £    ¬ qYîÃ
Uq s1 mXY{Uq qYî} 

Uq                 : Split the input into characters.
   s1              : Slice off the first.
      mXY{      }  : Map each item X and index Y to
          Uq       :   the input split into chars,
             q     :   joined with
              Yî   :     Y spaces.
```

At this point we have an array of e.g. `["ABCD", "A B C D", "A  B  C  D"]`. Unfortunately, it takes 13 bytes to square this:

```
y w ê y w ê ·
y w ê y w ê qR
y                : Pad each line to the same length with spaces and transpose.
  w              : Reverse the array, and
    ê            : palindromize. Now we have the bottom half of the output transposed.
      y          : Transpose back.
        w ê      : Reverse and palindromize again, giving the full output.
            qR   : Join with newlines.
                 : Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Comment: Wish I'd thought to use transpose - nicely done :)

Comment: Can I ask a question I'm scared to know the answer to?  Are you and the rest here actually coding this out in its minified version?

Comment: If you dare. Probably not.

Comment: @gdbj I usually do... is that a bad sign? :P

Comment: @ETHproductions Was just telling a buddy that this is similar to real golf: frustrating to learn, strangely addicting, and demonstrating skill in it commands respect.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>149 141</s> 95 bytes

```python
def f(s):l=len(s)-1;[print((' '*abs(i)).join(s[:0:-1]+s).center(2*l*l+1))for i in range(1-l,l)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxLDoIwFAD3nKK7vgdCKPjFuPBziCaEBWirNS@FtCzw9LWJK3eTmWSmz/wabR3CQ2mmwWNDJ1I2Qi6O7eSMnQE442k/eDCIxXs0sbZN2eSiyzwWd2Vn5aBKKaVMIOrRMcOMZa63TwUipxVhFzTw8@V645j8pphEI@WySPnvRFWvN9vd/lByDF8)

Thanks to @KevinCruijssen and @ETHproductions for saving some bytes

***Special thanks to @notjagan for saving 46 bytes!***

Comment: Changing `l=len(s);` to `l=len(s)-1;` and then changing all the values involving `l` (i.e. `l-1` -> `l`; `-l+2` -> `-l+1`; etc.) is 8 bytes shorter. [Try it here.](https://tio.run/##Rcy9CsMgFAXg3adw815TE2w3S4b@PIQQMqRE21vEBJMhfXob6dDlcDgHvvmzvqZ4ynl0nntY0DAe2uDiXpU@p7YDwYUcHgsQYv2eqDx@Spw4RZ6G@HSgQqUPAXvG/4eZE8UVIEgISqOCYiZsmqNKNcXRbQWUAeXuV9QZo3TflagIswdxud7uAtmPQbYv1m6btQLzFw)

Comment: `-l+2` -> `2-l` :)

Comment: Thanks @KevinCruijssen, unfortunately I cannot edit right now, can you please edit in?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks a lot!

Comment: [6 bytes shorter](https://tio.run/##Tcy9DoIwFIbhnavo1nOKBasbhMGfi2hCGDC0esxJIYUBr75CXNy@vF/yTJ/lNYZzSoPzwsOMFTfswja0qWPTghRS9Y8ZCLF4j7Q/foyCBAUR@/B0YDQfGLu6nSKFBYAVsDaoYXciluVJx4LC4NYdUYxqM3Nqq2OlTZfTn9clD/Jyvd0lZj8Ns61Yu67WSkxf) by changing the `for` loop to a list comp and changing `i[::-1][:-1]` to `i[:0:-1]`.

Comment: Down to [95 bytes](https://tio.run/##VYxLDoIwFAD3nKK7vgdCKPjFuPBziCaEBWirNS@FtCzw9LWJK3eTmWSmz/wabR3CQ2mmwWNDJ1I2Qi6O7eSMnQE442k/eDCIxXs0sbZN2eSiyzwWd2Vn5aBKKaVMIOrRMcOMZa63TwUipxVhFzTw8@V645j8pphEI@WySPnvRFWvN9vd/lByDF8) using `center` instead of the `for` loop!

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 17 bytes

```
g<F¹RSðN×ýû})Rû.c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P8wNWFiMWX//2c8RsK5UlPDsE7Dl8O9w7t9KVLDuy5j//8xMjM0NTY3ODkw)

-1 thanks to [kalsowerus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68910/kalsowerus).

Comment: You can save one byte by replacing `.c.∊` with `û.c`

Comment: @kalsowerus And I knew there would be some way to use `û`...thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
Ｅ⁻Ｌθ¹⪫θ× ι‖Ｏ←↑
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9jaGFyY29hbP//77yl4oG777yszrjCueKqq864w5cgzrnigJbvvK/ihpDihpH//zEyMzQ1Njc4OTA)

AST:

```
Program
├Print
│└Ｅ: Map
│ ├⁻: Difference
│ │├Ｌ: Length
│ ││└θ: Identifier θ
│ │└1: Number 1
│ └⪫: Join
│  ├θ: Identifier θ
│  └×: Product
│   ├' ': String ' '
│   └ι: Identifier ι
└‖Ｏ: Reflect overlap
 └Multidirectional
  ├←: Left
  └↑: Up
```

Comment: Might be 16 codepoints, but as UTF-8 Python 3 reports that it is 41 bytes. Which charset do you use to make it 16 bytes?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen It's a custom charset.

Comment: Huh, ⪫ works on strings? Must remember that for next time...

Comment: @Neil Yeah it makes sense doesn't it?

Comment: Technically your edit is noncompeting because the relevant commit postdates the challenge.

Comment: There's new consensus about that, and right now it has lots of upvotes so I follow it. ;)

Comment: Sometimes I'm curious what the backend source code for Charcoal looks like.. It's cool that you print the input string and add one more space every line, and with a 'simply' `‖Ｏ←↑` you reflect it left, up and diagonal left+up, like it's nothing. I really need to learn this language. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen You seem to like ascii-art, so I'd recommend to...it's not really difficult btw.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen If you're curious then look at it :P remember you can click on the language name on TIO

Comment: @ASCII-only Or directly on the header of my post!

Comment: :O what amazing

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (ES6)](https://babeljs.io/), <strike>159</strike> <strike>136</strike> <strike>129</strike> 127 bytes

```javascript
f=(i,x=1-(l=i.length-1),y=x<0?-x:x,[,...b]=i)=>l>x?''.padEnd(l*(l+~y))+[...b.reverse(),...i].join(''.padEnd(y))+`
`+f(i,x+1):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1dC4IwGEbv@yPbm9vQvpOm9PUfhBDSnDYZm6jIvKi/bnkVhLfnnIenTLqkedSyammapEJRbTIxDDnHkljuUay4ZEroon1SD0jP7cENqfUtuRHGWBpzCTxQgQ0RYlWSXXWG1Rwr590DOLcxYbXoRN0IDONCxqw0UuNfPob32d3Jx0vHAx@h4WF0Y5RgyhQ4x8hbLFfrzXa3dxHA7E8eT@fLBOYBvOIJHkXWRtFXDB8) Explanation below

```javascript
// This is a recursive function
// First, inputs and various variable initializations
// by using defaults
let func = (
  // Text input, will not be modified through recursion
  input,

  // Current line, for the first function call we start from -lines to +lines
  // It's roughly equivalent to lines*2 but this helps us computing the spacing
  // Also computing the total amount of lines
  currentLine = 1 - (totalLines = input.length - 1),

  // Getting the absolute value of the current line (like Math.floor)
  absCurrentLine = currentLine < 0 ? -currentLine : currentLine,

  // Getting the input without it's first letter, useful for the palidrome of the input
  [,...slicedInput] = input

// Base case, stopping the recursion if the current line
// is still below the total amount of lines
) => totalLines > currentLine

  // Leading spacing
  ? ''.padEnd(totalLines * (totalLines + ~absCurrentLine)) + 

  // Putting together the palindrome version and adding spaces between the chars
    [...slicedInput.reverse(), ...input].join(''.padEnd(absCurrentLine)) + `

  // Line return + recursion call
` + f(input, currentLine + 1)
  : ''
```

First entry to codegolf, I apologise in advance for any obvious mistakes.

Thanks to Justin Mariner for saving 23 bytes!
Thanks to Craig Ayre for saving 11 bytes and for the bug report.

Comment: Nice first answer, +1 from me and welcome to PPCG. I'm not too familiar with Js, but is it possible to start `x` at -2 instead of -1, and change `x<=l` to `++x<=l` so you can remove the `x++` and save a byte?

Comment: I tried but didn't manage to because `lines` is entangled with the spacing as well so it ends up costing more bytes to make it all work again. But I'm fairly certain that there is both a better way to organise the code and add your suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, nice first post and explanation! Golfed down to [133 bytes here](https://goo.gl/KcDQmD). Includes explanation of what was changed.

Comment: Unfortunately your output doesn't seem to quite match the expected output: [see here](https://gist.github.com/craigayre/f36871744074b4e4d9222f313c7469da)

Comment: Thank you for noticing, should be fixed now - had to add 3 bytes but at least it works!

Comment: Good job on fixing the bug with so few bytes! [Here](https://tio.run/##bY/LboMwEEX3@YrZ2S7ghL4blUR9/UC7QYoixcCQOHJsZBsEi347NV2kUpWVpXvOnRkfRSdcaWXjk0IUqBJtKhznc/jEsrVOdggdhtdoMDV8iZPUe@LAGdX6EM5@Td9a7UCA8zZgsMIf0II/iFBqfdN6H@IYWjfRs1YGXCCIplESK/AGamNBGdOcx0PR@jBHhoWiQwcnYxGKwaMb64zKuM8SqjLJFeq9PyQpi9J4yPrnxTrpl328iTnnxTaTLFupVb8mhDei@tAVVVdUJUMosGgzOdzi9E2kbKrILT8aqemfPwRxN9tF9bQ0StmSkLE0OtyJXJk9rSlJr29u7@4fHp8WhLHZP/jy@vZ@Ic5W7Ht7Ic/zvs/zAMYf) is a recursive version of your solution - I'm sure it can be golfed further still!

Comment: This is great, I added your new function and updated the explanation

Comment: Sadly, the output is [not the same](https://tio.run/##bY1LCoMwAAX3vUiSxgTtv9Io/d1BEMFftJGQiIrERXt1q6tCcTszj1clfdJmjag7kiYpl0TpnI9jwaCwDHMIlExQyVXZvbCDrIGZi@0T4xortCilacQEYp70jA8ArZP8qXIo11Diz4AQDueENrznTcshmhciopUWCv7yOYxXMS7my@nEBWDMtGq15FTqEhYQOJvtbn84ns42QGj1J6@3@2MBMw@9owUeBMYEwSTGLw)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61761/discussion-between-saming-and-craig-ayre).

Answer (score 4):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>22</s> 18 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
ā,⁄H{,čFH@*∑Κ}▓±╬-
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUwMTAxJTJDJXUyMDQ0SCU3QiUyQyV1MDEwREZIQColdTIyMTEldTAzOUElN0QldTI1OTMlQjEldTI1NkMt,inputs=JTNEJTNFJTI5JTdEJTVE)

Explanation:

```
ā                   push an empty array - canvas
 ,⁄H{        }      input length-1 times do
     ,                push the input
      č               chop it into chars
       FH@*           get the current iteration-1 amount of spaces
           ∑          join the chopped input with the spaces
            Κ         prepend it to the array
              ▓     space to a square
               ±    reverse each string in that list
                ╬-  quad-palindromize with 1 X and 1 Y overlap and without swapping characters
```

Comment: Is `╬-` the four-way palindromize command? I was just over here wishing Japt had something like that... :P

Comment: @ETHproductions FWIW, `╬` is [many things](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline/blob/master/compiler/interpreter/data/palenChars.txt)

Comment: I know, hence why I specified `╬-`. But thanks, I couldn't find that page for some reason

Comment: @ETHproductions Oh. It only exists in the SOGLOnline copy of the interpreter :/ At some point I need to join the two together :|

Comment: Hmm...you should implement automatic `F` for `∑` if it's needed.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer The explanation is a bit off (it's `č` that chops). I thought I already implemented it, but forgot to  push. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, <s>145</s> 131 bytes

It took some thinking to golf that additional byte; but it was worth it.

```php
while($y<=2*$e=strlen($a=$argn)-1)echo($p=str_pad)("
",$e*($e-$d=abs($y++-$e))+1),chunk_split($a.substr(strrev($a),1),1,$p("",$d));
```

prints a leading newline. Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5d070ffdde85d82aefcb56f98bb115c08b6a5db5).

**breakdown**

```php
while($y<=2*$e=strlen($a=$argn)-1)  # $e=length-1, loop through rows
                                        # 1. print linebreak and left padding
    echo($p=str_pad)("\n",$e*($e-$d=abs($y++-$e))+1),
        chunk_split(
            $a.substr(strrev($a),1)     # 2. palindromize input
            ,1,$p("",$d));              # 3. insert $e..0..$e spaces between characters
```

**alternative solution**, same length:

```php
for($d=-$e=strlen($a=$argn)-1;$d<$e;)echo($p=str_pad)("
",$e*($e-$b=abs($d++))+1),chunk_split($a.substr(strrev($a),1),1,$p("",$b));
```

Comment: You can save 13 Bytes with [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7LDoJADEX3fIVpumiZ0QS2QIyP/zCDjgIh0MygCRt/fSwuurg9p@mVTlJ9lE4ydOE1NXA6X65QpeccqDIG17rM0TdxCaOfCF3z17hif@9mQtnITdyDaZh7FYQArGsj4bpHz2w3HmXsFz0@xHermXSC/@iCbcHqlPlXZf1jCgs7sCVbyLRE@gE "PHP – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 37 bytes

Requires `⎕IO←0` which is default on many systems.

```apl
{⍉m(2-d)↓⍉(m←⊖⍪1↓⊢)↑∊¨(1↓⍳d←≢⍵)↑¨¨⊂⍵}
```

`{`…`}` anonymous function where the argument is represented by *⍵*

`(`…`)↑¨¨⊂⍵` for each (`¨`) of the following numbers take (`↑`) that many characters from each (`¨`) of the entire (`⊂`) argument, padding with spaces as necessary:

`≢w` the number of characters in the argument

`d←` store that in *d*

`⍳` that many **ɩ**ndices (0 … *d* − 1)

`1↓` drop one (the zero)

`∊¨` **ϵ**nlist (flatten) each

`↑` raise the rank (convert the list of lists into a matrix)

`(m←`…`)` apply the following tacit function *m*, defined as:

`⊖` the upside-down argument

`⍪` on top of

`1` one [row]

`↓` dropped from

`⊢` the argument

`⍉` transpose

`(`…`)↓` drop:

`2-d` = −(*d* − 2), i.e. *d* − 2 rows from the bottom

`m` apply *m*

`⍉` transpose

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/9OAZPWj3s5cDSPdFM1HbZOBbI1coOCjrmmPelcZgkS6FgElJj7q6Dq0QgMs0Ls5BaSic9Gj3q0gqUMrDq141NUE5NX@/5@moG5oZGxiamZuYWmgzgXkOjo5u4AZtnaatbFgVkRERUVEhDoA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>201</s> 196 bytes

```java
s->{for(int l=s.length()-1,i=-l,x=0;++i<l;x+=i<0?l:-l)System.out.printf("%1$"+(x<1?"":x)+"s"+s.join("%1$"+(i<0?-i:i>0?i:"")+"s",(new StringBuffer(s.substring(1)).reverse()+s).split(""))+"%n","");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDLbsIwELzzFSurSLaSWKTvJgRUaI89cUQcQnDA1DiR14FUKN9OnYdUqT54VzOe8c4e03MaFKXQx933ray2SmaQqRQRvlKp4ToCGFC0qXXlXMgdnBxHV9ZIvV9vIDV7ZGAPprggfNaZKK0sei3A0X3AKysVzyudtQRfFhqrkzDT3mEGJrlhMLvmhaFSW1AJciX03h4oC0JfJoHy62QSe56cqrj2EjmdzFUUKLb6QStOvKgsL52VzSkZh3fEo/U0nBMS1cwjSDzkx8INPHCtOpCRnE3mMiKke@JTLS7Qz7Oo8lwYihyrLXYIDRnjRpyFQUGZh4xjqaSlTuzUY01818XNDboTd7nbML0fYAR/7uvNlYT3D49Pzy@vbxOnfF8sP1xJZqzZkIYNawMwPM3aVVJk8QD9j6s0HbhmNGqv5vYL)

It's the same idea as [the one I used for the previous challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129550/16236), except that the generator string is now a tad longer and with more hard to handle cases.

```java
%1$Ns0%1$Ns9%1$Ns8%1$Ns7%1$Ns6%1$Ns5%1$Ns4%1$Ns3%1$Ns2%1$Ns1%1$Ns2%1$Ns3%1$Ns4%1$Ns5%1$Ns6%1$Ns7%1$Ns8%1$Ns9%1$Ns0%n
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>134</s> 124 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:'\n'.join([' '*(len(s)-1)*abs(len(s)-abs(i)-2)+(' '*abs(i)).join(s[::-1]+s[1:]) for i in range(2-len(s),len(s)-1)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzLDoIwFET3fkV37QVrLPhsgomPj2iCXZQIWoMXQlngwm@vEiIJuzknM1O/20eFsfdFUppXdjPESXpFunhWFllKCQ1YmSNzwAUEJnN/6qMFHkHI@tKAMMxcKiUXOnSpkBpIUTXEEoukMXjPWcSHi/n4q8HXjcWWFYyKKF6tN9vdfkkBZqM@ns6XiUgO8NETo1TXKfVT/gs)

First post to PPCG after lurking for a while. Looking for any suggestions/advice!

---

Thanks to @LyricLy and @Łukasz Rogalski for improvements!

Comment: You don't have to print the output inside the function, output can be given in a return value. Also, you don't have to count the `f=` in the bytecount, simply providing an anonymous function is fine.

Comment: Also, `-len(s)+2` is just `2-len(s)`, one less byte.

Comment: Thank you @Łukasz Rogalski and @LyricLy; you have saved me 10 bytes!

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>177</s> 163 bytes

```
import Data.List
k n=[1..n]>>" "
f s=let n=length s in map(\x->(k(((n-1)*(n-(abs x)))))++(intercalate (k(abs x))$map(\z->[z])$((++)=<<reverse.tail) s))[n,n-1.. -n]
```

The function `f` is the challenge function and returns a list of strings (`[String]`), using `unlines` on it should provide the same visual output as the test cases (`main = putStr $ unlines $ f "test string"` to compile it).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU27bsMwDNz9FYThgYproc6jbYDYU8duHR0PTMA0gmXWkJggyM@7apAbDoc78u5McWDv59mN029Q@CQl@@WiZgNI09XWSt@2OeTZCWLjWZPrWX70DBGcwEgT7m9ViwMiSlWbRWKkQ4Sb@UdZohPlcCRPypDOnlnx@LxXbXfvTYFYlqbZ7QJfOUS2Ss4biMZ08pJarYVK@iwbKU02MF30WwMUcBHvhGNSJ8jr5Wq9eXv/2L7m8/wH)

-14 bytes thanks to @nimi

Comment: `k` can be defined as `k n=[1..n]>>" "` and `p` as `p=(++)=<<reverse.tail` (you can even inline this definition).

Answer (score 3):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `N`, 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ḣı$ṅṣj;ðƬrⱮṬrⱮ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOCVBMyVDNCVCMSUyNCVFMSVCOSU4NSVFMSVCOSVBM2olM0IlQzMlQjAlQzYlQUNyJUUyJUIxJUFFJUUxJUI5JUFDciVFMiVCMSVBRSZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSUyMjEyMzQ1Njc4OTAlMjImZmxhZ3M9Tg==)

I have *absolutely* no idea why this works, but it does.

##### Explanation

```python
ḣı$ṅṣj;ðƬrⱮṬrⱮ  # Implicit input
ḣı    ;         # len(input) - 1 times:
  $  j          #   Join the input by...
   ṅṣ           #   ...loop index spaces
       ðƬ       # Transpose with filler space
         rⱮ     # Reverse and palindromise
           Ṭ    # Tranpose it
            rⱮ  # Reverse and palindromise
                # Implicit output, joined on newlines
```

I did quite a bit of experimenting, producing a lot of buggy outputs. Here's my favourite:

```js
                                                                        0987654321234567890                                                                        
                                                               0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0                                                               
                                                      0  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0                                                      
                                             0   9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0                                             
                                    0    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0                                    
                           0     9     8     7     6     5     4     3     2     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0                           
                  0      9      8      7      6      5      4      3      2      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0                  
         0       9       8       7       6       5       4       3       2       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0         
0        9        8        7        6        5        4        3        2        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0
         0       9       8       7       6       5       4       3       2       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0         
                  0      9      8      7      6      5      4      3      2      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0                  
                           0     9     8     7     6     5     4     3     2     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0                           
                                    0    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0                                    
                                             0   9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0                                             
                                                      0  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0                                                      
                                                               0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0                                                               
                                                                        0987654321234567890
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 141 bytes

```
Column[Join[Reverse@(s=Row/@Table[Riffle[Reverse@Rest@b~Join~b,""<>Table[" ",i]],{i,0,Length[b=Characters@#]-1}]),Rest@s],Alignment->Center]&
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 15 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ÊÆÔ¬qXç)êÃÔÅê û
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=ysbUrHFY5ynqw9TF6iD7&input=IkFCQ0Qi)

```
ÊÆÔ¬qXç)êÃÔÅê û     :Implicit input of string
Ê                   :Length
 Æ                  :Map each X in the range [0,length)
  Ô                 :  Reverse U
   ¬                :  Split
    q               :  Join with
     Xç             :    X spaces
       )            :  End join
        ê           :  Palindromise
         Ã          :End map
          Ô         :Reverse
           Å        :Slice off first element
            ê       :Palindromise
              û     :Centre pad each element with spaces to the length of the longest
                    :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <sup><s>100</s></sup> 90 bytes

```julia
s->(l=length(s)-2;[' '^(-~l*(l-j))*prod(s[abs(i)+1]*' '^j for i=~l:l+1) for j=abs.(-l:l)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3LDoIwFETX9isaNtwLllh8a@p3NCGYYAAtaQqhNWHFr9fiQndzJmcy3Vurik@@pYJ6y26ghW7M073AIsuvRUzjO7BZJ6BZh5gMY1@DLaqHBYUpL5NF6Gjbj1SJWV90yvFLnQhOBixUWKJ3jXXhoiCRlNMkZbQmEc@3u/3heDpvIlISsqwcVYYuLlkNozJOG3D4yxm0Af8MSBpT@w8)

-10 bytes thanks to @KevinCruijssen

Comment: Nice answer! Some small things to golf: `(l+1)` can be `-~l` and `in -l-1` can be `in~l` for -5 bytes. ([Here is the relevant tip.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67630/52210) And if you haven't seen it yet, [tips for golfing in Julia](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24407/tips-for-golfing-in-julia) might be interesting to read through as well.)

Comment: You've now accidently used `~-l` (l-1) instead of `-~l` (l+1) in your latest edit, so the output is incorrect.. :)

Comment: true, thanks for checking ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
Ｌ╷ｒＨ ×⁸；＊∔｝↔↕┼
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjJDJXUyNTc3JXVGRjUyJXVGRjI4JTIwJUQ3JXUyMDc4JXVGRjFCJXVGRjBBJXUyMjE0JXVGRjVEJXUyMTk0JXUyMTk1JXUyNTND,i=QUJDRA__,v=8)

### Explanation

```
L|rH ×⁸;*∔}↔↕┼
L              length of input
 |r            decrement, make range [0..n-1]
   H           create an empty art object, start a loop with i
     ×         repeat space i times
      ⁸;       swap with the input
        *      join input with i spaces
         ∔     add to the bottom of the previous iteration
          }    close the loop
           ↔↕  mirror horizontally and vertically
             ┼ quad palindromize with 1 character overlap
```

Comment: Yep, looks great now. I'll remove my comments. +1 from me. Would you mind adding an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
¦ε\RðN×ýû}Rû.c
```

Input as a list of characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0IpzW2OCDm/wOzz98N7Du2uDDu/WS/7/P1rJUUlHyQmInYHYRSkWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaBkX6nDpeRfWgLh6VQGH1r5/9CKc1sPrQs6vMHv8PTDew/vrg06vFsv@b/OoW32/6OVHJ2cXZR0lGztNGtjgXREREVFRASQYWhkbGJqZm5hqRQLAA).

**14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) alternative:**

```
ā¨RjJíðδÜ€ûû.c
```

Also takes a list of characters as input.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SOOhFVleh9ce3nBuy@E5j5rWHN4ddHi3XvL//9FKjko6Sk5A7AzELkqxAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaBkX6nDpeRfWgLh6VQGu/w/0nhoRVCW1@G1hzec23J4zqOmNYd3H96tl/xf59A2@//RSo5Ozi5KOkq2dpq1sUA6IqKiIiICyDA0MjYxNTO3sFSKBQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
¦              # Remove the first item of the (implicit) input-list
               # (could have removed the last as alternative as well)
 ε             # Map over each character:
  \            #  Discard the character
   R           #  Reverse the (implicit) input-list
     N         #  Push the 0-based map-index
    ð ×        #  Repeat a space character that many times as string
       ý       #  Join the reversed input-list with this spaces-string as delimiter
        û      #  Palindromize the entire string
 }R            # After the map: reverse the resulting list
   û           # Palindromize this entire list
    .c         # And centralize it, which also implicitly joins by newlines
               # (after which the result is output implicitly)

ā              # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-length]
 ¨             # Remove the last item to make the range [1, input-length)
  R            # Reverse the list to (input-length, 1]
   j           # Pad each character in the (implicit) input-list with leading spaces so
               # the string lengths become equal to the current integer
    J          # Join each inner list of strings together to a single string
     í         # Reverse each string
       δ       # Map over each string:
      ð Ü      #  And remove all trailing spaces
         €û    # Palindromize each string
           û   # Palindromize the entire list
            .c # And centralize it, which also implicitly joins by newlines
               # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>117</s> <s>113</s> <s>109</s> 112 bytes

```sh
b=`rev<<<$1`${1:1};j=$#1
for c ({$j..1} {2..$j}){printf %$[(j-1)*(j-c)]s
for x (${(s::)b})printf %-$c\s $x;echo}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcrBCsIwDADQu18RMEIrrBCPXfclKoyVjtmD03boNOTbowhe3um966Q6dH1JjxACUo9MnqTNHW5pM84FIhjG7BwJ8ME5zGL5Vi7XZYQdHk1uyO6/Rnuuv7@CQTbVezuI/ccG46kCrm2K0yyqen@msrw@)
 <sub><s>[109b invalid](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/yTahKLXMxsZGxTBBpdrQyrDWOstWRdmQKy2/SCFZQaNaJUtPz7BWodpIT08lq1azoCgzryRNISYmT1UlWiNL11BTC0gma8YWq6mBtFQoaKhUaxRbWWkmwRWr6qokxxQrqFT8//@/sDy1qKQSAA)</s></sub>
 <sub><s>[113b](https://tio.run/##PcpBDsIgEADAu6/YxG0DGoh7RfoSStKUtFEOVaHRKuHta7w45/nkC/PYDWl6WmuRBixkqJ5jhw73pMjv5luCAKJg1PpUoZDWGKu8p@uyztD3S4MuHkRUQfrctr@@gcAisjFy/MdGoQtH8hlwY@bHa0rr@ws)</s></sub>
 <sub><s>[117b](https://tio.run/##LcvdCsIgGAbg865C2DvQwsF36vRKnDD2R3mwmo5aidduEJ0/zydeSxlMH@an1hrUI5Gi3HoDi4okudNyD2xkPEn4poHPIk0Gaaxkbh/htu4L67q1hvVn7uUkXPyNg3EkHpUSQxZ/V0vY6UIuMhy5lLK95rC/vw)</s></sub>

`b` is the palindrome; `j` is the length of input string `$1`. Iterate `c` over the range `{j..1..j}`. For each `c`, print a prefixed number of spaces. For every character `x` in `b`, print `x` with `c` spaces between each.

Comment: Your output has a leading newline, making it invalid I'm afraid due to rule "_(Additional) leading spaces or leading new-lines are not allowed._". (If I would have posted this challenge now, I would have done it differently and allowed any amount of leading/trailing spaces/newlines. But since the amount of answers already on this six year old challenge, it's too late to change it now unfortunately.)

Comment: Hah, I didn't think anyone would notice that :). OK, adjusted per spec. At least the code is slightly more readable now.