# "Print this diamond" gone beautifully wrong

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

Write a function (or a whole program) that outputs (or prints) the following ASCII art:

#### Output:

```
                    1
            1       2       1
      1      2      3      2      1
  1     2     3     4     3     2     1
1    2    3    4    5    4    3    2    1
1   2   3   4   5   6   5   4   3   2   1
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
            12345678987654321
      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
1   2   3   4   5   6   5   4   3   2   1
1    2    3    4    5    4    3    2    1
  1     2     3     4     3     2     1
      1      2      3      2      1
            1       2       1
                    1
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution in bytes wins!

##### Allowed:

- Any number of **trailing spaces** on each line
- An equal number of *additional* **leading spaces** on each line (meaning of additional: without counting the already mandatory leading spaces shown in the output above)
- *Additional* **newlines** at the beginning and/or at the end. These additional lines can contain any number of spaces

---

I'm late to the party, but as some of you may have recognized, this challenge is inspired by the bugged output in [*Carcigenicate*'s answer in Clojure](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109197/52210) for the [Print this diamond](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8696/print-this-diamond) challenge.

This answer also led to a chain of 3 challenges from [*Kevin Cruijssen*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) : [It was just a bug](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/129523/it-was-just-a-bug), [It was just an input-bug](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/129925/it-was-just-an-input-bug), and [I done did made a spaceship maw!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/171679/i-done-did-made-a-spaceship-maw)

But i wanted to see something more "pulsar-y", as this is what i find most beautiful in the original answer!

I hope you will generate beautifully bugged ASCII arts while doing this challenge :)

Comment: Can we output as a list of lines?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I'm not fond of the idea, but apparently multiple solutions already took the initiative of doing it, so i'll allow it.

Comment: Rather than 'pulsar-y', this challenge looks more like a real diamond! Or, well, a brilliant-cut diamond seen from the top; point stands :p.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 80 bytes

```python
i=8
while i+9:k=abs(i);print(f"{(' '*k).join(str((10**(9-k)//9)**2)):^41}");i-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHdCkAwFADge08hN8458jNcGO1VFEWOadasJHn2@T77@O00TWddCKy66N74WGLOZK/VNF/AOFjHxsOavJDGKWks9pMNXN4BiIoIZK6xLCUS1Yj92IovwYFzJUL4AQ)

Uses the classic arithmetic trick where, for example,

```python
(10**9//9)**2 == 111111111**2 == 12345678987654321
```

### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 79 bytes

```python
f=lambda k=8,c=1:(s:=[f"{(' '*k).join(str(c*c)):^41}"])[k:]or s+f(k-1,c*10+1)+s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchBDsIgEADAu6/Y9NJdqEaih4aElzQ1qSgRaRcCXIzx7ahznPSqj8inMeXWnFmX7XpbIJhxsEZpLNpMrntjD70IdHhGz1hqRisskb6c1aebaQp6jhmKdBj2arBCHaUiWZr77er5Dp7BIekdpOy54v@ofQE)

Recursive function that generates a list of lines when called with no inputs. The idea is to start with the center line, then repeatedly sandwich what we have between two copies of a new line.

### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 79 bytes

```python
f=lambda p=8*' ',c=1:(s:=f"{p.join(str(c*c)):^41}\n")+(p and f(p[1:],c*10+1)+s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoMwEADArwQv7iYiXepBAnmJWkgjoYquS5JLKb49nZFv@Vz8HCXVGt3hz/fqlbhRt6rtgiML2brY/KTfr40hlwRBB0T7GuieuUEDojyvKoJMZJcuaHoYQpOxStq4QATE@gc)

Recursive function that generates the whole multiline string, with a trailing newline, when called with no input.

Answer (score 7):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
9Rƒıṅ8_ṣjⱮ;ⱮØC
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPTlSJUM2JTkyJUM0JUIxJUUxJUI5JTg1OF8lRTElQjklQTNqJUUyJUIxJUFFJTNCJUUyJUIxJUFFJUMzJTk4QyZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSZmbGFncz0=)

<s>Seems like the compressed list part (`¿qJŒḣ“ɲþẇɦɠ¿i`) could be golfed a bit with a formula, but I couldn't find it.</s>

<s>I found the formula \$(n-6)(n-5)\$ for the leading spaces.</s>

I don't need that any more. Port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.

*-5 by porting @KevinCruijssen's 05AB1E answer*

##### Explanation

```python
9Rƒıṅ8_ṣjⱮ;ⱮØC  # Full program
9Rƒ             # Prefixes of [1..9]
   ı      ;     # Map over:
    ṅ8_         #  8 - iteration index
       ṣj       #  Join by that many spaces
         Ɱ      #  Palindromise
           Ɱ    # Palindromise
            ØC  # Center
                # Implicit output
```

Old:

```python
9RⱮı65d-pṣnRⱮn9_ṣj+  # Full program
9RⱮı                 # Map over [1,2,...,8,9,8,...,2,1]:
    65d-pṣ           #  Push (n-6) * (n-5) spaces
          nRⱮ        #  Push [1,2,...,n,...2,1]
             n9_ṣj   #  Join by (9-n) spaces
                  +  #  Prepend the leading spaces
                     # Implicit output, joined on newlines
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>71</s> 69 bytes

Function outputting an array of lines. A synthesis of my old answer with [Level River St](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15599/level-river-st)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263151/52194) as per their suggestions.

-2 bytes by switching to Ruby 2.7+ (TIO is on 2.5.5)

```ruby
->{(-8..8).map{([*1...x=9-k=_1.abs,*x.downto(1)]*(' '*k)).center 41}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsHiNNuYpaUlaboWN1117ao1dC309Cw09XITC6o1orUM9fT0KmwtdbNt4w31EpOKdbQq9FLyy_NK8jUMNWO1NNQV1LWyNTX1klPzSlKLFEwMa2shhq0uKC0pVkjTS07MyYGILFgAoQE)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 77 bytes

Recursion, ahoy! Function outputting an array of lines.

```ruby
f=->x=1{s=([*1...x,*x.downto(1)]*(' '*(9-x))).center 41;x<9?[s,*f[x+1],s]: s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLDoMgEADQq7ATRphkEjdqsQchLOqHldHGgThN07PT964yf2pN3k3i6cteByBEFAuC63kf@dRkIuhGNaB7J8YYXLYjb5fqaJRH/wxsIQVpKVqOg@JffZfMKuHy2vf6Bw)

Comment: Thanks for the tips on my answer. Here's 72 bytes, combining the best of both of our ideas: `(-8..8).map{|i|puts ([*1...x=9-k=i.abs,*x.downto(1)]*(' '*k)).center 41}`

Comment: @LevelRiverSt Good ideas! It also turns out keeping it as a function saves an extra byte as well.

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 12 bytes

```
9ƛɾ9n-Ij;∞øṗ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCI5xpvJvjluLUlqO+KInsO44bmXIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Uses the strangely specific `øṗ` (Flip Brackets Vertical Palindromise, Center, Join on Newlines) builtin.

```
9ƛ      ;         for n in [1...9]:
  ɾ9n-Ij            join [1..n] by 9-n spaces
         ∞        palindromize the list
          øṗ      palindromize and center all the strings and join by \n
```

Comment: Allegedly, it's quite a common pattern in ascii art, [because it was specifically requested to be a shortcut for combining the 3 operations](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/issues/908)

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 17 bytes

```
Ｅ⁹⪫⮌…·¹⊕ι× ⁻⁸ι‖Ｏ¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYxBCsIwEEX3nmLoagJx4U7tCRSKErxAiF8dSKclSXMqT@HFYt7yPXjh41NYfGztnkQLT37lk6XrIsoOFSmDLxrilqXCeX2DD5a6SZihBU8WYyw9ZEbmgQZLk@iW@Wiph864c3hFhHLrs9jv59/XjK21fY1/) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｅ⁹⪫⮌…·¹⊕ι× ⁻⁸ι
```

For `n` from `1` to `9`, output the numbers from `n` down to `1` joined with `9-n` spaces, but doing everything `0`-indexed.

```
‖Ｏ¬
```

Reflect both left and down to complete the diamond gone beautifully wrong.

Answer (score 5):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-l`, 23 bytes

```
QPZJ RZJ:R\,_JsX9-_M\,9
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSbo5S7IKlpSVpuhbbAwOivBSCorysgmJ04r2KIyx1431jdCwhslBFC6A0AA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
QPZJ RZJ:R\,_JsX9-_M\,9
                    \,9  ; Range from 1 to 9, inclusive
                   M     ; Map this function to each:
          \,_            ;   Range from 1 to fn arg, inclusive
         R               ;   Reversed
             J           ;   Join on this string:
              sX         ;   A number of spaces equal to
                9-_      ;   9 minus fn arg
      ZJ:                ; Transpose list of strings, filling gaps with spaces
     R                   ; Reverse list of lines
  ZJ                     ; Transpose again
QP                       ; Quad-palindromize
                         ; Autoprint, joining on newlines (-l flag)
```

Here's the step-by-step evolution, using size 5 instead of 9 and showing spaces using periods:

```
\,5

1
2
3
4
5

R\,_JsX5-_M

1
2...1
3..2..1
4.3.2.1
54321

ZJ:

12345
....4
...33
..2.2
.1.21
.....
..11.

R

..11.
.....
.1.21
..2.2
...33
....4
12345

ZJ

......1
..1...2
1..2..3
1.2.3.4
..12345

QP

......1......
..1...2...1..
1..2..3..2..1
1.2.3.4.3.2.1
..123454321..
1.2.3.4.3.2.1
1..2..3..2..1
..1...2...1..
......1......
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 83 bytes

Updated per suggestion from @ValueInk

```ruby
(-8..8).map{|i|puts (((-8+c=i.abs)..8-c).map{|j|"#{9-c-j.abs}"}*(" "*c)).center 41}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X0PXQk/PQlMvN7GguiazpqC0pFhBQwMoqp1sm6mXmFSsCZTWTYYqyKpRUq621E3WzQJJ1SrVamkoKShpJWtq6iWn5pWkFimYGNb@/w8A)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 86 bytes

```ruby
(-8..8).map{|i|puts (((-8+c=i.abs)..8-c).map{|j|(9-c-j.abs).to_s}*(" "*c)).center(41)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X0PXQk/PQlMvN7GguiazpqC0pFhBQwMoqp1sm6mXmFSsCZTWTYYqyKrRsNRN1s2CSJTkxxfXamkoKShpJWtq6iWn5pWkFmmYGGrW/v8PAA)

Comment: `"#{9-c-j.abs}"` saves 4 bytes over `.to_s` and you can lose the parens on `center(41)` for 1 more.

Comment: @ValueInk The saving for `"#{9-c-j.abs}"` is only 2 bytes, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
9Rjạ9⁶xƊƊ€Uz⁶ZUŒBŒḄY
```

A full program that prints the diamond.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98yKOvhroWWjxq3VRzrOtb1qGlNaBWQExV6dJLT0UkPd7RE/v8PAA)**

#### How?

```
9Rjạ9⁶xƊƊ€Uz⁶ZUŒBŒḄY - Main Link: no arguments
9                    - 9
         €           - for each {i in [1..9]}:
        Ɗ            -   last three links as a monad f(i):
 R                   -     range -> [1..i]
       Ɗ             -     last three links as a monad f(i):
   ạ9                -       absolute difference with 9 -> 9-i
     ⁶               -       space character
      x              -       repeat -> ' '*(9-i)
  j                  -     join -> e.g. "1      2      3"
          U          - reverse each
           z⁶        - transpose with space character as filler
             Z       - transpose
              U      - reverse each
               ŒB    - bounce each
                 ŒḄ  - bounce
                   Y - join with newline characters
                     - implicit, smashing print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 16 bytes

```
9ɾKėƛ÷$8εIj∞;∞øĊ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJqIiwiIiwiOcm+S8SXxpvDtyQ4zrVJauKInjviiJ7DuMSKIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Port of <s>my Thunno 2 answer</s> Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.

*-1 thanks to @lyxal* 
*-3 by porting @KevinCruijssen's 05AB1E answer*

##### Explanation

```python
9ɾKėƛ÷$8εIj∞;∞øĊ  # Full program
9ɾK               # Prefixes of [1..9]
   ėƛ       ;     # Enumerate and map over:
     ÷$8ε         #  Absolute difference between 8 and the iteration index
         Ij       #  Join by that many spaces
           ∞      #  Palindromise
             ∞    # Palindromise
              øĊ  # Center
                  # Implicit output
```

Old:

```python
9ɾ∞ƛ65f-ΠInɾ∞n9εIj+  # Full program
9ɾ∞ƛ                 # Map over [1,2,...,8,9,8,...,2,1]:
    65f-ΠI           #  Push (n-6) * (n-5) spaces
          nɾ∞        #  Push [1,2,...,n,...2,1]
             n9εIj   #  Join by (9-n) spaces
                  +  #  Prepend the leading spaces
                     # Implicit output, joined on newlines
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJqIiwiIiwiOcm+4oiexps2NWYtzqBJbsm+4oiebjnOtUlqKyIsIiIsIiJd) for 19 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## Swift, 156 bytes

`String(repeating:count)` is nice for practical code, but so long for code golf...

```swift
let f={(1...$0)+(1..<$0).reversed()}
f(9).map{n in print(.init(repeating:" ",count:(n-6)*(n-5))+f(n).map{"\($0)"+String(repeating:" ",count:9-n)}.joined())}
```

[Try it on SwiftFiddle!](https://swiftfiddle.com/ttgutsx66vdrfldkcc6dz3r2yy)

Port of @TheThonnu's various answers. `f` is a shorthand for counting from 1 to n and back. I put the joining spaces inside the `map` callback rather than passing them to `joined` because the latter would involve an extra argument label (`joined(separator:)`).

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 214 bytes

Port of [@Level River St's Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263151/110802) in Scala.

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pcxBDoIwEIXhvadoWM2IrUhc4AISD@DKE5SxwWIpjZ0YE8LZK8oR3L3F/71I2umUxrY3xOIizJuNv0VxDmECWQkeRYVq0GGydfPSTlBtlW7jJjytZ@cBMpFtoSwkLHlOyCNUknA1fd3ASZLsvwQVj1deWDer4bGunyZUzviO7/sS839uUEVnyUCxOx4Q5zmlDw)

```scala
object M extends App{(-8 to 8).map{i=>val c=i.abs
println((" "*(20-((-8+c)to(8-c)).map{j=>(9-c-j.abs).toString}.mkString(" "*c).length/2)+((-8+c)to(8-c)).map{j=>(9-c-j.abs).toString}.mkString(" "*c)).slice(0,41))}}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZA/T8MwFMT3fIpTJxva8EcMISJIjAxMFRNicB03dXCcKLZAUOWzh@c4garDk5K7n8/v7KQwYhzbXa2kx4vQFscEKNUeDf0w0Vcux1Pfi@@3re@1rd55jlerPYqJBNgmg2@R8bQRHY7QKB4nA/gUBpJAnYqdO9GMtopkFo5eQvJwnmXY0OeSUv@n0BX3waOpQxBPfRt3mYEhbT6iwFZY4YJiZqcj0RvLpLJe9Szcu8bdDY/@kMSZC88Q9Y1ha3zp0h9yPFvPF/GvdujRiXKrf0KViaQFXWqUrfxhQvSeLcRDgWuO@AbKOIV50wW4uuWcnsLRnDkUesJMGw/JOP4C)

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    (-8 to 8).map { i =>
      val c = i.abs
      val line = ((-8 + c) to (8 - c)).map { j =>
        (9 - c - j.abs).toString
      }.mkString(" " * c)
      println(center(line, 41))
    }
  }
  
  def center(s: String, width: Int): String = {
    val padSize = width - s.length
    if(padSize <= 0) s
    else (" " * (padSize/2)) + s + (" " * (padSize - padSize/2))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>16</s> 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
9Lηε8N-ð×ýû}û.c
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9vc2FiaWX//zlMzrfOtThOLcOww5fDvcO7fcO7LmP//w)

**Explanation:**

```python
9L           # Push a list in the range [1,9]
  η          # Pop and push its prefixes: [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],...]
   ε         # Map over each prefix:
    8N-      #  Push 8 minus the 0-based map index
       ð×    #  Pop and push a string of that many spaces
         ý   #  Join the list with those spaces (or empty string for N=8) as delimiter
          û  #  Palindromize this string
   }û        # After the map: palindromize the list of lines as well
     .c      # Join the list by newlines,
             # and add leading spaces where necessary to centralize the lines
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: To whoever downvoted: any reason why? The output is correct as far as I can tell: [verify here](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/a/kWpCaXJKaYqWgpKPDpeSYXFKamAPi/Lf0Obf93FYLP93DGw5PP7z38O5avWS9Rx1d/225lJzzi4qA2uwVlOwDM5UqU4uVDq9WystXqtX5r6SkpIAFGHKh8KC0EZqsIYqwMQoPpMYQSQAia4LENoKqM4RzjOFKTOEsY7gsRKURVMwEqsoMSptAxY0QdhuBRUzA8kBl5mDSFCxiDJZF@MMIKGIClDMDqrIAYjMg2wQoZoQeEkbGJqZm5haWFuZmpibGRsSaQJxriPcf8WFGbCwQF6OE0wRaOgKmLwA)?

Comment: @KevinCruissjen I think the downvote is from a troll or a bot: the challenge and 4 of the answers got a -1 for no reason in an interval of only a few seconds/minutes

Comment: @Fhuvi Ah, is it that time of year again. ;) Yeah, I've seen it a few times before in the past, where all answers had a downvote on a single challenge. Ah well. Nice challenge btw! I think I'm gonna wait a while before posting a challenge based on [this output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263169/52210) now, haha. :D

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 65 bytes

```perl
$a=-1-abs,print map/\D|0/?$":$_,map$a+10+abs()/$a,-20..20for-8..8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l0VbXUDcxqVinoCgzr0QhN7FAP8alxkDfXkXJSiVeB8hXSdQ2NNAGKtHQ1FdJ1NE1MtDTMzJIyy/StdDTs/j//19@QUlmfl7xf90cAA)

I'd count it `63+1` (instead of `65`), the `+1` for `-E` and `say` instead of `print`, can't figure out how to get it in TIO which also doesn't add 1 for `-l` switch. But it beats direct competitors anyway :), it's strange nobody used this strategy.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 107 bytes

```python
R=range
for n in[*R(1,9),*R(9,0,-1)]:print((n-6)*(n-5)*' '+((9-n)*' ').join(map(str,[*R(1,n),*R(n,0,-1)])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8i2KDEvPZUrLb9IIU8hMy9aK0jDUMdSUwdIW@oY6OgaasZaFRRl5pVoaOTpmmlqAUlTTS11BXVtDQ1L3TwwU1MvKz8zTyM3sUCjuKRIB2JGHtiMPKgZmpqa//8DAA)

Port of my Thunno 2 answer.

*-5 thanks to @Neil*

Comment: `[*R(1,9),*R(9,0,-1)]` saves 1 byte and `[*R(1,n),*R(n,0,-1)]` saves 4!

Comment: @Neil good spot, thanks

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 102 bytes

A full program.

```javascript
for(n=17;n--;print(s))for(q=n<9?n:16-n,x=9-q,i=s=''.padEnd(20-q*x);~q;)s+=`${++i>q?1+q--:i}`.padEnd(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcrBCsIwDADQnxHW2EWsB3WrcSf/Y8UhxEPWtGMURH@94sHr4z3DGvI9cVxwPdf6mJMRcicviD4mlsVkgJ8qyaUbpHdHlLZQh9oyZWqaXQzTTSZz2KNuC/iPesiWxs3LWr7q4Kwi9vwe/7FArV8)

---

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 116 bytes

*-1 thanks to [@c--](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/112488/c)*

```c
q;x;i;main(n){for(n=17;n--;i=!puts(""))for(q=n<9?n:16-n,x=9-q;~q;q-=i>q)printf("%*d",i>1?x:x+12-q*x+q,++i>q?1+q:i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCsIwEADAtxgQkiZ7iAel3aZ5S4mkLOjabSsGRJ9u1PNMgimlWgULEl5HYs3mmW@L5uBPyABIYTfft1UrZcwfJHDfRu78EdiV0ILgW1Ag0CBmXoi3rNW@OStHg4@lK9YfQJpixVn7O9Fb6cjgq9ZPypdxWis8vg)

Comment: What exactly does `[...Array(k)]` achieve?

Comment: @Bbrk24 It generates an array of `k` undefined entries.

Comment: ...right, because JS distinguishes "array of missing items" from "array with `undefined` items". I forgot about that.

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##FcpBCsIwEADAtxgQkiZ7iAel3aZ5S4mkLOjabSsGRJ9u1PNMgimlWgULEl5HYs3mmW@L5uBPyABIYTfft1UrZcwfJHDfRu78EdiV0ILgW1Ag0CBmXoi3rNW@OStHg4@lK9YfQJpixVn7O9Fb6cjgq9ZPypdxWis8vg) for the C program. It relies on `puts(3)` not returning 0 though, so [here](https://tio.run/##FcpBCsIwEEDRuxSEpNMB40JpxjQXcVMiKQM6dqpgQPToxrr5i8dPOKVUq1IhpuvIYsS@8m0xEtyBBJE4bO0fNMixj@LdHqUroUelj5Ji4EHtvLA8smlOsmnPDRgenO3WxOILuB1qW0A7gPWNDtSzpXet35Qv43Sv@PwB)'s an alternative after some rearranging

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 21 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
9Lûε65S-Pð×yLûy9αð×ý«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0ufw7nNbzUyDdQMObzg8vRLIrbQ8txHEPrz30Or/tYd2/wcA)

Port of my Thunno 2 answer. Unfortunately 05AB1E doesn't have the "push n spaces" built-in that Thunno 2 and Vyxal have.

Output as a list of lines. TIO footer joins by newlines.

*-2 thanks to @KevinCruijssen*

##### Explanation

```python
9Lûε65S-Pð×yLûy9αð×ý«  # Implicit input
9Lûε                   # Map over [1,2,...,8,9,8,...,2,1]:
    65S-P×J            #  Push (n-6) * (n-5) spaces
           yLû         #  Push [1,2,...,n,...2,1]
              y9αð×ý   #  Join by (9-n) spaces
                    «  #  Prepend the leading spaces
                       # Implicit output
```

Comment: Both `иJ` can be `×` for -2 bytes. Although with the centralize and mirror builtins in addition to the palindromize, [16 bytes is possible](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263249/52210). :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen wow... time to port to Thunno 2 and Vyxal :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 60 bytes

```
9* 
 
$`;$'¶
v`( *;)( *)
$.1$2
P`.+
%`^.
$^$<'
L$`9
$>`$^$`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/n8tSS4FLgUslwVpF/dA2rrIEDQUta00gocmlomeoYsQVkKCnzaWaEKfHpRKnYqPO5aOSYMmlYpcA5CX8/w8A) Explanation:

```
9*
```

Insert 9 spaces.

```
 
$`;$'¶
```

Generate a `9×9` square of spaces, but with `;`s on the main diagonal.

```
v`( *;)( *)
$.1$2
```

Use the spaces before the `;` to generate the numbers from `n` down to `1` on the `n`th row, spaced using the spaces after the `;`.

```
P`.+
%`^.
$^$<'
```

Reflect horizontally.

```
L$`9
$>`$^$`
```

Reflect vertically (actually around the central `9` but it comes to the same thing).

92 bytes in [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d):

```
9$* 
 
$`;$'¶
(?=( *;)( *)).
$.1$2
.+
$&12$* 
(.(.{20})).*
$2$1
%20O^$`.

¶.+¶$
$&$`
9>O^$`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYqxDYQwEATzrcLBAraRTvgyhIAS6ACZgIDkgxfZ69tyAW7MmGSCmfme9/U5SsFIb2DAOLHLCXadrfGTq3BOQAlUSA@2Qd/TipWfDv8aPagMaHTYdkYBcpI@J9aXEePy2lIe) Explanation:

```
9$*
```

Insert 9 spaces.

```
 
$`;$'¶
```

Generate a `9×9` square of spaces, but with `;`s on the main diagonal.

```
(?=( *;)( *)).
$.1$2
```

Use the spaces before the `;` to generate the numbers from `n` down to `1` on the `n`th row, spaced using the spaces after the `;`.

```
.+
$&12$* 
(.(.{20})).*
$2$1
%20O^$`.
```

Reflect horizontally by prefixing each line with a copy of the 20 characters after the first and then reversing those 20 characters.

```
¶.+¶$
$&$`
9>O^$`
```

Reflect vertically by duplicating all the lines except the last and then reversing only the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 108 bytes

```sh
for c ({1..9} {8..1}){w=$[(10**c/9)**2];printf \\n%$[(5-c)*(6-c)]s
for x (${(s::)w})printf %-$[9-$#w/2]s $x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIVlBo9pQT8@yVqHaQk/PsFazutxWJVrD0EBLK1nfUlNLyyjWuqAoM68kTSEmJk8VKGWqm6yppWEGJGOLuUBGVChoqFRrFFtZaZbXakLVquqqRFvqqiiX6xvFFiuoVNT@/w8A)

Adapted from @Donat's "[bash diamond](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263045/15940)" code and my "[spaceship maw](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216255/15940)" solution.

Comment: TODO: Try iterating `c` over `{-8..8}` per some other solutions here...

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 45 bytes

```
8({.~#-@+41-:@-#)@dlb@(9&-":1+]-|@i:)@-|@i:@8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/LTSq9eqUdR20TQx1rRx0lTUdUnKSHDQs1XSVrAy1Y3VrHDKtNB3AlIPFf02u1OSMfIU0dfX/AA)

Meh.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 98 bytes

```c
i,c=8;main(j){for(;--i/j?i=j=9-abs(c--):1;)printf("%*c",i-j?j-10:11*i-i*i-31,i-j?48+j-abs(i):10);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcvBCoMwEEXRfxEKifWhQ11oQvBb7IDlDWhF3ZV@exQXd3PhKD6qObPS1MV55OLM/6bv5iLA2gYmSz3G9@4U8EGiXzcux@SKR6lFRdhgkCaIlASvXnLPtnvazXihxsd/zic)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 98 bytes

```c
j;main(z,x){for(;z<10;putchar(x>20?10:x%z|(x=58-z-abs(x/z))<49?32:x))x=j%43-21,z=abs(j++/43-8)+1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcntCoMgFADQpwnuRSW1Bi1zPosT9iFsjVZwubVnt/bzcJK6p1RKdq/4fANLwvU2TuB4MNp9ljk94gR0sToY3VPFG5A/dYpVvH6BakYc2nNobE@I5HPVNsoayf7fWYj6cIfCuF8pOw)

Comment: Suggest `z<10` -> `9/z`

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 98 bytes

I don't know if it's very polite to answer my own challenge, but here it is!

```javascript
for(z of(z=9,s=(n=1,p="".padEnd(9-z))=>n<z?n+p+s(n+1,p)+p+n:z)())print("".padEnd((6-z)*(5-z))+s())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcsxDoMwDEbhqyCm3wSQGFoVhMvEQaIiJDoYK4kYfPmQTt3e8L6vv3z8hENTd71y3s8Aq84dxmMbGcJDq1zXvfptlQ1jZ0T8ltkWceoixJWBSspkBCINhyT8AZ5FNHj8XNmJcr4B)

---

This is the combined works of [*Donat*'s recent Javascript answer to the challenge "Print this diamond"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263191/116582)
and [*The Thonnu*'s formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263139/116582): **(n−6)(n−5) for the leading spaces**.

[*@Donat*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95987/donat), don't hesitate if you want to post this as your own answer, this is mostly your work after all :)

Answer (score -1):

## Vyxal, 278 Bytes

```
»×ẏ∴⁺¢ɽƒ3∴ĿṘ€ȯLdd2)"lY∇λµ≠Ḟw⅛!ḋ₌₁ẊṘ?
‡₄¥D‹Ḣ€ɾȯḟǑLdẇm₁≤ɖ↵$hḭ«€X⇧0A2&/•p[₀‟₃5Ǔ≈Π>ḋṠßĠ-⋏↳ĖOUḃ`∑ß∨(V⋏⋎ṁ7Ż≥×h'D℅p×>¥D↲‛℅ddlʀɾ⌐D%₆₄⁋ŻṘġȧ₅ḣ'ɾp0Ḋ¢lǐ⟨6K⌊∵¶⟨Ḣ,g#;¬‛^4⟨β•qrṠg₅Þf⋎→__↑¢[ẏNcḟ≠H꘍C¼↔Π꘍∧≬ǏḭḞǔṄꜝ⌐ø₇µ`ʁȯ⁋√ÞVe↲ <†∧↔⊍n÷PḂė?ġ¦$₌$e⋎\]↵⇩ṁn€⋏+₀ǒ&Ċ⌐∩ṁṗ½VḃḞβ#WżL∵ṖðǓmẊOur,8‹»`1 
23456789`τ
```

Compressed number converted to custom string base.

[Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLCu8OX4bqP4oi04oG6wqLJvcaSM%20KItMS/4bmY4oKsyK9MZGQyKVwibFniiIfOu8K14omg4bied%20KFmyHhuIvigozigoHhuorhuZg/XG7igKHigoTCpUTigLnhuKLigqzJvsiv4bifx5FMZOG6h23igoHiiaTJluKGtSRo4bitwqvigqxY4oenMEEyJi/igKJwW%20KCgOKAn%20KCgzXHk%20KJiM6gPuG4i%20G5oMOfxKAt4ouP4oazxJZPVeG4g2DiiJHDn%20KIqChW4ouP4ouO4bmBN8W74omlw5doJ0TihIVww5c%20wqVE4oay4oCb4oSFZGRsyoDJvuKMkEQl4oKG4oKE4oGLxbvhuZjEocin4oKF4bijJ8m%20cDDhuIrComzHkOKfqDZL4oyK4oi1wrbin6jhuKIsZyM7wqzigJteNOKfqM6y4oCicXLhuaBn4oKFw55m4ouO4oaSX1/ihpHColvhuo9OY%20G4n%20KJoEjqmI1DwrzihpTOoOqYjeKIp%20KJrMeP4bit4biex5ThuYTqnJ3ijJDDuOKCh8K1YMqByK/igYviiJrDnlZl4oayIDzigKDiiKfihpTiio1uw7dQ4biCxJc/xKHCpiTigowkZeKLjlxcXeKGteKHqeG5gW7igqzii48r4oKAx5ImxIrijJDiiKnhuYHhuZfCvVbhuIPhuJ7OsiNXxbxM4oi14bmWw7DHk23huopPdXIsOOKAucK7YDEgXG4yMzQ1Njc4OWDPhCIsIiIsIiJd)

Comment: [Try looking for a pattern instead of just compressing the output next time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263142/114446)

Comment: @TheThonnu It doesn't even look that compressed; Charcoal can compress the entire output in 125 bytes.

Comment: Yeah for Vyxal this is uncommonly long, even PHP can do better with GZip `<?=gzinflate('•‘KÀ D÷Mz¯à€hï±J Ú5Q`æÅ–òõ<¦Ò#V»N:M•A5)Í)ÇÖ¨(˜…ë(\dÇÄ#»Žt<Lb”ë¶6SÈÜô¨ÄjŠbC§hÎªáÓ7éã]ö÷Ø¼ÑWþèÝölþnjH™ÜÕì');` for 143 bytes (it won't work here, many special chars)

Comment: The try it online link ends up as blank code